# Change \textwidth and \textheight in mid-document

Tags: margins

I set my `\textwidth` and `\textheight` in the preamble and would like to change both for some pages. How can this be done? E.g., the following example for `\textwidth` appears to work for the page number, but not for the text:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\textwidth=5cm \textheight=5cm
\begin{document}
A \hfill B
\eject \textwidth=10cm
A \hfill B
\end{document}
```

Output (true to scale):

[image]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` from the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=5cm,textheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\newgeometry{textwidth=10cm,textheight=10cm}
\lipsum[1-4]
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great - thanks. I had given up on the geometry package after it frustrated me in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document

Comment: Is there a way to change the text column width mid-page?

Comment: Tried this and the text width works fine but the page numbering is no longer centered. Is there a way to fix that? I'm using `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` from the `fancyhdr` package.

Comment: @cjm: adjustwidth seems to be useful for that. Note that floats don't get scaled.

Answer (score 10):

To change textwidth locally for a defined scope you may use 
`\begin{minipage}{WIDTH}`.

```
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
...
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Welcome, minipages cannot be broken, so the content might overflow the page at the bottom.

Comment: It's interesting, pages **cannot** be broken with `minipage`, but pages **must** be broken with `\newgeometry`. It complements the previous one for the cases when the textwidth change takes place at the same page of the unchanged text.

Comment: This one is perfect for my usage with the TeXMaths plug in for LibreOffice