# Additional margin for the table of contents / on a single page

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change \textwidth and \textheight in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13449/change-textwidth-and-textheight-in-mid-document)

is there a way to adjust the vertical margins, i.e. left and right, on a single page / a certain region (the table of contents in my case) of a TeX document?

The reason why I'm asking is, that I've got a simple TeX-Article with two columns, therefor I set the margins left and right to somewhat around 2cm. However, I did not apply multicols on the table of contents (as I do not want that). Now the toc stretches over the full page width, which I find very ugly. Ideally it would have an individual width of 2/3 of the page, somewhat around 12cm.

Comment: @lockstep The solution given there uses `\newgeometry` that forces a page break.

Comment: @egreg Thanks -- I normally start ToC's on a new page, so I didn't think abput `\newgeometry`s limitation. (And +1 for your answer.)

Comment: @egreg Looking at the question title again, it reads "on a single page". ;-)

Comment: @lockstep "on a single page / a certain region". Maybe scravy can make the question more precise.

Comment: @egreg: As the OP accepted your answer, the correct tag seems to be {indentation}, not {margins}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A practical way might be

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.667\textwidth}
\tableofcontents
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

The `center` environment however, introduces vertical space; you could also use

```
{\centering
 \begin{minipage}{.667\textwidth}
 \tableofcontents
 \end{minipage}\par}
```

Take your pick.