# Setting different margin sizes in different pages

Tags: margins, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change \textwidth and \textheight in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13449/change-textwidth-and-textheight-in-mid-document)

I am currently using `geometry` package to set margin sizes. I want to set different `\topmargin` sizes for different pages. For example, in the first page, `\topmargin` is 1 inch, and in the second page, it is 1.5 inch. How can I do this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Change \textwidth and \textheight in mid-document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13449/2693).

Comment: Ah indeed, I should have probably looked around before answering.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks. By the way, can I explicitly specify "the second page"?

Answer (score 2):

you can change the layout mid-document by using the `\newgeometry{...}` command.

if you need to return to the top level geometry later on , you then use the `\restoregeometry` command.

As far as I know the syntax is the same as the one you would use in the preamble. one thing to note is that `\newgeometry` will disable all the settings set with the `\geometry` command, with the exception of paper size related ones.