# How to change the margins of ‎the only‎ first page ‎of‎ ‎‎each‎ ‎‎‎chapter‎?‎

Tags: margins, geometry, book-design

I'm‎ using ‎the ‎`geometry` package in the ‎`book‎` class‎ ‎and now I ‎want‎ the margins of the first page of each chapter ‎to‎ be, for example, `top=50mm, ‎bottom=50mm‎, ‎left=50mm‎, ‎‎right=50mm`‎ and the margins of other pages to be, say, `‎top=3‎0mm, ‎‎bottom=3‎0mm‎, ‎‎left=3‎0mm‎, ‎‎‎‎right=30‎mm`.‎
BTW,‎ I ‎want‎ to do it in the preamle, and not in the document ‎body ‎itself.  For ‎convenience,‎ I put ‎the‎ following MWE:‎‎

```
‎\documentclass{book}‎
\usepackage[top=50mm, ‎bottom=50mm‎, ‎left=50mm‎, ‎‎‎right=50mm]{geometry}‎‎‎
‎‎\usepackage{lipsum‎} ‎‎
‎\begin{document}‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎\chapter{One‎}‎‎‎
‎\lipsum[1-‎‎‎12‎‎‎]‎
‎\chapter{Two‎}‎‎‎‎
‎\lipsum[4-‎8‎]         
‎‎‎‎\end{document}‎‎‎
```

I'm‎ familiar with ‎command‎s like `\newgeometry`, `\savegeometry`, ‎and‎ `\loadgeometry` ‎etc‎, but I couldn't ‎accomplish‎ that. ‎Can‎ anybody please help me do that?

Comment: It's not easy in TeX to change line width mid-paragraph unless you know in advance how many lines are required for the first width. thus you can not change the lien width at an automatic page break the whole paragraph has already been set with the settings from the first page. If you have a fixed break such as \clearpage then you can reset the geometry at that point (as done in lscape package for example)  it would perhaps be possible in some cases with a multiple-pass procedure that determined the page break on one pass and re-set on later passes, or using luatex which has extra features here

Comment: I would try `afterpage` package. But this isn't working for me: `\newgeometry{top=50mm,bottom=50mm,left=50mm,right=50mm}`
`\afterpage{\clearpage\restoregeometry}` (just thought mentioning the package could help)

Comment: Cannot it be done using another package?

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan -- I'm afraid there is no existing, automatic solution in 'package' form.  Perhaps someone could get clever with `LuaTeX`, but I don't think anyone has done so yet.

Comment: Does this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13451/10898

Comment: Could you maybe draw a small sketch what are are trying to accomplish? I am not sure you need to change the geometry at all. If I understand correctly, wouldn't a 20mm vertical white space above the chapter name suffice?

Comment: @Andy: As I said in my post, I want the first page of each chapter in different margins.

Comment: @lockstep done.

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy in TeX to change line width mid-paragraph unless you know in advance how many lines are required for the first width. thus you can not change the line width at an automatic page break the whole paragraph has already been set with the settings from the first page.

If you have a fixed break such as `\clearpage` then you can reset the geometry at that point (as done in `lscape` package for example) it would perhaps be possible in some cases with a multiple-pass procedure that determined the page break on one pass and re-set on later passes, or using `luatex` which has extra features here