# Change \textwidth after first page in scrlttr2

Tags: margins, scrlttr2

I am looking for an automated mechanism to change the effective `\textwidth` at the first pagebreak of a letter in `scrpage2`. I've tried `\afterpage` and `\nextpage` (ideally they would be set within `\firsthead`), both without success. I do not want to use the `geometry` package because firstly, IMO `scrlttr2` *should work* with a change of `KOMAoptions` and friends and secondly, it does not seem to work anyways if used within `scrlttr2` and the KOMA layout. Ideas and suggestions are very welcome.

Here's a MNWE. Page 2 and following should have a wider text block than the first page — but doesn't.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum,afterpage}%
\setlength{\textwidth}{125mm}%
\nexthead{%
  \global\areaset{170mm}{\textheight}%
  \global\KOMAoptions{DIV=areaset}%
  \global\recalctypearea%
}
\afterpage{%
  \global\areaset{170mm}{\textheight}%
  \global\KOMAoptions{DIV=areaset}%
  \global\recalctypearea%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Receipient}
  \opening{Dear receipient,}
  \lipsum[1-6]
  \closing{Yours}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

And BTW, I genuinely think that this is *not* covered by [Change \textwidth and \textheight in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13449/2693) and related questions and instead somehow relates to the internals of the KOMA classes.

Comment: You will need to force a page break if changing the width of the text block. TeX typesets at least an entire paragraph before considering the page break and does not re-set the text on the new page so the first part of the page is always set with the settings from the previous page. By forcing a page break you ensure no text is held over. This is a basic limitation in tex/pdftex/xetex, it can be worked around with some difficulty using lua callbacks in luatex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, but even when I add `\eject` or `\clearpage` as first commands into the `\nexthead` and `\afterpage` arguments, it still doesn't work. And despite an increased argument to `\lipsum`, the modified `\textwidth` does not even show at later pages.

Comment: No they can not work there, the heading is inserted in the output routine _after_ the page has been broken. The text on the following page has _already_ been set to the previous width by the time the heading code (or afterpage code) is activated.  Also in you can only use `\global` with a single primitive assignment if you go `\global\areaset` you just make a single assignment at the start of the expansion of areaset global. As far as I can see this will be the assignment of `\reserved@d` in the middle of `\@ifnextchar` looking for an optional argument. No length assignments will be global.

Comment: have you looked at the `adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` package?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I finally understand your comment, after copying the required definitions from the `changepage` package. This does almost what I want:      
  `\afterpage{%
    \pagebreak
    \global\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm}%
    \global\setlength{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}%
    \global\setlength{\hsize}{\columnwidth}%
    \global\setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}}%`
Except that the `\pagebreak` (or `\eject` or `\clearpage`) does not do what I want it to do. As you say, the pagebreak has already taken place. `\firstfoot` does not seem to work either.

Comment: Sorry if my comments were opaque:-) @cmhughes should then make his comment an answer then you can accept that and the question can be signed off. Glad you got something working.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, almost working at least. I still haven't figured out how to issue the change of `\textwidth` at *exactly* the page break and not after the end of the first (broken across pagebreak) paragraph on page 2. But as I understand you, this won't be possible without additional machinery like luatex. Pity. However I think that your reply, while a negative answer, deserves the status answer.

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks for the pointer to the `changepage` package, inspection of its `\ch@ngetext` macro was indeed helpful. +1

Comment: To change the width mid paragraph you either need luatex's linebreaking callbacks or a multi-pass algorithm that figures out how many lines of space you have left on the page, and then sets a `\parshape` that sets up a non-rectangular paragraph with n lines of one textwidth and then the remaining lines at the second textwidth.  This is really pushing the limits of what is possible in TeX.  If you allow yourself a manual forced break you can force the page break change the size and re-start the paragraph with `\noindent` so it is a continuation not a new para. It is _so_ much easier:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is now a working example. It still requires a manual `\pagebreak` in the main text of the letter, but according to explanations by @DavidCarlisle, see above, this is at good as it can get without resorting to more powerful systems like luatex.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum,afterpage}%
\setlength{\textwidth}{125mm}%
\firstfoot{%
  \afterpage{%
    \global\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm}%
    \global\setlength{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}%
    \global\setlength{\hsize}{\columnwidth}%
    \global\setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Receipient}
  \opening{Dear receipient,}
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \pagebreak % enfore the page break, otherwise afterpage will take
  % effect too late, i.e. after first broken paragraph on page 2.
  \lipsum[3-12]
  \closing{Yours}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

In this example the text body on the first page has a width of 12.5cm and on of 17cm on all following pages. If you want this to work in documents containing multiple letters, you should reset `\textwidth` on every "first page," e.g. using

```
\firsthead{%
    \global\setlength{\textwidth}{12.5cm}%
    \global\setlength{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}%
    \global\setlength{\hsize}{\columnwidth}%
    \global\setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}%
}
```

in the preamble.