# Change margin next page with KOMA-script and everyshi

Tags: koma-script, everyshi

I would like to change the margin with the beginning of the second page simply by using a KOMA-script option: `mpinclude=true`. It works, if I write at the end of the text on page 1 this line:

```
\KOMAoptions{mpinclude=true}\recalctypearea{}
```

But the drawback is a pagebreak exactly where I put this line.

So I'd like to postpone the command to the end of the page. I found the package everyshi, which offers the command `\AtNextShipout`.

The following MWE does not work, the margin does not change on the second page, but I get the words `[current]last` as first line of the second page.

Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{everyshi}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\AtNextShipout{\KOMAoptions{mpinclude=true}\recalctypearea{}}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

This MWE is rather short. My file as well uses the packages scrletter and some *.lco customisation.

Comment: But you are aware that it won't work if you have a paragraph that is split at the end of page 1?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Öh, no?! Why not? Can't I add a `\par` into the argument of `\AtNextShipout`? Or something like this? Or ist there something like `\AtEndOfLastParagraphFullyOnPage`? But if no good solution, then let's forget about it and I add the `\AtNextShipout`after finishing the article.

Comment: Well a paragraph is built first and a page split is done later. So the paragraph will always have the line width of the first page.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you have an idea for a solution that worked, if the pagebreak isn't in the middle of a paragraph, => great. If the pagebreak is inside, then maybe the last lines on the first page may run shorter or on the next page longer, I can manually correct it.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79737/change-textwidth-after-first-page-in-scrlttr2/79827#79827

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll read that and report whether it works or not. Thank you!

Comment: @KeksDose Can we close the question as a duplicate of Ulrikes link? See also section »C.2. Satzspiegeländerungen zwischen zwei Seiten« in the KOMA-Script book (6th edition; section D2 in 5th edition).

Comment: @esdd Yes to closing. Question asked to early, will ask again after switching to LuaTeX, whenever that will be. I'll read the new version of Appendix C in the book asap. Thank you!