# How to make this table fit on a portrait A4 page?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \footnotesize
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
    \toprule
    Bank  & Country &       &       & Conditional joint probability of default &       &       & Total assets & Total liabilities \\
    \midrule
          &       & 15 Sept. 2008 & 10 Mar. 2009 & 2 May 2010 & 25 Nov. 2011 & 19 Dec. 2013 &       &  \\
    Erste Group Bank AG & AUT   & 0.084 & 0.133 & 0.094 & 0.201 & 0.091 & 209.30 & 194.12 \\
    Raiffeisen Bank & AUT   & 0.094 & 0.121 & 0.080 & 0.256 & 0.097 & 146.63 & 135.69 \\
    Dexia SA & BEL   & 0.052 & 0.111 & 0.059 & 0.154 & 0.060 & 412.05 & 412.37 \\
    KBC Groep NV & BEL   & 0.145 & 0.140 & 0.123 & 0.256 & 0.134 & 282.94 & 266.17 \\
    Danske Bank A/S & DEN   & 0.071 & 0.118 & 0.071 & 0.191 & 0.075 & 3422.61 & 3296.76 \\
    BNP Paribas & FRA   & 0.230 & 0.293 & 0.209 & 0.333 & 0.208 & 1955.94 & 1870.31 \\
    Credit Agricole SA & FRA   & 0.156 & 0.286 & 0.151 & 0.330 & 0.162 & 1718.51 & 1669.22 \\
    Natixis & FRA   & 0.108 & 0.119 & 0.146 & 0.404 & 0.164 & 504.50 & 487.11 \\
    Societe Generale & FRA   & 0.168 & 0.285 & 0.167 & 0.278 & 0.166 & 1176.79 & 1125.68 \\
    Commerzbank AG & GER   & 0.182 & 0.335 & 0.180 & 0.277 & 0.153 & 657.61 & 630.23 \\
    Deutsche Bank AG & GER   & 0.182 & 0.262 & 0.146 & 0.322 & 0.204 & 2155.37 & 2100.71 \\
    IKB Bank & GER   & 0.038 & 0.052 & 0.055 & 0.202 & 0.051 & 31.25 & 30.27 \\
    Alpha Bank & GRE   & 0.034 & 0.060 & 0.031 & 0.096 & 0.035 & 57.68 & 56.25 \\
    Allied Irish Banks PLC & IRE   & 0.040 & 0.062 & 0.037 & 0.124 & 0.019 & 132.96 & 118.50 \\
    Irish Life and Permanent & IRE   & 0.038 & 0.071 & 0.039 & 0.097 & 0.090 & 71.85 & 68.34 \\
    Bank of Ireland & IRE   & 0.035 & 0.061 & 0.040 & 0.109 & 0.092 & 153.50 & 143.25 \\
    Banca Italease & ITA   & 0.030 & 0.043 & 0.081 & 0.336 & 0.105 & 10.53 & 8.89 \\
    Banca Monte dei Paschi di Siena & ITA   & 0.117 & 0.261 & 0.115 & 0.205 & 0.068 & 234.03 & 223.05 \\
    Banca Popolare di Milano & ITA   & 0.166 & 0.232 & 0.132 & 0.224 & 0.079 & 51.22 & 47.16 \\
    Banco Popolare SC & ITA   & 0.110 & 0.119 & 0.090 & 0.157 & 0.084 & 130.86 & 121.44 \\
    Intesa Sanpaolo SpA & ITA   & 0.158 & 0.242 & 0.131 & 0.230 & 0.162 & 626.90 & 579.14 \\
    Mediobanca SpA & ITA   & 0.152 & 0.242 & 0.129 & 0.259 & 0.152 & 74.80 & 67.77 \\
    UniCredit SpA & ITA   & 0.133 & 0.162 & 0.116 & 0.336 & 0.164 & 914.11 & 859.31 \\
    Banco Comercial Portugues SA & POR   & 0.097 & 0.147 & 0.078 & 0.148 & 0.075 & 91.92 & 87.54 \\
    Espirito Santo Financial Group & POR   & 0.076 & 0.126 & 0.075 & 0.198 & 0.092 & 79.53 & 73.54 \\
    Banco Bilbao Vizcaya & SPA   & 0.185 & 0.251 & 0.154 & 0.321 & 0.164 & 3198.97 & 3082.27 \\
    Banco de Sabadell SA & SPA   & 0.067 & 0.120 & 0.085 & 0.195 & 0.103 & 1180.67 & 1126.09 \\
    Banco Santander SA & SPA   & 0.178 & 0.249 & 0.169 & 0.325 & 0.163 & 1226.99 & 1179.73 \\
    Nordea Bank & SWE   & 0.108 & 0.193 & 0.097 & 0.243 & 0.110 & 6397.94 & 6164.55 \\
    Skandinaviska Enskilda Banken & SWE   & 0.077 & 0.112 & 0.073 & 0.192 & 0.078 & 2361.34 & 2252.18 \\
    Svenska Handelsbanken AB & SWE   & 0.118 & 0.196 & 0.112 & 0.285 & 0.112 & 2453.99 & 2359.46 \\
    Swedbank AB & SWE   & 0.058 & 0.090 & 0.070 & 0.195 & 0.071 & 1856.19 & 1758.06 \\
    Credit Suisse Group & SWI   & 0.210 & 0.265 & 0.209 & 0.405 & 0.186 & 1040.23 & 999.14 \\
    UBS SG & SWI   & 0.151 & 0.194 & 0.159 & 0.351 & 0.196 & 1410.64 & 1352.78 \\
    ING Groep NV & NL    & 0.083 & 0.199 & 0.114 & 0.259 & 0.174 & 1270.56 & 1223.33 \\
    SNS Bank Netherlands & NL    & 0.128 & 0.072 & 0.056 & 0.165 & 0.039 & 128.21 & 123.64 \\
    Barclays PLC & UK    & 0.119 & 0.185 & 0.167 & 0.317 & 0.142 & 1560.52 & 1495.32 \\
    HBOS PLC & UK    & 0.065 & 0.209 & 0.115 & 0.317 & 0.217 & 568.00 & 540.36 \\
    Lloyds Banking Group & UK    & 0.166 & 0.207 & 0.117 & 0.228 & 0.156 & 966.05 & 919.46 \\
    Standard Chartered & UK    & 0.201 & 0.126 & 0.219 & 0.417 & 0.116 & 385.26 & 358.62 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

I produce the above code using the Excel2Latex addin in Excel. I want to fit this table (portrait) on a single A4 page. However, the above code produces:
[image]

How can I edit the table to make it fit? Also there are a few things which I'm not sure how to change. For example, the '`Conditional joint probability of default`' should span over the 5 dates rather than being forced into the same column as the middle date '`2 May 2010`'. Furthermore, I have a feeling that the bank names could be too long for the first column, if so, perhaps we can make the banks with longer names use up 2 rows rather than one row?

---

EDIT:

The below is what I have for my document.

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\tabstack}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\raggedbottom
```

If I do not remove the `12pt` I get the following output for the table:

[image]

But if I remove the `12pt` the table shows up nicely:

[image]

Comment: How wide is your document's text block? Alternatively, how wide are the left and right margins?

Comment: @TrueTears Just for curiosity, what the table is about?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Example, which uses the following tricks:

- Smaller font size as in the question: `\footnotesize`. (Should not be smaller than that.)
- Long column headers put in two lines (via macro `\tabstack`).
- Also the dates are written in two lines to save space. `\cmidrule` adds a visual separator between the year and the following numbers in the column.
- Space between columns reduced to 30%: `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3\tabcolsep}`.
- Width of the bank column limited to 30 mm by using `p` column type.
  Adding package `microtype` prevents one of the bank names to be broken across two lines (Allied Irish Bank PLC).
- Package `siunitx` provides column type `S` for aligning numbers at the decimal point (thanks cmhughes for the suggestion).
- The column header `Country` sticks to the left and right to save some space.
- Package `caption` added for correct space between table caption and table (thanks Bernard).
- Uniform spacing of the date columns without abbreviation dot (suggestion of Barbara Beeton).

Complete source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{% robust version needed because of column type S
  \tabstack}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3\tabcolsep}
  \newcommand*{\tabdate}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \settowidth{\dimen0 }{10 Mar}%
      \hbox to \dimen0{\hss #1\hss}%
    \endgroup
  }
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{
      >{\centering}p{30mm}
      c
      *{5}{S[table-format=1.3]}
      *{2}{S[table-format=4.2]}
    }
    \toprule
    Bank  & \hspace{-\tabcolsep}Country\hspace{-\tabcolsep}\null &
      \multicolumn{5}{c}{%
        Conditional joint probability of default%
      }
      & \tabstack{Total\\assets}
      & \tabstack{Total\\liabilities} \\
    \midrule
      &
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{15 Sept}\\2008}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{10 Mar}\\2009}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{2 May}\\2010}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{25 Nov}\\2011}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{19 Dec}\\2013}
      &       &  \\
    \cmidrule(r{\tabcolsep}){3-7}
    Erste Group Bank AG & AUT   & 0.084 & 0.133 & 0.094 & 0.201 & 0.091 & 209.30 & 194.12 \\
    Raiffeisen Bank & AUT   & 0.094 & 0.121 & 0.080 & 0.256 & 0.097 & 146.63 & 135.69 \\
    Dexia SA & BEL   & 0.052 & 0.111 & 0.059 & 0.154 & 0.060 & 412.05 & 412.37 \\
    KBC Groep NV & BEL   & 0.145 & 0.140 & 0.123 & 0.256 & 0.134 & 282.94 & 266.17 \\
    Danske Bank A/S & DEN   & 0.071 & 0.118 & 0.071 & 0.191 & 0.075 & 3422.61 & 3296.76 \\
    BNP Paribas & FRA   & 0.230 & 0.293 & 0.209 & 0.333 & 0.208 & 1955.94 & 1870.31 \\
    Credit Agricole SA & FRA   & 0.156 & 0.286 & 0.151 & 0.330 & 0.162 & 1718.51 & 1669.22 \\
    Natixis & FRA   & 0.108 & 0.119 & 0.146 & 0.404 & 0.164 & 504.50 & 487.11 \\
    Societe Generale & FRA   & 0.168 & 0.285 & 0.167 & 0.278 & 0.166 & 1176.79 & 1125.68 \\
    Commerzbank AG & GER   & 0.182 & 0.335 & 0.180 & 0.277 & 0.153 & 657.61 & 630.23 \\
    Deutsche Bank AG & GER   & 0.182 & 0.262 & 0.146 & 0.322 & 0.204 & 2155.37 & 2100.71 \\
    IKB Bank & GER   & 0.038 & 0.052 & 0.055 & 0.202 & 0.051 & 31.25 & 30.27 \\
    Alpha Bank & GRE   & 0.034 & 0.060 & 0.031 & 0.096 & 0.035 & 57.68 & 56.25 \\
    Allied Irish Banks PLC & IRE   & 0.040 & 0.062 & 0.037 & 0.124 & 0.019 & 132.96 & 118.50 \\
    Irish Life and Permanent & IRE   & 0.038 & 0.071 & 0.039 & 0.097 & 0.090 & 71.85 & 68.34 \\
    Bank of Ireland & IRE   & 0.035 & 0.061 & 0.040 & 0.109 & 0.092 & 153.50 & 143.25 \\
    Banca Italease & ITA   & 0.030 & 0.043 & 0.081 & 0.336 & 0.105 & 10.53 & 8.89 \\
    Banca Monte dei Paschi di Siena & ITA   & 0.117 & 0.261 & 0.115 & 0.205 & 0.068 & 234.03 & 223.05 \\
    Banca Popolare di Milano & ITA   & 0.166 & 0.232 & 0.132 & 0.224 & 0.079 & 51.22 & 47.16 \\
    Banco Popolare SC & ITA   & 0.110 & 0.119 & 0.090 & 0.157 & 0.084 & 130.86 & 121.44 \\
    Intesa Sanpaolo SpA & ITA   & 0.158 & 0.242 & 0.131 & 0.230 & 0.162 & 626.90 & 579.14 \\
    Mediobanca SpA & ITA   & 0.152 & 0.242 & 0.129 & 0.259 & 0.152 & 74.80 & 67.77 \\
    UniCredit SpA & ITA   & 0.133 & 0.162 & 0.116 & 0.336 & 0.164 & 914.11 & 859.31 \\
    Banco Comercial Portugues SA & POR   & 0.097 & 0.147 & 0.078 & 0.148 & 0.075 & 91.92 & 87.54 \\
    Espirito Santo Financial Group & POR   & 0.076 & 0.126 & 0.075 & 0.198 & 0.092 & 79.53 & 73.54 \\
    Banco Bilbao Vizcaya & SPA   & 0.185 & 0.251 & 0.154 & 0.321 & 0.164 & 3198.97 & 3082.27 \\
    Banco de Sabadell SA & SPA   & 0.067 & 0.120 & 0.085 & 0.195 & 0.103 & 1180.67 & 1126.09 \\
    Banco Santander SA & SPA   & 0.178 & 0.249 & 0.169 & 0.325 & 0.163 & 1226.99 & 1179.73 \\
    Nordea Bank & SWE   & 0.108 & 0.193 & 0.097 & 0.243 & 0.110 & 6397.94 & 6164.55 \\
    Skandinaviska Enskilda Banken & SWE   & 0.077 & 0.112 & 0.073 & 0.192 & 0.078 & 2361.34 & 2252.18 \\
    Svenska Handelsbanken AB & SWE   & 0.118 & 0.196 & 0.112 & 0.285 & 0.112 & 2453.99 & 2359.46 \\
    Swedbank AB & SWE   & 0.058 & 0.090 & 0.070 & 0.195 & 0.071 & 1856.19 & 1758.06 \\
    Credit Suisse Group & SWI   & 0.210 & 0.265 & 0.209 & 0.405 & 0.186 & 1040.23 & 999.14 \\
    UBS SG & SWI   & 0.151 & 0.194 & 0.159 & 0.351 & 0.196 & 1410.64 & 1352.78 \\
    ING Groep NV & NL    & 0.083 & 0.199 & 0.114 & 0.259 & 0.174 & 1270.56 & 1223.33 \\
    SNS Bank Netherlands & NL    & 0.128 & 0.072 & 0.056 & 0.165 & 0.039 & 128.21 & 123.64 \\
    Barclays PLC & UK    & 0.119 & 0.185 & 0.167 & 0.317 & 0.142 & 1560.52 & 1495.32 \\
    HBOS PLC & UK    & 0.065 & 0.209 & 0.115 & 0.317 & 0.217 & 568.00 & 540.36 \\
    Lloyds Banking Group & UK    & 0.166 & 0.207 & 0.117 & 0.228 & 0.156 & 966.05 & 919.46 \\
    Standard Chartered & UK    & 0.201 & 0.126 & 0.219 & 0.417 & 0.116 & 385.26 & 358.62 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Another variant, inspired by [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192245/16967):

- Use of package `multirow` for "Total assets" and "Total liabilities".
- Using three letter abbreviation "Sep." instead of "Sept.".
- "Total assets" moved a tiny bit to the right, also a little space
  is added before the last two columns.

Source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\tabstack}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3\tabcolsep}
  \newcommand*{\tabdate}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \settowidth{\dimen0 }{10 Mar}%
      \hbox to \dimen0{\hss #1\hss}%
    \endgroup
  }
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{
      >{\centering}p{30mm}
      c
      *{5}{S[table-format=1.3]}
      !{\kern.9\tabcolsep}
      *{2}{S[table-format=4.2]}
    }
    \toprule
      Bank & \hspace{-\tabcolsep}Country &
      \multicolumn{5}{c}{%
        Conditional joint probability of default%
      }
      & \multirow{2}{*}{\,\tabstack{Total\\assets}}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{\tabstack{Total\\liabilities}} \\
    \cmidrule(r{\tabcolsep}){3-7}
      &
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{15 Sep}\\2008}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{10 Mar}\\2009}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{2 May}\\2010}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{25 Nov}\\2011}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{19 Dec}\\2013}
      & & \\
    \midrule
    Erste Group Bank AG & AUT   & 0.084 & 0.133 & 0.094 & 0.201 & 0.091 & 209.30 & 194.12 \\
    Raiffeisen Bank & AUT   & 0.094 & 0.121 & 0.080 & 0.256 & 0.097 & 146.63 & 135.69 \\
    Dexia SA & BEL   & 0.052 & 0.111 & 0.059 & 0.154 & 0.060 & 412.05 & 412.37 \\
    KBC Groep NV & BEL   & 0.145 & 0.140 & 0.123 & 0.256 & 0.134 & 282.94 & 266.17 \\
    Danske Bank A/S & DEN   & 0.071 & 0.118 & 0.071 & 0.191 & 0.075 & 3422.61 & 3296.76 \\
    BNP Paribas & FRA   & 0.230 & 0.293 & 0.209 & 0.333 & 0.208 & 1955.94 & 1870.31 \\
    Credit Agricole SA & FRA   & 0.156 & 0.286 & 0.151 & 0.330 & 0.162 & 1718.51 & 1669.22 \\
    Natixis & FRA   & 0.108 & 0.119 & 0.146 & 0.404 & 0.164 & 504.50 & 487.11 \\
    Societe Generale & FRA   & 0.168 & 0.285 & 0.167 & 0.278 & 0.166 & 1176.79 & 1125.68 \\
    Commerzbank AG & GER   & 0.182 & 0.335 & 0.180 & 0.277 & 0.153 & 657.61 & 630.23 \\
    Deutsche Bank AG & GER   & 0.182 & 0.262 & 0.146 & 0.322 & 0.204 & 2155.37 & 2100.71 \\
    IKB Bank & GER   & 0.038 & 0.052 & 0.055 & 0.202 & 0.051 & 31.25 & 30.27 \\
    Alpha Bank & GRE   & 0.034 & 0.060 & 0.031 & 0.096 & 0.035 & 57.68 & 56.25 \\
    Allied Irish Banks PLC & IRE   & 0.040 & 0.062 & 0.037 & 0.124 & 0.019 & 132.96 & 118.50 \\
    Irish Life and Permanent & IRE   & 0.038 & 0.071 & 0.039 & 0.097 & 0.090 & 71.85 & 68.34 \\
    Bank of Ireland & IRE   & 0.035 & 0.061 & 0.040 & 0.109 & 0.092 & 153.50 & 143.25 \\
    Banca Italease & ITA   & 0.030 & 0.043 & 0.081 & 0.336 & 0.105 & 10.53 & 8.89 \\
    Banca Monte dei Paschi di Siena & ITA   & 0.117 & 0.261 & 0.115 & 0.205 & 0.068 & 234.03 & 223.05 \\
    Banca Popolare di Milano & ITA   & 0.166 & 0.232 & 0.132 & 0.224 & 0.079 & 51.22 & 47.16 \\
    Banco Popolare SC & ITA   & 0.110 & 0.119 & 0.090 & 0.157 & 0.084 & 130.86 & 121.44 \\
    Intesa Sanpaolo SpA & ITA   & 0.158 & 0.242 & 0.131 & 0.230 & 0.162 & 626.90 & 579.14 \\
    Mediobanca SpA & ITA   & 0.152 & 0.242 & 0.129 & 0.259 & 0.152 & 74.80 & 67.77 \\
    UniCredit SpA & ITA   & 0.133 & 0.162 & 0.116 & 0.336 & 0.164 & 914.11 & 859.31 \\
    Banco Comercial Portugues SA & POR   & 0.097 & 0.147 & 0.078 & 0.148 & 0.075 & 91.92 & 87.54 \\
    Espirito Santo Financial Group & POR   & 0.076 & 0.126 & 0.075 & 0.198 & 0.092 & 79.53 & 73.54 \\
    Banco Bilbao Vizcaya & SPA   & 0.185 & 0.251 & 0.154 & 0.321 & 0.164 & 3198.97 & 3082.27 \\
    Banco de Sabadell SA & SPA   & 0.067 & 0.120 & 0.085 & 0.195 & 0.103 & 1180.67 & 1126.09 \\
    Banco Santander SA & SPA   & 0.178 & 0.249 & 0.169 & 0.325 & 0.163 & 1226.99 & 1179.73 \\
    Nordea Bank & SWE   & 0.108 & 0.193 & 0.097 & 0.243 & 0.110 & 6397.94 & 6164.55 \\
    Skandinaviska Enskilda Banken & SWE   & 0.077 & 0.112 & 0.073 & 0.192 & 0.078 & 2361.34 & 2252.18 \\
    Svenska Handelsbanken AB & SWE   & 0.118 & 0.196 & 0.112 & 0.285 & 0.112 & 2453.99 & 2359.46 \\
    Swedbank AB & SWE   & 0.058 & 0.090 & 0.070 & 0.195 & 0.071 & 1856.19 & 1758.06 \\
    Credit Suisse Group & SWI   & 0.210 & 0.265 & 0.209 & 0.405 & 0.186 & 1040.23 & 999.14 \\
    UBS SG & SWI   & 0.151 & 0.194 & 0.159 & 0.351 & 0.196 & 1410.64 & 1352.78 \\
    ING Groep NV & NL    & 0.083 & 0.199 & 0.114 & 0.259 & 0.174 & 1270.56 & 1223.33 \\
    SNS Bank Netherlands & NL    & 0.128 & 0.072 & 0.056 & 0.165 & 0.039 & 128.21 & 123.64 \\
    Barclays PLC & UK    & 0.119 & 0.185 & 0.167 & 0.317 & 0.142 & 1560.52 & 1495.32 \\
    HBOS PLC & UK    & 0.065 & 0.209 & 0.115 & 0.317 & 0.217 & 568.00 & 540.36 \\
    Lloyds Banking Group & UK    & 0.166 & 0.207 & 0.117 & 0.228 & 0.156 & 966.05 & 919.46 \\
    Standard Chartered & UK    & 0.201 & 0.126 & 0.219 & 0.417 & 0.116 & 385.26 & 358.62 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

First variant with class option `12pt`, now the height becomes too large,
the following example tries to fit the table on the page without a smaller
font:

- If it is possible to write into the margin (as `\marginpar` does), then
  the bank column can be made wider to avoid line breaks.
- Because of class option `twoside`, the margin can be at the left or right side depending on the oddity of the page number. Package `zref-abspage` is used to write a label with the absolute page number to check it in the next LaTeX run. Therefore two LaTeX runs are necessary.
- The height is still to large (about 20pt), thus `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{.95}` makes the row heights smaller.

Source:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\newif\ifpageodd
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\labelforpageodd}[1]{%
  \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{abspage}%
  \zref@refused{#1}%
  \ifodd\zref@extractdefault{#1}{abspage}{\value{page}}%
    \pageoddtrue
  \else
    \pageoddfalse
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\DeclareRobustCommand*{% robust version needed because of column type S
  \tabstack}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3\tabcolsep}
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.95}
  \newcommand*{\tabdate}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \settowidth{\dimen0 }{10 Mar}%
      \hbox to \dimen0{\hss #1\hss}%
    \endgroup
  }
  \labelforpageodd{bank}
  \caption{Add caption}
  \ifpageodd
  \else
    \hspace*{-\marginparsep}\hspace{-\marginparwidth}%
  \fi
    \begin{tabular}{
      c
      c
      *{5}{S[table-format=1.3]}
      *{2}{S[table-format=4.2]}
    }
    \toprule
    Bank  & \hspace{-\tabcolsep}Country\hspace{-\tabcolsep}\null &
      \multicolumn{5}{c}{%
        Conditional joint probability of default%
      }
      & \tabstack{Total\\assets}
      & \tabstack{Total\\liabilities} \\
    \midrule
      &
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{15 Sept}\\2008}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{10 Mar}\\2009}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{2 May}\\2010}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{25 Nov}\\2011}
      & \tabstack{\tabdate{19 Dec}\\2013}
      &       &  \\
    \cmidrule(r{\tabcolsep}){3-7}
    Erste Group Bank AG & AUT   & 0.084 & 0.133 & 0.094 & 0.201 & 0.091 & 209.30 & 194.12 \\
    Raiffeisen Bank & AUT   & 0.094 & 0.121 & 0.080 & 0.256 & 0.097 & 146.63 & 135.69 \\
    Dexia SA & BEL   & 0.052 & 0.111 & 0.059 & 0.154 & 0.060 & 412.05 & 412.37 \\
    KBC Groep NV & BEL   & 0.145 & 0.140 & 0.123 & 0.256 & 0.134 & 282.94 & 266.17 \\
    Danske Bank A/S & DEN   & 0.071 & 0.118 & 0.071 & 0.191 & 0.075 & 3422.61 & 3296.76 \\
    BNP Paribas & FRA   & 0.230 & 0.293 & 0.209 & 0.333 & 0.208 & 1955.94 & 1870.31 \\
    Credit Agricole SA & FRA   & 0.156 & 0.286 & 0.151 & 0.330 & 0.162 & 1718.51 & 1669.22 \\
    Natixis & FRA   & 0.108 & 0.119 & 0.146 & 0.404 & 0.164 & 504.50 & 487.11 \\
    Societe Generale & FRA   & 0.168 & 0.285 & 0.167 & 0.278 & 0.166 & 1176.79 & 1125.68 \\
    Commerzbank AG & GER   & 0.182 & 0.335 & 0.180 & 0.277 & 0.153 & 657.61 & 630.23 \\
    Deutsche Bank AG & GER   & 0.182 & 0.262 & 0.146 & 0.322 & 0.204 & 2155.37 & 2100.71 \\
    IKB Bank & GER   & 0.038 & 0.052 & 0.055 & 0.202 & 0.051 & 31.25 & 30.27 \\
    Alpha Bank & GRE   & 0.034 & 0.060 & 0.031 & 0.096 & 0.035 & 57.68 & 56.25 \\
    Allied Irish Banks PLC & IRE   & 0.040 & 0.062 & 0.037 & 0.124 & 0.019 & 132.96 & 118.50 \\
    Irish Life and Permanent & IRE   & 0.038 & 0.071 & 0.039 & 0.097 & 0.090 & 71.85 & 68.34 \\
    Bank of Ireland & IRE   & 0.035 & 0.061 & 0.040 & 0.109 & 0.092 & 153.50 & 143.25 \\
    Banca Italease & ITA   & 0.030 & 0.043 & 0.081 & 0.336 & 0.105 & 10.53 & 8.89 \\
    Banca Monte dei Paschi di Siena & ITA   & 0.117 & 0.261 & 0.115 & 0.205 & 0.068 & 234.03 & 223.05 \\
    Banca Popolare di Milano & ITA   & 0.166 & 0.232 & 0.132 & 0.224 & 0.079 & 51.22 & 47.16 \\
    Banco Popolare SC & ITA   & 0.110 & 0.119 & 0.090 & 0.157 & 0.084 & 130.86 & 121.44 \\
    Intesa Sanpaolo SpA & ITA   & 0.158 & 0.242 & 0.131 & 0.230 & 0.162 & 626.90 & 579.14 \\
    Mediobanca SpA & ITA   & 0.152 & 0.242 & 0.129 & 0.259 & 0.152 & 74.80 & 67.77 \\
    UniCredit SpA & ITA   & 0.133 & 0.162 & 0.116 & 0.336 & 0.164 & 914.11 & 859.31 \\
    Banco Comercial Portugues SA & POR   & 0.097 & 0.147 & 0.078 & 0.148 & 0.075 & 91.92 & 87.54 \\
    Espirito Santo Financial Group & POR   & 0.076 & 0.126 & 0.075 & 0.198 & 0.092 & 79.53 & 73.54 \\
    Banco Bilbao Vizcaya & SPA   & 0.185 & 0.251 & 0.154 & 0.321 & 0.164 & 3198.97 & 3082.27 \\
    Banco de Sabadell SA & SPA   & 0.067 & 0.120 & 0.085 & 0.195 & 0.103 & 1180.67 & 1126.09 \\
    Banco Santander SA & SPA   & 0.178 & 0.249 & 0.169 & 0.325 & 0.163 & 1226.99 & 1179.73 \\
    Nordea Bank & SWE   & 0.108 & 0.193 & 0.097 & 0.243 & 0.110 & 6397.94 & 6164.55 \\
    Skandinaviska Enskilda Banken & SWE   & 0.077 & 0.112 & 0.073 & 0.192 & 0.078 & 2361.34 & 2252.18 \\
    Svenska Handelsbanken AB & SWE   & 0.118 & 0.196 & 0.112 & 0.285 & 0.112 & 2453.99 & 2359.46 \\
    Swedbank AB & SWE   & 0.058 & 0.090 & 0.070 & 0.195 & 0.071 & 1856.19 & 1758.06 \\
    Credit Suisse Group & SWI   & 0.210 & 0.265 & 0.209 & 0.405 & 0.186 & 1040.23 & 999.14 \\
    UBS SG & SWI   & 0.151 & 0.194 & 0.159 & 0.351 & 0.196 & 1410.64 & 1352.78 \\
    ING Groep NV & NL    & 0.083 & 0.199 & 0.114 & 0.259 & 0.174 & 1270.56 & 1223.33 \\
    SNS Bank Netherlands & NL    & 0.128 & 0.072 & 0.056 & 0.165 & 0.039 & 128.21 & 123.64 \\
    Barclays PLC & UK    & 0.119 & 0.185 & 0.167 & 0.317 & 0.142 & 1560.52 & 1495.32 \\
    HBOS PLC & UK    & 0.065 & 0.209 & 0.115 & 0.317 & 0.217 & 568.00 & 540.36 \\
    Lloyds Banking Group & UK    & 0.166 & 0.207 & 0.117 & 0.228 & 0.156 & 966.05 & 919.46 \\
    Standard Chartered & UK    & 0.201 & 0.126 & 0.219 & 0.417 & 0.116 & 385.26 & 358.62 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \ifpageodd
    \nobreak
    \hspace{-\marginparsep}\hspace{-\marginparwidth}\null
  \fi
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result 12pt]

Comment: beautiful (as always) :) the only thing that might improve things is to use a decimal alignment column on the last two columns, something like `S` from `siunitx`

Comment: @cmhughes: The danger is, that the width is becoming larger because of the additional alignment constraints. But in this case it can be done with the right values for option `table-format`, see the updated answer.

Comment: I would load the `caption` package to have correct vertical skips for the caption when, like here, it is above the table. And perhaps right- or left-align the first column.

Comment: the gaps between the five dated columns are slightly different in width, which i find a bit distracting.  the date headings might be packed into boxes of equal width to overcome the width discrepancies.  also, i see no reason that the period after the month is needed,

Comment: Thanks. This is great. Just one thing, I have font 12 selected `\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt]{article}` so the table messes up. How do I fix this?

Comment: @TrueTears: I do not know the layout of the document. If the margin par area is used and available, the updated answer shows, how it can be used. Otherwise `\footnotesize` for option `10pt` is `\scriptsize` for option `12pt` (however `\scriptsize` is a little too small for my taste). Alternatively package `longtable` can be used to make a table that spans two pages.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Please see edit. Basically when I remove the `12pt` option, the table shows up nicely. If I don't remove it, the table messes up. I need to have the `12pt` because I have text in the document as well.

Comment: @TrueTears: If you can let the table stick into the margin, then see the updated answer. Otherwise `\scriptsize` instead of `\footnotesize` can be used. Or a table with two packages can be made with `longtable`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Oh right! `\scriptsize` fixed it :)

Answer (score 7):

You've told us the size of the sheet of paper (A4), but we lack information regarding the width of the text block or, equivalently, the widths of the margins. In the example below, I assume 1" margins.

Some suggestions:

- Use `\multicolumn{5}{c}{...}` to typeset the material that spans five columns.
- Split the headers of the final two columns to make them less wide
- The five dates each take up a lot of space -- I suggest one way of writing them more compactly, but there are obviously other choices too. Furthermore, the dates really belong in the header part of the table, i.e., before `\midrule`. You can use `\cmidrule` to separate the dates from their respective header.
- I suggest left-aligning the first two columns. I would also like to suggest aligning the numerical data on their respective decimal points; this may be done by using the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package.
- Finally, what to do about the long names in the first column? I suggest wrapping them to the next line if they're too long. Here, "too long" is determined by the width of the text block (which constrains the overall width of the table). To assure that you're using the full width of the text block (but no more), I suggest you employ the `tabularx` environment (provided by the package with the same name) instead of `tabular` and specify a variant of the `X` column type for the first column.
- With all these choices in place, you can even get by with a `\small` font directive instead of a `\footnotesize` directive. I think your readers will appreciate that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % specify margins here
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt
\small
\caption{Add caption}\label{tab:big}
\smallskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L l
     *{5}{S[table-format=1.3]}
     *{2}{S[table-format=4.2]} @{}}
\toprule
Bank  & Country & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Conditional joint probability of default} & {Total} & {Total} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-7}
&  & {15/09/08} & {10/03/09} & {2/05/10} & {25/11/11} & {19/12/13} & {Assets} &  {Liab.}\\
\midrule
    Erste Group Bank AG & AUT   & 0.084 & 0.133 & 0.094 & 0.201 & 0.091 & 209.30 & 194.12 \\
    Raiffeisen Bank & AUT   & 0.094 & 0.121 & 0.080 & 0.256 & 0.097 & 146.63 & 135.69 \\
    Dexia SA & BEL   & 0.052 & 0.111 & 0.059 & 0.154 & 0.060 & 412.05 & 412.37 \\
    KBC Groep NV & BEL   & 0.145 & 0.140 & 0.123 & 0.256 & 0.134 & 282.94 & 266.17 \\
    Danske Bank A/S & DEN   & 0.071 & 0.118 & 0.071 & 0.191 & 0.075 & 3422.61 & 3296.76 \\
    BNP Paribas & FRA   & 0.230 & 0.293 & 0.209 & 0.333 & 0.208 & 1955.94 & 1870.31 \\
    Credit Agricole SA & FRA   & 0.156 & 0.286 & 0.151 & 0.330 & 0.162 & 1718.51 & 1669.22 \\
    Natixis & FRA   & 0.108 & 0.119 & 0.146 & 0.404 & 0.164 & 504.50 & 487.11 \\
    Societe Generale & FRA   & 0.168 & 0.285 & 0.167 & 0.278 & 0.166 & 1176.79 & 1125.68 \\
    Commerzbank AG & GER   & 0.182 & 0.335 & 0.180 & 0.277 & 0.153 & 657.61 & 630.23 \\
    Deutsche Bank AG & GER   & 0.182 & 0.262 & 0.146 & 0.322 & 0.204 & 2155.37 & 2100.71 \\
    IKB Bank & GER   & 0.038 & 0.052 & 0.055 & 0.202 & 0.051 & 31.25 & 30.27 \\
    Alpha Bank & GRE   & 0.034 & 0.060 & 0.031 & 0.096 & 0.035 & 57.68 & 56.25 \\
    Allied Irish Banks PLC & IRE   & 0.040 & 0.062 & 0.037 & 0.124 & 0.019 & 132.96 & 118.50 \\
    Irish Life and Permanent & IRE   & 0.038 & 0.071 & 0.039 & 0.097 & 0.090 & 71.85 & 68.34 \\
    Bank of Ireland & IRE   & 0.035 & 0.061 & 0.040 & 0.109 & 0.092 & 153.50 & 143.25 \\
    Banca Italease & ITA   & 0.030 & 0.043 & 0.081 & 0.336 & 0.105 & 10.53 & 8.89 \\
    Banca Monte dei Paschi di Siena & ITA   & 0.117 & 0.261 & 0.115 & 0.205 & 0.068 & 234.03 & 223.05 \\
    Banca Popolare di Milano & ITA   & 0.166 & 0.232 & 0.132 & 0.224 & 0.079 & 51.22 & 47.16 \\
    Banco Popolare SC & ITA   & 0.110 & 0.119 & 0.090 & 0.157 & 0.084 & 130.86 & 121.44 \\
    Intesa Sanpaolo SpA & ITA   & 0.158 & 0.242 & 0.131 & 0.230 & 0.162 & 626.90 & 579.14 \\
    Mediobanca SpA & ITA   & 0.152 & 0.242 & 0.129 & 0.259 & 0.152 & 74.80 & 67.77 \\
    UniCredit SpA & ITA   & 0.133 & 0.162 & 0.116 & 0.336 & 0.164 & 914.11 & 859.31 \\
    Banco Comercial Portugues SA & POR   & 0.097 & 0.147 & 0.078 & 0.148 & 0.075 & 91.92 & 87.54 \\
    Espirito Santo Financial Group & POR   & 0.076 & 0.126 & 0.075 & 0.198 & 0.092 & 79.53 & 73.54 \\
    Banco Bilbao Vizcaya & SPA   & 0.185 & 0.251 & 0.154 & 0.321 & 0.164 & 3198.97 & 3082.27 \\
    Banco de Sabadell SA & SPA   & 0.067 & 0.120 & 0.085 & 0.195 & 0.103 & 1180.67 & 1126.09 \\
    Banco Santander SA & SPA   & 0.178 & 0.249 & 0.169 & 0.325 & 0.163 & 1226.99 & 1179.73 \\
    Nordea Bank & SWE   & 0.108 & 0.193 & 0.097 & 0.243 & 0.110 & 6397.94 & 6164.55 \\
    Skandinaviska Enskilda Banken & SWE   & 0.077 & 0.112 & 0.073 & 0.192 & 0.078 & 2361.34 & 2252.18 \\
    Svenska Handelsbanken AB & SWE   & 0.118 & 0.196 & 0.112 & 0.285 & 0.112 & 2453.99 & 2359.46 \\
    Swedbank AB & SWE   & 0.058 & 0.090 & 0.070 & 0.195 & 0.071 & 1856.19 & 1758.06 \\
    Credit Suisse Group & SWI   & 0.210 & 0.265 & 0.209 & 0.405 & 0.186 & 1040.23 & 999.14 \\
    UBS SG & SWI   & 0.151 & 0.194 & 0.159 & 0.351 & 0.196 & 1410.64 & 1352.78 \\
    ING Groep NV & NL    & 0.083 & 0.199 & 0.114 & 0.259 & 0.174 & 1270.56 & 1223.33 \\
    SNS Bank Netherlands & NL    & 0.128 & 0.072 & 0.056 & 0.165 & 0.039 & 128.21 & 123.64 \\
    Barclays PLC & UK    & 0.119 & 0.185 & 0.167 & 0.317 & 0.142 & 1560.52 & 1495.32 \\
    HBOS PLC & UK    & 0.065 & 0.209 & 0.115 & 0.317 & 0.217 & 568.00 & 540.36 \\
    Lloyds Banking Group & UK    & 0.166 & 0.207 & 0.117 & 0.228 & 0.156 & 966.05 & 919.46 \\
    Standard Chartered & UK    & 0.201 & 0.126 & 0.219 & 0.417 & 0.116 & 385.26 & 358.62 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: while i expect that most people looking at this table would understand that the date format is "day/month/year", u.s. readers might initially make a different assumption, and ask "what is month 15? ... oh!"  (at least the dates aren't presented in "julian" form ...)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Indeed, the abbreviated form of the date string might create momentary flashes of ambiguity. Should the OP choose to use such a date format, I trust he/she will take the time to define explicitly the date string formats in use throughout the document. :-)

Comment: The third upvote on this answer pushed my point count on this site to 80K. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use p type colums to limit column width: `p{2.5cm}` limits the columns width to 2.5 cm (contrary to c/l/r type colums which grow with the content)
2. Replace the table head with `Bank  & Country & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Conditional joint probability of default} & Total assets & Total liabilities \\` . The `\multicolumn`command joins the number of cells specified in the first bracket for that row.
3. Change the date format to numeric: `15.11.08`is shorter than `15. Sep. 2008`
4. Change the margins of the page which holds your table. See the answer here for how: [Change \textwidth and \textheight in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13449/change-textwidth-and-textheight-in-mid-document)
5. If all this does is not sufficient try to reduce font-size or use a font-type with a smaller letter-spacing / tracking.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer would be "use a (even) smaller font size", or wider margins (see the `geometry` package) but I assume you don't want to do that.

By best effort:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \footnotesize
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{llcccccp{0.4in}p{0.46in}}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Conditional joint probability of default} & & \\ \cmidrule{3-7}
    Bank & Country & \begin{turn}{90}15 Sept. 2008\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}10 Mar. 2009\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}2 May 2010\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}25 Nov.               2011\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}19 Dec. 2013\end{turn} & Total assets & Total \mbox{liabilities} \\
    \midrule
    Erste Group Bank AG & AUT   & 0.084 & 0.133 & 0.094 & 0.201 & 0.091 & 209.30 & 194.12 \\
    Raiffeisen Bank & AUT   & 0.094 & 0.121 & 0.080 & 0.256 & 0.097 & 146.63 & 135.69 \\
    \ldots \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

What I did:

1. The `Conditional joint probability of default` across 5 columns (see `\multicolumn`)
2. Rotate dates (see the `rotating` package) and put them above the `\midrule`
3. Add a `\cmidrule` to separate `Conditional joint...` and the dates
4. Moved all the other headers to the second header line (the one with the dates)
5. Changed the last two columns to `p{<width}` in order to make the `Total` headers break across two lines and thus making the columns narrower, and put `liabilities` inside an `\mbox` to keep it from being hyphenated

There's room for improvement, but maybe this is enough for you. Take at look at the [Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) for ideas.