# A3 pages within A4 doc

Tags: graphics

I'm writing my thesis and I'd like to insert A3 pages within my A4 document.
Is it possible to place figures with captions (as normal) on those A3?

I'm able to include full PDF pages which are A3 by `\includepdf`, however that way I can't have captions.

I get this error:

```
! Package caption Error: No float type
! Package caption Error\caprion outside float
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! If you're looking for a way to change the paper size mid-document, this question might be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code).

Comment: You could just zoom the A3 page down to A4 by using e.g. `\includegraphics[height=\textheight,page=1]{a3file}`.

Answer (score 13):

Here a solution based on my answer to [Change paper size in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document/21431#21431) which uses the `typearea` package. You might want to adjust the margin it generates. I'm also using `\afterpage` (`afterpage` package) to insert the float after the current page. This avoids half-filled pages before the figure.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[paper=A4,pagesize]{typearea}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy code
\begin{document}
\lipsum% Placed on A4

\afterpage{% Insert after the current page
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\begin{figure}[p]
   \includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{largeimage}%
   \caption{A large image which required A3}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
}

\lipsum% Placed on A4 again

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: where do I place "landscape" comment if I want this A3 page to be in landscape please? (I'm a complete beginner, sorry)

Comment: @Marta: Use `\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape,pagesize}` instead of `\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,pagesize}`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Thanks for the helpful post! How can I decrease the left and right margins of the generated A3 landscape page? Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: No idea right now. Please check the KOMA Skript manual for the right options.

Answer (score 10):

You can place the corresponding caption in each one of the A3 pages and then use the `addtolist` option  of `\includepdf` (refer to the package documentation for details on the arguments of the option) to add the caption to the list of figures and to assign a label to the figure. A simple example: first, let's create a test A3 page containing an image (the `demo` option is only to make the example compilable for everyone):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight]{figure}
  \captionof{figure}{A test figure included with the help of the \texttt{pdfpages} package}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Let's call the above document `figone.tex`, and compile it to obtain `figone.pdf`; for convenience in the example, save it in your current working directory.

Now, your main file can look something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\lipsum[1-10]\clearpage
\includepdf[pages=1,noautoscale,addtolist={1,figure,A test figure included with the help of the \texttt{pdfpages} package,fig:test1}]{figone}
\lipsum[1-10]
See Figure~\ref{fig:test1} on page~\pageref{fig:test1}

\end{document}
```

Compile the above document twice and you will have a five page document, with the A3 page included, having its entry in the LoF. You  will also have the possibility to refer to that figure with `\ref` and `\pageref`, and `hyperref` will create the correct hyperlinks.

Comment: However I still can't get the caption work and appear under my figure (although it is listed in the LoF).

Comment: @Marta: As I mentioned, the caption has to be already in the A3 page; I used the `\captionof` command provided by the `caption` package to produce a caption for the figure. If you can't (for some reason) modify the A3 document to add the caption there, let me know and I'll propose another solution.

Comment: @Marta: please notice that I don't use `\caption` but `\captionof` which requires the `caption` package. Do you have an updated LaTeX installation?

Comment: \documentclass[a3paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=2cm, left=4cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\leavevmode
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/Thesis/Pictures_Research/Well_sect_flt_kpfsch.jpg}
\captionof{/Thesis/Pictures_Research/Well_sect_flt_kpfsch.jpg}{Palaeo-morphology of the Base Permian Unconformity after flattening on the Top Kupferschiefer horizon}
\end{center}
\end{figure} 


\end{document}

Comment: @Marta: the first argument of `\captionof` declares the type of object (e.g., `figure` or `table`). Besides, you don't really need the `figure` environment here (if you are going to use it, the use `\caption` instead of `\captionof`). You can say (I omit the preamble): `\begin{document}\begin{center} \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/Thesis/Pictures_Research/Well_sect_flt_kpfsc‌​h.jpg} \captionof{figure}{Palaeo-morphology of the Base Permian Unconformity after flattening on the Top Kupferschiefer horizon} \end{center}\end{document}`

Comment: How do you make the caption of a figure in A3 page, to follow numbering of the figures in the main file, after including it there with \includepdf[...] command please? Also, how do I adjust page numbering position in this included A3 page (at the moment, the number is offset to the left, instead of being centered)

Comment: @Marta: Please open new questions with these new requirements. You can link this question in the new ones to indicate a follow up.