# \includepdf in A3 format

Tags: page-numbering, appendices, pdfpages, paper-size

I am creating an A4 document and I need to insert a longtable in A3 into this document.

I have created a document for this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,landscape,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

 \begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{List Sandwaves}

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{| r | l | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c| c|}
        \caption{Sandwaves} \\ 
            .....
\end{longtable}%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And then the man document is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\includepdf[pages=1-4,noautoscale,landscape,addtolist={1, table , Ondas de Arena, Todas}]{Tabla.pdf}

\end{document}
```

I have several problems with this:

1. The A3 document work fine but then when I compile the main document the page size is still A4 and no A3 as it should be.
2. The Appendix does not show in the table of contents.
3. The table does show in the list of tables, but not with the right number (it uses the number of the chapter before and not the appendix).
4. The pages numbers do not correspond with the ones they should in the main     document it keeps the numbers of the A3 doc.

I am a beginner on LaTeX so I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Look at this: [A3 pages within A4 doc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/a3-pages-within-a4-doc). Does that helps?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Also do not surround a `longtable` with `\begin{center}` it has no effect on longtable but does in general introduce spurious vertical space

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up using the hugepage newenvironment and removed the \begincenter...