# why do I get 'Undefined control sequence' for KOMAoptions?

Tags: errors

I am trying to include A3 pages in an A4 LaTeX document (following this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21433)) but get the following
when I run `pdflatex`:

```
Chapter 1.
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2]
! Undefined control sequence.
\AP@ ->{ \clearpage \KOMAoptions 
                             {paper=a3,paper=landscape} \recalctypearea ...
l.27 \end{document}

?
```

[SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,pagesize]{report}
\usepackage{pslatex,palatino,avant,graphicx,color,nextpage,afterpage,comment}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
foo
\clearpage
bar

\afterpage{ % Insert after the current page
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a3,paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
A3 stuff goes here ...
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
}


\end{document}
```

I understand that "undefined control sequence" means I've forgotten to use some package on my document preamble. However it is not clear to me what's wrong in this case.

Comment: You are not using the KOMA version of report, `scrreprt`, and I think that's why your code is not reading the \recalctypearea... you either load the package or you change your documentclass to include the KOMA versio of report

Comment: @MarioS.E. which package should I load?

Comment: It's the [`typearea`](http://ctan.org/pkg/typearea) package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preamble of LaTeX files usually starts with `\documentclass`. You use the documentclass `report`, which is included in LaTeX. The KOMA-script bundle offers its own documentclasses: scrartcl instead of article, screprt instead of report and scrbook instead of book.

So please switch from report to screprt for using KOMA-script commands. You don't need to load typearea, if you do this. In case you just need some features of KOMAscript, have a look at the package `scrextend`.

I did not test your example regarding the size of the included page. But it is a bad idea to mix geometry and typearea. Choose one of them and stick to it.