# Override global page style?

Tags: header-footer, sphinx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change paper size in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document)

How can I use default

```
\documentclass[a4paper]
```

styles in Title page, index pages, header and footer - but the text itself as if I were using

```
\documentclass[a4paper]
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=6cm]{geometry}
```

The point is - long lines are not convenient to read, while I want to use `A4` paper - to include code listings (I can exceed `right=6cm` manually in verbatim environment). And code listings look better at A4 paper (otherwise I have to cut lines all the time...)

P.S. Actually I get `latex` from sphinx. But I'm interested in general solutions as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
\newgeometry{<args>}
```

you can change the geometry options for the page that follows; and then

```
\restoregeometry
```

get you back to the initial config.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=6cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\clearpage
\newgeometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=2.5cm}
\blindtext
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: MWE gives me:
`Undefined control sequence. l.7 \newgeometry`. I'm also interested in specifiying newgeometry inside a single page. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't have the `Undefined control sequence` warning here (maybe it's a sphinx issue). Specifying a new geometry within a single page is precisely what the example does: both `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` commands will start a clear page by their very definition (I only added the `\clearpage` commands to illustrate it). Please, check if this question is not a duplicate to <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document>, as suggested by egreg (if so, consider closing this question)

Comment: I've googled my `udefined newgeometry` and found out that I have an outdated `texlive` and in particular - outdated `geometry` (I'm on `kubutnu 12.04`). I'm now updating it all (using the [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa)) - and I think everything will be working after that.

Comment: Now it works - but I get the page breaks even without `\clearpage`.