# why can't I get the A3 page where I want it (inside an A4 document)

Tags: geometry, afterpage

I am using an A3 page within an A4 document.

In the [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) example below, my plan was to get (in this order):

1. "foo" on an A4 page
2. "A3 stuff" on an A3 page
3. "bar" on an A4 page

Instead, I get:

1. "foo" on an A4 page
2. "bar" on an A4 page
3. "A3 stuff" on an A3 page

That is, correct page sizes but wrong order. What am I missing?

code below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,pagesize]{report}
\usepackage{nextpage}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\begin{document}

foo

\newpage
\clearpage
\pagebreak

\afterpage{ % Insert after the current page
\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{paper=a3} 
\recalctypearea

A3 stuff

\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
}


bar

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\afterpage` works *after* the current page. And, since you're setting your A3 page on page two within the `\afterpage` construction, most certainly it will end up on page 3. Move the `\clearpage` to *after* your `\afterpage` construction. You don't need `\newpage` *and* `\pagebreak` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the changing of page geometry mid-document is covered in [Change paper size in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6834/5764), I'll only address the order of how items appear when using [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) in this answer.

`\afterpage` works *after* the current page. And, since you're setting your A3 page on page two within the `\afterpage` construction, most certainly it will end up on page 3. So, the following prints `foo` on page 1, `bar` on page 2 and `foobar` on page 3:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Only for this example
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}

\Huge
\afterpage{bar \clearpage}% Insert this AFTER the current page

foo

\clearpage

foobar

\end{document}
```