# Why does \newgeometry from the geometry package not change the papersize?

Tags: geometry, paper-size

What technical reasons are behind this?

From [manual of package geometry](http://mirror.macomnet.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf):

> ... paper size options (such as papersize,
>   paper=a4paper and so forth), which can’t be changed with `\newgeometry`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but in case you want a workaround: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document?rq=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thank @DavidCarlisle and @UlrikeFischer for the support in providing this answer

`paperwidth` and `paperheight` are LaTeX lenghts, which are then ultimately converted in eg `pdftex` into the lenghts `pdfpagewidth` and `pdfpageheight` using this snippet:

```
\ifGin@setpagesize
\ifx\paperwidth\@undefined\else
  \AtBeginDocument{%
% If a package has changed \mag, assume it knows what it is doing
% and leave page size alone
\ifnum\mag=\@m
  \@ifundefined{stockwidth}{%
  \@ifundefined{paperwidth}{%
  }{%
    \ifdim\paperwidth>0pt\relax
      \ifdim\paperheight>0pt\relax
        \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
        \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}{%
  \ifdim\stockwidth>0pt\relax
    \ifdim\stockheight>0pt\relax
      \pdfpagewidth=\stockwidth
      \pdfpageheight=\stockheight
    \fi
  \fi
}%
\fi
}
```

The "LaTeX" counterparts are discarded after the document has started (meaning they are not meaningful anymore), while the `pdf` counterparts are the ones ultimately used for setting.

Geometry sets the `pdf` lengths also at the begin of the document, possibly to maintain compatibility with the `dvips` drivers (which do not support multiple page sizes), so it does not allow them to be reset during the document, thus discarding the paper resizing options

Comment: Imho the main reason is that with e.g. the dvips driver it simply doesn't work to have to different papersizes in the document.