# Why is LaTeX creating an empty page after an image?

Tags: graphics

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, pdftex]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage [bottom=2cm, top=3cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\input{./Title.tex}

\newgeometry{left=0cm, right=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm}

\includegraphics[angle=-0.87]{Folha_de_rosto}

\restoregeometry

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\end{document}
```

When I compile the file, an empty page is created between the title and the image inserted with `\includegraphics`. When I don't use `\newgeometry`, it doesn't happen. The image that I want to use has the size of a whole page. So, when I try to include the image without changing the margins, it is displaced and a part of it is cut out, because it's out of the page. I don't know any other way to correct this displacement. Does anyone kwon why it is happening? Is there any other way to correct the displacement of the image besides changing margins?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post full documents, not documents ending halfway down to the end... and `\newgeometry` does the `\clearpage`, since the page parameters change completely. Do you really need a new page geometry after the page title?

Comment: Since the titlepage is something relatively static, you can do that as an extra document and include the page using `\includepdf`.

Comment: If those are the correct parameters for the title page, issue the `\newgeometry` before `\input{Title}`. But it is hard to think of a case where this would be truly necessary. Since we don't know what is wrong with the image's displacement, the second question isn't really answerable.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you'd ever need a `\newgeometry`/`\restoregeometry` around an `\includegraphics`

Comment: What happens is that the image that I want to use has the size of a whole page. So, when I try to include the image without changing the margins, it is displaced and a part of it is cut out, because it's out of the page. I don't know any other way to correct this displacement, so I would be really grateful if someone would tell me one.

Comment: @WillianBicaio -- include the information about the size of the image in your question.  that would avoid some of the questions raised in the comments.

Comment: @WillianBicaio: Usually, whole pages are included with `\includepdf` (from the _pdfpages_ package), not with `\includegraphics`.  In this case, I'm a bit confused by the very small rotation angle, that makes your intentions unclear.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239786/landscape-a3-page-in-portrait-a4-document-adds-a-blank-page-or-reorients-previ/239867#239867

Comment: There are several ways to include a picture in the background of a page, package `eso-pic`, `tikz`, `texpos`, `scrlayer-scrpage` ...