# Change page style of page a floating element is finally being placed

Tags: floats, koma-script, scrbook, pagestyle

I sometimes use a figure which extends into the marginpar and towards the page header while being placed at the top, something like that
[image]
generated from this MWE:

```
\documentclass[automark]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Chapter}

\clearpage
\section{My Section Left}

pewpew

% So that we have a headmark on the right

\clearpage
\section{My Section Right}

Here is some text. Followed by a float extending into the marginpar and to
the top.

\begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{addmargin*}[0pt]{\dimexpr-\marginparwidth - \marginparsep}
    \vspace*{-\headsep}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \rule{\textwidth}{5cm}
      \caption{Foo}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{addmargin*}
\end{figure}

Compare this to a normal inline figure.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
   \rule{\textwidth}{5cm}
   \caption{Bar}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For the **final page** where the float is being placed, I want to remove the page header, ie, `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

However, for the life of mine, I'm unable to achieve this. I have found no way to reliably run `\thispagestyle{}` on the actual page. I tried the `floatpag` package, `everypage` package, etc. but nothing worked. Sometimes, the style is applied to the page before or after.

I'm using the `scrbook` class.

**Edit:**

The only reliable way I've found to be working, is a simple hack to place a white `\rule` on top of the text, \ie, move the figure a bit more to the top and put the `\rule` in this place. That however only works for the top (sufficient for me though) and the text can still be selected in the resulting PDF (it is still there).

```
\vspace*{\dimexpr-\headsep - 1cm}\textcolor{white}{\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}\\[0pt]}
```

**Edit 2:** I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248490/211192) to basically the same question. However, this only works if you define the label list that is being created upfront, **not dynamically**. If the list is build dynamically by using `\listxadd` in place of the figure, the shipout hook does not see the added label if the figure is not moved to the next page, which means it misses some pages where to change the page style. Note that I would prefer this dynamic way, as I use a key-value-command to build these figures and do want to do everything automatically in there.

Comment: the markup seems over complicated, why the minipage? but a float is set at the point it is specified and just used as a box on the page it  is placed so your tests are testing the wrong page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added a complete MWE. This was essentially the code I ended up with that actually worked. Simplifications welcome though.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427572/remove-header-footer-on-page-with-large-figure

Comment: @JohnKormylo This is for `[p]` floats, which does not apply here. But thanks.

Comment: Just because it CAN work on [p] floats doesn't mean it ONLY works on [p] floats.