# Insert large horizontal page to document

Tags: pdftex, texpad

I am trying to insert a large diagram to my document. The diagram is too large to be inserted to a horizontal A4 page. What is the best way to add a single A3 or A2 page to a document?

This is the outline of the document:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    oneside,
    10.5pt,
    fleqn,
    headsepline,
    toc=listofnumbered, 
    bibliography=totocnumbered,
    glossary=totocnumbered,
    abstract=on
    ]{scrartcl}

%%% CONFIG
% Document Formating

\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            left=3.35cm,right=2.12cm,top=3.75cm,bottom=2.88cm,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% Project Plan Package
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
%%% PACKAGES

%URL
\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

% MATH
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% CODE
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}

% COLORS / IMAGES
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


% CITATION / BIBLIOGRAPHY
\usepackage[numberedbib]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\newcommand*{\quelle}[1]{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize Quelle:~#1}

% GLOSSARY
\usepackage[style=super,toc,nopostdot,numberedsection]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\loadglsentries{glossary}


LOREM IPSUM

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: This might be a nice alternative https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239786/landscape-a3-page-in-portrait-a4-document-adds-a-blank-page-or-reorients-previ