# Including an odd sized PDF

Tags: graphics

I am trying to include an odd sized graph in between to pages as a graph however, the graph is automatically sized on an A4 page. My graph has a different background color, so ideally I would like to have only my graph with its odd size and not my graph printed on a white A4 page and autosized.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a minimal working example so that we can help you.

Comment: I am very newbie to LaTeX so I used one line that I saw somehere.

code is : 
\includepdf[pages={1}]{src/img/branding/table.pdf}

the table has a rectangular form, slimmer than an A4 in width. 
I don't know what else to tell you about it.

Comment: If it will fit into the text area, use \includegraphics[page=1]{src/img/branding/table.pdf} from the graphicx package.  If source is only one page, you can skip the [page=1].

Comment: The thing is my table is on an A4 page. I don't want my table to be printed on a page at all. 
Imaging a table 150x297 which is black. An A4 is 210 x 297. So there are 60cms (30 on each side) of white remainings of the page. 
I would like to have my odd sized table to be a custom made page itself with nothing on the background. Only the table and nothing white left at the background. 

I am sorry if I am not expressing myself properly. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: @latexguy Do you want to adapt page size to your table size (read [Change paper size in mid-document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document))?

Comment: A sketch, what you like to have is the same as 1000 words ... try to include your table with `\includepdf[<options>]{file.pdf}` and table make for example with `standalone` with desired size.

Comment: \includepdf[fitpaper]{src/img/branding/table.pdf} worked!

Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Should @Zarko answer, do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases, when a some page in text should have completely different layout, seems to be the best way to make this page separately (for example by help of document class `standalone` or extracting content with `preview` package) and than include it as pdf page:

```
\includepdf[<options>]{file.pdf}
```

In your case (as you said in your comment):

```
\includepdf[fitpaper]{table.pdf}
```