# two different pagestyles

Tags: packages, document-classes

I am trying to do a document in which I have a text box in the first page and the rest of document I have fancy style.

I tried to do it and I can do it if I do two different documents (and so two different tex files).
In the first one I used

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop}
```

and in the second one I used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Is there any way to do just one document?

Answer (score 1):

## Short explanation of the changes needed

- **Pagestyle:** You can easily change the pagestyle for a single page using `\thispagestyle{style}`, or for all pages following, using the macro `\pagestyle{style}`, both from the `fancyhdr`-package.
- **Layout** The `geometry`-package makes it quite easy to change margins, textwidth, height and so on for a page with it's commands `\newgeometry{arguments}` and `\restoregeometry` to the original settings.
- **Papersize**
  Changing the size of the paper in the middle of a document is more difficult, and to make those changes I have been using the information found in the answer by *Charles Stewart* in the post [Change paper size in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6838/89976). There are other alternative answers there, well worth the read.

---

What I've done is first setting a standard-pagesize, and then storing the the dimensions of that page into the lengths called `\originalPaperWidth` and `\originalPaperHeight` to be able to restore the page to that dimension.

## Usage

I've created two macros, `\changePaper{width}{height}[optional arguments for \newgeometry]` and `\restorePaper`, which should make it easy to create custom pages. Use this in combination with `\thispagestyle{style}` or `\pagestyle{style}`

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse} % Needed for newdocumentcommand
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\newlength{\originalPaperHeight}
\newlength{\originalPaperWidth}
\setlength{\originalPaperHeight}{\pdfpageheight}
\setlength{\originalPaperWidth}{\pdfpagewidth}

\newcommand{\restorePaperSize}{%
\clearpage%
\pdfpagewidth=\originalPaperWidth \pdfpageheight=\originalPaperHeight
\restoregeometry
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\changePaper}{mmO{}}{%
    % Input:
    % #1: width
    % #2: height
    % #3: optional arguments for \newgeometry
    \pdfpagewidth=#1 \pdfpageheight=#2
\newgeometry{layoutwidth=#1,layoutheight=#2,#3}
    }
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\changePaper{16cm}{23cm}[margin=1cm,top=2cm]
\section{Special page}
\lipsum[1-2]
\restorePaperSize
\section{Back to normal fancy pages}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am trying with this code:

### Code

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum

%now i want to use \documentclass[a4paper,twoside]
\newpage
\newgeometry{a4paper,twoside}
\restoregeometry
\lipsum

\end{document}


The first part is ok but the second is not...what is supposed to write in newgeometry?

Comment: '\newgeometry' cannot change the papersize.