# Insert new page with size of inserted image

Tags: macros, graphics, size

I am creating a template for document creation, where I need to insert images of *varying* sizes (sometimes 1024px, sometimes ~4000px wide). Those images can be oriented both vertically and horizontally.

The problem is, I can't afford to have them shrunk (there is text in them).
Is there a way to force LaTeX to create a new page as big as the picture, which picture would fully fill?

I thought of a macro, which would end document style and temporarily use a different one (change pages to horizontal, change sizes...), but I don't think this would handle sizes well.

In the past, I did this manually via Adobe Acrobat (which was able to insert an image as an independent page with its own size).
I use MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: Short answer: Use [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) or [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) depending on what you want (include an image page to LaTeX or create a page reduced to the contents).

Comment: pdfpages looks like it inserts pdf pages, I have those images in .jpg, .png or something like that. Anyway, it might work with some effort.
Does it preserve the size of included pages?  

About standalone package, I can't really imagine how would I use it.
Ideally, I would like to create macro, which would take image.jpg(.png...) as an argument and create a new page, which would contain only image.jpg

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document OTOH, are you sure you are losing resolution?   A PDF viewer with a zoom feature should be able to recover the full resolution (and the resulting PDF files can become huge).

Comment: You mean that if I were to insert image into a page and it was resized, it stil should be able to recover the full resolution? Like putting 4600px * 3450px on A4 page and with enough zoom, it would still show it in original size?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to know the zoom factor to use.  Another option is to use \href (hyperref package) to link to the image file.

Comment: `pdfpages` cannot only insert PDFs but every image format `graphicx` can import. Using `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex` you can, e.g., also insert PNG or JPEG pages without loosing any pixel of the original file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using the PNG shown below.  While zooming in on the circle shows stair-stepping, both images when zoomed look the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/large.png}{link to web image}

\href[pdfnewwindow]{large.pdf}{link to local pdf}

\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{large.png}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{large.png}

\end{document}
```

### [image: example iamge]

It turns out you can only link to images on the web or local PDFs.  However, one can easily convert images to PDFs using standalone.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{large.png}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May I ask for an example of targeting local pdf? I tried \href{pom.pdf}{link to image}. pom.pdf is located in the same folder.

Comment: I tried to enter relative path \hyperbaseurl{pom.pdf} and 
absolute path \hyperbaseurl{D:\Test\Img\}, but that did not work. Main file has an image prepared in pom.pdf, which is in the same folder.
I tried googling, but I did not find much about \hyperbaseurl.

Comment: My experiments show that \hyperbaseurl has to go into the preamble.  My latest experiments show that the baseurl is ignored with local PDFs.  Weird!

Comment: The heart of \baseurl is the command  `\special{html:<base href="\@baseurl">}` which is executed AtBeginDocument.  In other words, the base url is written as HTML directly to the PDF driver.

Comment: I managed to find an easy way how to deal with this problem: http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/incgraph/incgraph.pdf ... "The graphics can
be centered for a given paper format or the paper may be resized to the graphics dimensions." It looks like it is exactly what I needed.
Thank you for your answers.