# Centering captions in document that contains A3 and A4 paper sizes

Tags: floats, captions, geometry, paper-size, paper

In order to fit multiple figures on one line, my document has A4 (portrait) and A3 (landscape) pages. To set up the A3 pages I created a new environment (a trick I adapted from another solution). Please note that I can't create a separate pdf for the A3 pages and add it in because figure references, pages, sections etc. will be constantly changing.

However, when I plot the figures on the A3 page, the main caption is placed as if it was A4. (See below) How do I center the caption relative to the A3 page?

[image: A3 doc caption is not centered]

I include the code without the text in the A4 sections:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Pictures & Labels
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
% Paper Style
\usepackage[a4paper,
            width=150 mm,
            top=25 mm,
            bottom=25 mm]
            {geometry}
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}
%% Allow A3 sheets - - New environment
\newenvironment{a3page}
{\newpage
\advance\textwidth\pdfpagewidth
\headwidth = \textwidth 
\pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth}
{\newpage}

\begin{document}

%% Start A3 page
\begin{a3page}
\section{Title}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{images/pic.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{images/pic.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{images/pic.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
                \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{images/pic.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{images/pic.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{images/pic.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.05\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{images/pic2.png}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \centering
        \caption{This caption isn't centered}\label{fig:}
\end{figure}
%
%
\end{a3page}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is more to a page layout, then just the well known parameters like `\textwidth`. For example, internally TeX uses `\hsize` for building paragraphs. The best is, to leave this to the `geometry` package.

Unfortunately, `\newgeometry` doesn't allow to switch between portrait and landscape or change the paper size mid document. But a macro can be written, which allows this. It's basically a changed copy of `\newgeometry`, called `\newgeometryfull` here. Use it with care! Additionally, `\pdfpageheight` and `\pdfpagewidth` must be set, so the PDF viewer also knows the paper size. This is done in the `a3page` environments.

I removed the line `\headwidth=\textwidth`, because `\headwidth` doesn't exist in your example. But may be you need it for headers not present here.

The result:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Pictures & Labels
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
% Paper Style
\usepackage[a4paper,
            width=150 mm,
            top=25 mm,
            bottom=25 mm]
            {geometry}
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% like \newgeometry, but also allows change of landscape/portrait and paper size
% to be used with caution!
\newcommand{\newgeometryfull}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \Gm@restore@org
  \Gm@initnewgm
%  \Gm@newgmtrue
  \setkeys{Gm}{#1}%
%  \Gm@newgmfalse
  \Gm@process
  \ifnum\mag=\@m\else\Gm@magtooffset\fi
  \Gm@changelayout
  \Gm@showparams{newgeometry}}%
\makeatother

%% Allow A3 sheets - - New environment
\newenvironment{a3page}{%
    \newgeometryfull{a3paper,landscape,width=360 mm,top=25 mm,bottom=25 mm}
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
}{%
    \restoregeometry
    % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
    \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
    \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
}

\begin{document}
\section{A test}
\lipsum[1]

%% Start A3 page
\begin{a3page}
\section{Title}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.14\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-9x16.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:a}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.14\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-9x16.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:b}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.14\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-9x16.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:c}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.14\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-9x16.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:d}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.14\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-9x16.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:e}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.14\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-9x16.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:f}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.14\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-9x16.png}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:g}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        \caption{This caption isn't centered}\label{fig:}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{a3page}

\section{Another test}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my not so elegant solution. I used

```
\eject \pdfpagewidth=16.5in \pdfpageheight=11.7in
```

To make the page have different size.
This solution is based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6838/75648). Now the caption gets centered.

[image: A3 paper after A4]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Pictures & Labels
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
% Paper Style
\usepackage[a4paper,
            width=150 mm,
            top=25 mm,
            bottom=25 mm]
            {geometry}
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}
 \begin{document}
A4 paper

%% Start A3 page
\eject \pdfpagewidth=16.5in \pdfpageheight=11.7in
\section{Title}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
                \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.16\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
                \caption{}
                \label{subfig:}
        \end{subfigure}%
        %
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.05\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \centering
        \caption{This caption isn't centered}\label{fig:}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. When I said I wanted the caption centering, I meant relative to the A3 page - not the pictures. I will update the question to improve clarity.

Comment: Your code only changes the paper size shown by the PDF viewer. It doesn't change anything for LaTeX, which still sets a portrait a4 page.

Comment: @Mike yep, I notice that when I added showframe. This is issue seems to be more complicated then I thought.