# Changing page geometry from A4Portrait to A3Portrait in the middle of the document

Tags: geometry, paper-size

I found this code for defining a A3Landscape environment here on StackExchange https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431435/278762:

```
   \makeatletter
    % like \newgeometry, but also allows change of landscape/portrait
    % and paper size to be used with caution!
    \newcommand{\newgeometryfull}[1]{%
      \clearpage
      \Gm@restore@org
      \Gm@initnewgm
    %  \Gm@newgmtrue
      \setkeys{Gm}{#1}%
    %  \Gm@newgmfalse
      \Gm@process
      \ifnum\mag=\@m\else\Gm@magtooffset\fi
      \Gm@changelayout
      \Gm@showparams{newgeometry}}%
   \makeatother

   %% Allow A3 sheets - - New environment
    \newenvironment{a3pageLandscape}{%
            \newgeometryfull{a3paper,landscape=true,top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}
            % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
        \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
        \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
            \headwidth=\textwidth
    }{%
        \restoregeometry
        % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
        \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
        \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
    }
```

**Using this `a3pageLandscape` environment produces the following output:**

[image]

This works pretty well.

Now, I was wondering if it is possible to change the environment from A3Landscape to A3Portrait. So I changed the code from `landscape=true` to`landscape=false`. See the complete new-enviroment here:

```
   %% Allow A3 sheets - - New environment
    \newenvironment{a3pagePortrait}{%
            \newgeometryfull{a3paper,landscape=false,top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}
            % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
        \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
        \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
            \headwidth=\textwidth
    }{%
        \restoregeometry
        % set the correct dimension for the PDF viewer
        \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
        \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
    }
```

**Using `a3pagePortrait` environment produces the following output:**

[image]

**QUESTION**: Does anybody know why my footer disappeared using `a3pagePortrait` environment on the next page?

Comment: What if you wanted to print the document using multiple page sizes?

Comment: @PeterWilson: Printer usually have "automatic paper size detection". Thus, the printer will choose the correct paper tray A4 or A3.

Comment: Sorry but I think that I can't help you.  It seems to be upto the printer you use. Peter W.

Comment: You're setting things geometry doesn't know about and are probably doing it only locally. But it is really impossible to say much with compilable code.