# Store the value of \pdfpagewidth

Tags: page-breaking

Consider this example (developed upon [Change paper size in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document?answertab=active#tab-top)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Normal page
\def\normalpdfpagewidth{\pdfpagewidth}

\eject \pdfpagewidth=17in
Wide page
\eject \pdfpagewidth=\normalpdfpagewidth
Normal page again
\end{document}
```

In this example I try to store the normal value of `\pdfpagewidth` in:

```
\def\normalpdfpagewidth{\pdfpagewidth}
```

and reapply this value in a succeeding page.

However, this trick has not worked out:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: `\pdfpaperwidth` is a dimension, hence to store it's value you'll need `\edef\normalpdfpagewidth{\the\pdfpagewidth}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `\pdfpagewidth=17in` or `\pdfpagewidth=\normalpdfpagewidth` you're assigning one *length* or *dimension* to another *length* or *dimension*. That's the syntax used for such assignments `<lenA>=<lenB>` (the `=` is optional) and copies the length of `<lenB>` into `<lenA>`. If `<lenB>` changes after the assignment, `<lenA>` still holds the original length of `<lenB>`.

In your case, you're `\def`ining some control sequence (or macro) to represent the length, as in `\def<csname>{<stuff>}`. And since TeX doesn't naturally expand its control sequence until its set on paper, any change in `<stuff>` is carried with `<csname>`. You either want the expanded version of the length ([as mentioned by muzimuzhi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622302/store-the-value-of-pdfpagewidth#comment1553491_622302))

```
\edef\normalpdfpagewidth{\the\pdfpagewidth}
```

or assign the lengths in a more natural way:

```
\newlength{\normalpdfpagewidth}
\setlength{\normalpdfpagewidth}{\pdfpagewidth}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\normalpdfpagewidth}

\begin{document}

Normal page

\setlength{\normalpdfpagewidth}{\pdfpagewidth}

\clearpage \setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{17in}

Wide page

\clearpage \setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\normalpdfpagewidth}

Normal page again

\end{document}
```