# Change orientation and paper size for single page

Tags: geometry, landscape, page, format, custom

My document consist of A3 pages in landscape orientation, except for the first page which I want to be in A4 portrait. How can I change the paper format and orientation of a single page?

I thought I could use `\newgeometry`:

```
\documentclass[a3paper]{report} % BTW, is 'a3paper' necessary here also?
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}
% ...

\begin{document}
% ...

\newgeometry{a4paper,portrait}
% ...
\restoregeometry

% ...
\end{document}
```

However, [1 Preface to Version 5 says](https://texdoc.org/serve/geometry.pdf/0) for `\newgeometry`: *(...) and skips the papersize-related
options: landscape, portrait and paper size options (such as papersize, paper=a4paper and so
forth).*

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: What is the difference between the what's included on the (first) A4 and (subsequent) A3 pages? Is there a need for textual flow from the A4 to A3?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document or if the first page is a kind of cover, you could create it as a standalone document and load it via `\includepdf` (package `pdfpages`).

Comment: @Werner: It is a submission. I wanted A4 portrait should be the intro, and then A3 landscape the presentations.

Comment: @cabohah: Yes, the first is a cover, so your solution is actually neat. The only thing is that I have to write double latex files and keep the settings synchronized. I can `\input` a common settings file, though.

Comment: I've read that different formats are not possible with DVI (standard latex output) but has to be PDF. And physically printing such a document is probably not a usual task for a printer. But in this digital age a PDF file can be made for digital view, like a submission of an assigment.