# Printing a very large picture using latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use latex to generate a PDF file of a very large Hasse diagram.

The picture is too large to fit into a normal page, so I wanted to ask whether it is somehow possible to make latex use larger sizes of paper where one can print the picture  (in German it is called Din A1 format). Or is there a way to distribute the picture into 8 or so pages so that I can print those 8 pages to fit them together after I printed them?

Thanks for any help.

Here is the Ti*k*Z pictures made with sage for the Hasse diagram (warning large text) of such an example (the actual example I'm interested in is actually about 3-5 times as large and the code is too long to post in this forum):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line join=bevel,]
%%
\node (node_0) at (308.5bp,8.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{\right\}$};
  \node (node_1) at (308.5bp,61.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1\right\}$};
  \node (node_2) at (308.5bp,114.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 3\right\}$};
  \node (node_3) at (259.5bp,114.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 5\right\}$};
  \node (node_4) at (357.5bp,114.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2\right\}$};
  \node (node_5) at (357.5bp,167.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3\right\}$};
  \node (node_8) at (228.5bp,167.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 3, 5\right\}$};
  \node (node_6) at (292.5bp,167.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 5\right\}$};
  \node (node_7) at (431.5bp,167.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 4\right\}$};
  \node (node_9) at (499.5bp,220.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4\right\}$};
  \node (node_10) at (221.5bp,220.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 5\right\}$};
  \node (node_11) at (363.5bp,220.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 6\right\}$};
  \node (node_12) at (292.5bp,220.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 10, 5\right\}$};
  \node (node_13) at (431.5bp,220.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 4, 5\right\}$};
  \node (node_16) at (145.5bp,220.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 3, 5, 15\right\}$};
  \node (node_17) at (378.5bp,273.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\right\}$};
  \node (node_27) at (538.5bp,273.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 6\right\}$};
  \node (node_15) at (221.5bp,273.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 5, 10\right\}$};
  \node (node_18) at (301.5bp,273.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6\right\}$};
  \node (node_19) at (139.5bp,273.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 5, 15\right\}$};
  \node (node_14) at (458.5bp,273.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 4, 5, 10\right\}$};
  \node (node_22) at (410.5bp,326.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10\right\}$};
  \node (node_36) at (592.5bp,326.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 4, 5, 20, 10\right\}$};
  \node (node_20) at (39.5bp,326.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 15\right\}$};
  \node (node_21) at (226.5bp,326.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10\right\}$};
  \node (node_23) at (318.5bp,326.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15\right\}$};
  \node (node_28) at (500.5bp,326.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\right\}$};
  \node (node_24) at (134.5bp,326.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 15\right\}$};
  \node (node_25) at (121.5bp,379.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15\right\}$};
  \node (node_26) at (227.5bp,379.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15\right\}$};
  \node (node_29) at (432.5bp,379.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10\right\}$};
  \node (node_38) at (536.5bp,379.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 10\right\}$};
  \node (node_32) at (331.5bp,379.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 15\right\}$};
  \node (node_33) at (227.5bp,432.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 15\right\}$};
  \node (node_34) at (109.5bp,432.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30\right\}$};
  \node (node_41) at (345.5bp,432.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20\right\}$};
  \node (node_30) at (687.5bp,326.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12\right\}$};
  \node (node_31) at (666.5bp,379.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12\right\}$};
  \node (node_39) at (693.5bp,432.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12\right\}$};
  \node (node_40) at (463.5bp,432.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 20\right\}$};
  \node (node_37) at (578.5bp,432.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 15\right\}$};
  \node (node_35) at (221.5bp,485.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30\right\}$};
  \node (node_42) at (351.5bp,485.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 15, 20\right\}$};
  \node (node_43) at (495.5bp,485.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15\right\}$};
  \node (node_44) at (365.5bp,538.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 30\right\}$};
  \node (node_45) at (221.5bp,538.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 15, 20, 30\right\}$};
  \node (node_46) at (625.5bp,485.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 20\right\}$};
  \node (node_47) at (509.5bp,538.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20\right\}$};
  \node (node_48) at (365.5bp,591.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30\right\}$};
  \node (node_49) at (365.5bp,644.5bp) [draw,draw=none] {$\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 60, 30\right\}$};
  \draw [black,->] (node_0) ..controls (308.5bp,23.805bp) and (308.5bp,34.034bp)  .. (node_1);
  \draw [black,->] (node_1) ..controls (308.5bp,76.805bp) and (308.5bp,87.034bp)  .. (node_2);
  \draw [black,->] (node_1) ..controls (294.1bp,77.483bp) and (282.93bp,89.114bp)  .. (node_3);
  \draw [black,->] (node_1) ..controls (322.9bp,77.483bp) and (334.07bp,89.114bp)  .. (node_4);
  \draw [black,->] (node_2) ..controls (322.9bp,130.48bp) and (334.07bp,142.11bp)  .. (node_5);
  \draw [black,->] (node_2) ..controls (284.17bp,131.01bp) and (264.14bp,143.78bp)  .. (node_8);
  \draw [black,->] (node_3) ..controls (269.0bp,130.18bp) and (276.12bp,141.18bp)  .. (node_6);
  \draw [black,->] (node_3) ..controls (250.58bp,130.18bp) and (243.89bp,141.18bp)  .. (node_8);
  \draw [black,->] (node_4) ..controls (357.5bp,129.81bp) and (357.5bp,140.03bp)  .. (node_5);
  \draw [black,->] (node_4) ..controls (338.02bp,130.78bp) and (322.37bp,143.06bp)  .. (node_6);
  \draw [black,->] (node_4) ..controls (379.9bp,130.93bp) and (398.18bp,143.54bp)  .. (node_7);
  \draw [black,->] (node_5) ..controls (401.24bp,184.21bp) and (440.94bp,198.47bp)  .. (node_9);
  \draw [black,->] (node_5) ..controls (314.63bp,184.58bp) and (277.2bp,198.61bp)  .. (node_10);
  \draw [black,->] (node_5) ..controls (359.18bp,182.81bp) and (360.39bp,193.03bp)  .. (node_11);
  \draw [black,->] (node_6) ..controls (271.12bp,183.86bp) and (253.8bp,196.3bp)  .. (node_10);
  \draw [black,->] (node_6) ..controls (292.5bp,182.81bp) and (292.5bp,193.03bp)  .. (node_12);
  \draw [black,->] (node_6) ..controls (335.95bp,184.44bp) and (374.32bp,198.52bp)  .. (node_13);
  \draw [black,->] (node_7) ..controls (451.98bp,183.86bp) and (468.57bp,196.3bp)  .. (node_9);
  \draw [black,->] (node_7) ..controls (431.5bp,182.81bp) and (431.5bp,193.03bp)  .. (node_13);
  \draw [black,->] (node_8) ..controls (226.54bp,182.81bp) and (225.13bp,193.03bp)  .. (node_10);
  \draw [black,->] (node_8) ..controls (203.14bp,184.09bp) and (182.08bp,197.02bp)  .. (node_16);
  \draw [black,->] (node_9) ..controls (461.63bp,237.46bp) and (428.94bp,251.24bp)  .. (node_17);
  \draw [black,->] (node_9) ..controls (510.84bp,236.33bp) and (519.49bp,247.65bp)  .. (node_27);
  \draw [black,->] (node_10) ..controls (221.5bp,235.81bp) and (221.5bp,246.03bp)  .. (node_15);
  \draw [black,->] (node_10) ..controls (271.33bp,237.69bp) and (315.34bp,251.98bp)  .. (node_17);
  \draw [black,->] (node_10) ..controls (245.83bp,237.01bp) and (265.86bp,249.78bp)  .. (node_18);
  \draw [black,->] (node_10) ..controls (196.56bp,237.01bp) and (176.03bp,249.78bp)  .. (node_19);
  \draw [black,->] (node_11) ..controls (345.01bp,236.71bp) and (330.28bp,248.82bp)  .. (node_18);
  \draw [black,->] (node_11) ..controls (418.46bp,237.52bp) and (468.64bp,252.14bp)  .. (node_27);
  \draw [black,->] (node_12) ..controls (345.31bp,237.73bp) and (392.12bp,252.11bp)  .. (node_14);
  \draw [black,->] (node_12) ..controls (271.12bp,236.86bp) and (253.8bp,249.3bp)  .. (node_15);
  \draw [black,->] (node_13) ..controls (439.23bp,236.11bp) and (444.97bp,246.95bp)  .. (node_14);
  \draw [black,->] (node_13) ..controls (415.85bp,236.56bp) and (403.6bp,248.35bp)  .. (node_17);
  \draw [black,->] (node_14) ..controls (444.4bp,289.48bp) and (433.45bp,301.11bp)  .. (node_22);
  \draw [black,->] (node_14) ..controls (500.64bp,290.54bp) and (537.29bp,304.49bp)  .. (node_36);
  \draw [black,->] (node_15) ..controls (163.33bp,290.8bp) and (111.38bp,305.36bp)  .. (node_20);
  \draw [black,->] (node_15) ..controls (222.9bp,288.81bp) and (223.91bp,299.03bp)  .. (node_21);
  \draw [black,->] (node_15) ..controls (282.05bp,290.84bp) and (336.31bp,305.48bp)  .. (node_22);
  \draw [black,->] (node_16) ..controls (143.82bp,235.81bp) and (142.61bp,246.03bp)  .. (node_19);
  \draw [black,->] (node_17) ..controls (387.71bp,289.18bp) and (394.61bp,300.18bp)  .. (node_22);
  \draw [black,->] (node_17) ..controls (360.61bp,289.71bp) and (346.36bp,301.82bp)  .. (node_23);
  \draw [black,->] (node_17) ..controls (416.68bp,290.46bp) and (449.64bp,304.24bp)  .. (node_28);
  \draw [black,->] (node_18) ..controls (278.8bp,289.93bp) and (260.27bp,302.54bp)  .. (node_21);
  \draw [black,->] (node_18) ..controls (248.37bp,290.73bp) and (201.28bp,305.11bp)  .. (node_24);
  \draw [black,->] (node_18) ..controls (365.4bp,290.88bp) and (422.88bp,305.61bp)  .. (node_28);
  \draw [black,->] (node_19) ..controls (108.57bp,290.27bp) and (82.385bp,303.63bp)  .. (node_20);
  \draw [black,->] (node_19) ..controls (196.71bp,290.8bp) and (247.8bp,305.36bp)  .. (node_23);
  \draw [black,->] (node_19) ..controls (138.1bp,288.81bp) and (137.09bp,299.03bp)  .. (node_24);
  \draw [black,->] (node_20) ..controls (64.438bp,343.01bp) and (84.97bp,355.78bp)  .. (node_25);
  \draw [black,->] (node_20) ..controls (99.73bp,343.84bp) and (153.71bp,358.48bp)  .. (node_26);
  \draw [black,->] (node_21) ..controls (193.95bp,343.31bp) and (166.28bp,356.75bp)  .. (node_25);
  \draw [black,->] (node_21) ..controls (292.72bp,343.9bp) and (352.4bp,358.67bp)  .. (node_29);
  \draw [black,->] (node_22) ..controls (352.01bp,343.8bp) and (299.78bp,358.36bp)  .. (node_26);
  \draw [black,->] (node_22) ..controls (416.77bp,342.03bp) and (421.38bp,352.72bp)  .. (node_29);
  \draw [black,->] (node_22) ..controls (450.03bp,343.5bp) and (484.28bp,357.36bp)  .. (node_38);
  \draw [black,->] (node_23) ..controls (290.56bp,343.16bp) and (267.18bp,356.26bp)  .. (node_26);
  \draw [black,->] (node_23) ..controls (322.17bp,341.88bp) and (324.81bp,352.26bp)  .. (node_32);
  \draw [black,->] (node_24) ..controls (130.83bp,341.88bp) and (128.19bp,352.26bp)  .. (node_25);
  \draw [black,->] (node_24) ..controls (197.76bp,343.88bp) and (254.66bp,358.61bp)  .. (node_32);
  \draw [black,->] (node_25) ..controls (154.36bp,396.31bp) and (182.3bp,409.75bp)  .. (node_33);
  \draw [black,->] (node_25) ..controls (118.12bp,394.88bp) and (115.67bp,405.26bp)  .. (node_34);
  \draw [black,->] (node_26) ..controls (227.5bp,394.81bp) and (227.5bp,405.03bp)  .. (node_33);
  \draw [black,->] (node_26) ..controls (264.35bp,396.42bp) and (296.03bp,410.12bp)  .. (node_41);
  \draw [black,->] (node_27) ..controls (527.45bp,289.33bp) and (519.02bp,300.65bp)  .. (node_28);
  \draw [black,->] (node_27) ..controls (585.69bp,290.65bp) and (627.19bp,304.86bp)  .. (node_30);
  \draw [black,->] (node_28) ..controls (480.02bp,342.86bp) and (463.43bp,355.3bp)  .. (node_29);
  \draw [black,->] (node_28) ..controls (553.31bp,343.73bp) and (600.12bp,358.11bp)  .. (node_31);
  \draw [black,->] (node_28) ..controls (446.73bp,343.73bp) and (399.08bp,358.11bp)  .. (node_32);
  \draw [black,->] (node_29) ..controls (366.6bp,396.9bp) and (307.21bp,411.67bp)  .. (node_33);
  \draw [black,->] (node_29) ..controls (517.18bp,397.05bp) and (594.59bp,412.17bp)  .. (node_39);
  \draw [black,->] (node_29) ..controls (441.42bp,395.18bp) and (448.11bp,406.18bp)  .. (node_40);
  \draw [black,->] (node_30) ..controls (681.55bp,341.96bp) and (677.21bp,352.49bp)  .. (node_31);
  \draw [black,->] (node_31) ..controls (639.61bp,396.09bp) and (617.29bp,409.02bp)  .. (node_37);
  \draw [black,->] (node_31) ..controls (674.23bp,395.11bp) and (679.97bp,405.95bp)  .. (node_39);
  \draw [black,->] (node_32) ..controls (299.26bp,396.31bp) and (271.85bp,409.75bp)  .. (node_33);
  \draw [black,->] (node_32) ..controls (411.45bp,397.01bp) and (484.29bp,412.05bp)  .. (node_37);
  \draw [black,->] (node_33) ..controls (225.82bp,447.81bp) and (224.61bp,458.03bp)  .. (node_35);
  \draw [black,->] (node_33) ..controls (266.31bp,449.46bp) and (299.81bp,463.24bp)  .. (node_42);
  \draw [black,->] (node_33) ..controls (314.55bp,450.06bp) and (394.27bp,465.24bp)  .. (node_43);
  \draw [black,->] (node_34) ..controls (144.39bp,449.39bp) and (174.27bp,463.0bp)  .. (node_35);
  \draw [black,->] (node_35) ..controls (267.0bp,502.61bp) and (306.87bp,516.73bp)  .. (node_44);
  \draw [black,->] (node_35) ..controls (221.5bp,500.81bp) and (221.5bp,511.03bp)  .. (node_45);
  \draw [black,->] (node_36) ..controls (575.88bp,342.63bp) and (562.76bp,354.59bp)  .. (node_38);
  \draw [black,->] (node_37) ..controls (553.14bp,449.09bp) and (532.08bp,462.02bp)  .. (node_43);
  \draw [black,->] (node_38) ..controls (514.41bp,395.93bp) and (496.37bp,408.54bp)  .. (node_40);
  \draw [black,->] (node_38) ..controls (475.31bp,396.84bp) and (420.47bp,411.48bp)  .. (node_41);
  \draw [black,->] (node_39) ..controls (629.92bp,449.88bp) and (572.73bp,464.61bp)  .. (node_43);
  \draw [black,->] (node_39) ..controls (673.02bp,448.86bp) and (656.43bp,461.3bp)  .. (node_46);
  \draw [black,->] (node_40) ..controls (428.61bp,449.39bp) and (398.73bp,463.0bp)  .. (node_42);
  \draw [black,->] (node_40) ..controls (515.04bp,449.73bp) and (560.72bp,464.11bp)  .. (node_46);
  \draw [black,->] (node_41) ..controls (347.18bp,447.81bp) and (348.39bp,458.03bp)  .. (node_42);
  \draw [black,->] (node_42) ..controls (310.62bp,502.54bp) and (275.06bp,516.49bp)  .. (node_45);
  \draw [black,->] (node_42) ..controls (401.65bp,502.69bp) and (445.94bp,516.98bp)  .. (node_47);
  \draw [black,->] (node_43) ..controls (454.62bp,502.54bp) and (419.06bp,516.49bp)  .. (node_44);
  \draw [black,->] (node_43) ..controls (499.45bp,500.88bp) and (502.3bp,511.26bp)  .. (node_47);
  \draw [black,->] (node_44) ..controls (365.5bp,553.81bp) and (365.5bp,564.03bp)  .. (node_48);
  \draw [black,->] (node_45) ..controls (267.0bp,555.61bp) and (306.87bp,569.73bp)  .. (node_48);
  \draw [black,->] (node_46) ..controls (589.28bp,502.42bp) and (558.13bp,516.12bp)  .. (node_47);
  \draw [black,->] (node_47) ..controls (464.0bp,555.61bp) and (424.13bp,569.73bp)  .. (node_48);
  \draw [black,->] (node_48) ..controls (365.5bp,606.81bp) and (365.5bp,617.03bp)  .. (node_49);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `geometry` package to change to a different paper size: `\usepackage[a1paper]{geometry}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you very much. It works!

Comment: We don't need the actual image.  `example-image` (standard LaTeX) will do.  And yes it is possible, I would use a separate file and use pdfpages to copy it into your document.  So 4 wide and 2 high?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document

Answer (score 2):

First, create your image using standalone.  This will save you much time later.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c][594mm][c]{841mm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=800mm, height=550mm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Now break it into 8 pages using clip and trim.  In this case, `test5.pdf` is the standalone image.  Note that the first page cannot handle a full page image, so I use `\smash` to hide its size and `\vspace*{\fill}` to push it to the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\newcommand{\myfile}{test5.pdf}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}% first peage is tricky
\smash{\includegraphics*[trim=0mm {\paperheight} {3\paperwidth} 0mm]{\myfile}}% upper left
\newpage
\includegraphics*[trim={\paperwidth} {\paperheight} {2\paperwidth} 0mm]{\myfile}

\includegraphics*[trim={2\paperwidth} {\paperheight} {\paperwidth} 0mm]{\myfile}

\includegraphics*[trim={3\paperwidth} {\paperheight} 0mm 0mm]{\myfile}

\includegraphics*[trim=0mm 0mm {3\paperwidth} {\paperheight}]{\myfile}

\includegraphics*[trim={\paperwidth} 0mm {2\paperwidth} {\paperheight}]{\myfile}

\includegraphics*[trim={2\paperwidth} 0mm {\paperwidth} {\paperheight}]{\myfile}

\includegraphics*[trim={3\paperwidth}  0mm 0mm {\paperheight}]{\myfile}% lower right
\end{document}
```