Create One Legal Page Still A Challenge
apologies for reiterating this question. However this issue is still not solved.I figure the best way to learn was to do hands on and get it going for myself, but after a few days, I am still finding this challenging.
The issue is I have several tables that are not sitting within the parameters of the page margins. These tables are within different sections of the document.

What I am trying to do?: gather the knowledge of how to create one legal page that would be able to hold the data comfortably with out these issues in that specific location. please see image.

What I tried?
I search google and I think google is fed up of me by now. So I tried reviewing the documentation here https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins#Paper_size,_orientation_and_margins


however, I am still not getting it due to the lack of my understand and being new to latex, I've never used this tool.
it is really Kool but the lack of underwing it really frustrating
The rotation of the page would be nice to view the document at the 90 degrees angle. I tried this as well but the entire document shifted 90 degrees.
I did copy my document into another session just so that I can revert to the original scenario incase it gets messed up.

** This MY CODE Sample of the table I am trying to create**
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% Beamer presentation requires \usepackage{colortbl} instead of \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|cccccc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Transfer Learning On YOLOv5m Trained FROM SCRATCH Operations (random weights)}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{\#}}}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Experiment}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Model}}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Precision}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Recall}}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{mAP\_0.5}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} }}                             & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Exp18 No Pre-processing/ With Background Dataset Size 5944 images}}}                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{1}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Exp-18}}              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Medium-FS}}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.66}}               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.51}}            & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0.53}              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} }}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} }}                             & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Exp15 Pre-processing/ With Background Dataset Size 6204 images}}}                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{2}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Exp-15}}              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Medium-FS}}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.61}}               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.59}}            & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0.63}              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{}}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} }}                             & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Exp6 No Pre-processing/ No Background Dataset Size 2284 Images}}}                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{3}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Exp-6}}               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Medium-FS}}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.64}}               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.68}}            & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0.67}              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} }}                             & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Exp3 Pre-processing/ No Background Dataset Size 5944 Images}}}                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{4}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Exp-3}}               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Medium-FS}}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.67}}               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.70}}            & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0.72}              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Transfer Learning On YOLOv5m Finetuned by COCO Dataset Pre-Trained Operations}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} }}                             & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Exp12 No Pre-processing/ No Background Dataset Size 5944 images}}}                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{5}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Exp-12}}              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Medium-PT}}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.77}}               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.72}}            & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0.75}              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{}}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} }}                             & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Exp24 No Pre-processing/ With Background Images Dataset Size 5944 images}}}                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{6}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Exp-24}}              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} Medium-PT}}          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.84}}               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} 0.74}}            & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0.79}              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} }}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} }}                             & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Exp9 Pre-processing/ No Background Dataset Size 5944 images}}}                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{7}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Exp-9}}}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Medium-PT}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{0.83}}}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{0.81}}}   & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{0.83}}     \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{}}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} }}                             & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Exp21 Pre-processing/ With Background Dataset Size 6204 images}}}                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{8}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Exp-21}}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Medium-PT}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{0.85}}}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{0.82}}}   & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{0.85}}     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

I am using this table generation tool to create the table
https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables

New Image On New ERROR For this code:

This is what I am working with I manually removed the ** {\color[HTML]{000000} and the table settled down with some issues I am not sure how to explain not do I know the terminology for what the issue is I am at the baby level But I am figuring out things from a hands on perspective.
My Example
  % Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% Beamer presentation requires \usepackage{colortbl} instead of \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% \usepackage{lscape}
\begin{landscape}
\pagebreak
\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|cccccc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Transfer Trained Operations (random weights)} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\#} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Exp} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Mod} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Prec} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Rec} &
  {mAP\_0.5} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Exp186 processing/  Background images} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{1}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Exp-180} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Med-FR} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.66} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.51} &
  {0.53} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Exp153 processing Background images} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Exp-159} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Med-FG} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.61} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.59} &
  {0.63} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Exp608 processing/ No Background  Images} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Exp-609} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Med-FG} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.64} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.68} &
  {0.67} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Exp334 processing/ No Background Images} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Exp-300} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Med-FS} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.67} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.70} &
  {0.72} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Working With Binary Images with and without colours} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Exp98 processing/ No images} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{5}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Exp-96} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Med-PT} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.77} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.72} &
  {0.75} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{processing/Images images} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{6}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Exp-78} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Med-PT} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.84} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.74} &
  {0.79} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{processing/ No Background Dataset images} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{7}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Exp-9} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Med-PT} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.83} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.81} &
  {0.83} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Exp21 processing/ With Background Dataset images} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{8}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Exp-21} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Med-PT} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.85} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.82} &
  {0.85} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Appendix: Activity Impact Results}\label{tab:appendixchp4_Table_4}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
% End the rotation
\pagebreak[75]
\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}

In removing the \color[HTML]{000000} 
the table was finally created but the parameters are different than the usual table. I realised that I didn't need the legal page script after all as this instance with outage color tags created the table BUT the text is larger than the rest of tables and the text within the document.
With my limited knowledge of Latex
I tried the text reduce command like \smallbut that is not reducing the text size to its original state.
this is my example below and THANX in advance for assisting me everyone and forgive the lack of understanding with Latex, I'd get there slowly but hopefully surely.
Example of: My pages on the left being called via the main.tex file scripts and the Text Size ISSUE


The terrible code from these online table generators is very hard to adjust to fit a page.  All these \multicolumn{1}{...}{...} will make it nearly impossible to get a good looking result. Better create the table yourself.

that's the thing, I am trying the best way I Know how to in the easiest way possible to understand what I am doing. I will look into creating the table, however after googling, I am thinking that it's a package or something?!??!! I am not certain I am speculating here! or simple script that I have no knowledge of

You can learn how to create a table at https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08 (also available in other languages)

Please do not ask a question that has been closed again. Instead, edit the existing question, improve it and ask for it to be reopened. Unfortunately, the new question also has some flaws. For example, there is no link to the original question and the problem is only partially comprehensible. Although code was shown, it was not (originally) marked as such and it cannot be executed directly. Therefore, we do not know the page dimensions. For this reason, an minimal working example would be preferable.

BTW: You also have not shown how you've tried to rotate the page. So we cannot tell you, what is wrong and causes the rotation of all pages instead. Additionally this seems to be a mixture of several questions: e.g. How to learn how to create tables? How to rotate singe pages? How to use color rows, colums or cells in tables? … Please always focus on one question per question.

Does this answer your question? Is it possible to create one page as legal size landscape in latex

Hi all and thank you for responding, I am utterly grateful for your comments and trying assiduously to assist me. @cabohah, this is what I used to try creating the rotation of the page. %rotate the page
\pagebreak[75]
\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz someone cleaned up the code as I was not sure where to start. If this was you pal, thanx loads for assisting appreciate this loads!! However I tried rendering that clean code but to no avail it didn't work. the issue persists

@Simbadian You have to thank @ cabohah :)

Ohhh mmmyy, apologies!! I am getting everything wrong since this error!! My heartfelt thank yooouuu's @cabohah really appreciate this!!

@Simbadian Please don't hide question relevant information in a comment. Add it to the question. For code it is always the best to show it in a minimal working example, as already explained. Please have a look at the link in the comment above. BTW: I've just added markdown for the code. I've not changed anything inside the code.

And instead of just asking google, I would recommend to read also questions and answers linked as duplicate or linked in the duplicate also as duplicate … and ideally also to read questions and answers listed as potentially relevant. You should never delete a question to ask it again. If you do this often, you risk to be blocked. Instead: Edit your question and try to improve it. And please also clean up this question to ask only one clear question. This would also help to avoid lengthy discussions like in the comments here.

always make your examples complete so they show the problem. Do you really mean legal here?? that is, do you want a different physical size paper, or do you mean landscape ,that is :the same size paper, just rotated?  Also avoid that table generator, it does not make usable latex code.

Maybe a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

@cabohah thank you for the suggestions, however this is how I managed on my own to get the understanding thus far. that is, by reading others who made similar errors aligned with what I am trying to achieve. Forgive me for the newbie way of doing things but this me trying to get my knowledge to standard. I am not sure if there's another way to ask a question that I need assistance with. if there is please let me know and thanx in advance

@DavidCarlisle, thank you for clarifying this issue. What I am trying to do is get a legal page first. this is most important. the rotation is just nice to have, which I can figure out later. I think I have an idea how to create it.

Please understand, that is is hard to help you, if you (1) do not show a minimal working example, (2) mix several questions into one, (3) do not ask clear questions. Already as your first question, we have asked, whether you really want to add another page format into your document or just want to add have one page landscape instead of portrait.

For changing the page size of the whole document see the manual of the used class. For example, the standard classes, have option legalpaper to make the whole document use legal. You can also use package typearea or geometry to setup the legal paper size. But, for a single page in legal inside a document with another default page size, use the second link in my comment above or the second duplicate link to the question you've unfortunately deleted.

you have not for example said what page size you are starting with,  you can rotate a page just using \begin{landscape}  but if you want help you need to state more clearly what your problem is.  Why do you want to change page size for one page? It's possible of course but very unusual as it makes the document basically unprinatable (I have never seen a printer that would take legal size paper for example)

apologies @cabohah, I will try better next time. however might I add that some of the terms I am not sure what it is called and I am trying my very best to ask the question that would convey what I mean. I agree it may be challenging to assist me and decipher what I am trying to achieve, but trying seeing it from my perspective please. Someone who has always used word and make things happen in second Versus Latex which I have never used. Forgive me for causing an irritation this is painful for me as well. thanx for assisting regardless of the lack of standards using latex forums.

@DavidCarlisle, thank you for responding. I am familiar with the \begin{landscape} I have been creating smaller tables before. But I knew that this table required a legal page as per working with it in MS word. My challenge is setting the legal page feature for one Single page rather than the entire document

We already linked a question with answers, that shows how to add another paper format for some pages. We've done so already for your first question, you've unfortunately deleted. Unfortunately you've also not shown, how you've tried to use the information of these answers. Unfortunately, you ignore all requests for a complete example with which we can immediately understand the problem. So, sorry, I give up here.

@DavidCarlisle \newgeometry cannot be used to change the page size.

Ahh thank you @DavidCarlisle for highlighting this. I wouldn't have had the slightest clue if it can or cannot work. I am at the baby stages with Latex. Even though I read and YouTube most of the way the issues seems to be distinct to what I am trying to achieve Hence I came here for assistance as directed by the Latex Admin via email. Any Idea on better table generation tool online? I am unable to recreate the table cabohah did. I just don't have that skill just yet.

@Simbadian why do you want an online generator, the latex syntax is just aaa & bbb & ccc\\  for each row which is probably simpler than whatever input you used to generate the mass of pointless \multicolumn statements that the generator  output.

Please delete my answer code from your question and provide an example that produces an error that you want to ask about

You have again added an unusable fragment and an image from an unrelated document. Delete all examples that do not start \documentclass and end \end{document} and only post images posted by code you have posted here. The answer posted answers the question in the title on how to change the page size, Any other errors you may or may not get are unrelated to that and should be asked in a new question with an example that shows the problem.

I'll chime in and second the suggestion to drop the table generator and learn how to create a table on your own.  \color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{} is meaningless: the \color command says that you want black, and the textbf command makes its argument bold.  But with an empty argument it's doing nothing.

Hi @DavidCarlisle and thanx you loads for responding to my insane methods to get this going. The reason why the examples are not starting with the <\documentclass and end \end{document}>  tags is because most of the pages are being called to the main.tex file and that is where all over the packages are and major commands are implemented. what you are seeing is multiple sections within the document that are being called to compile the final draft. As such, I provided the examples based on the issue. Ho pe this makes some sense for you.

No.  your original document may have 1000 pages but is not relevant. Here you should always make a small complete example that shows the issue.  You never provided any example at all. Posting dozens of lines of machine generated nonsense table code that can not be checked by eye and can not  be run to see the issue does not help anyone answer.

If removing the \color macro helped, than you are probably missing the necessary packages in the preamble. But that's just a guess as you never showed us a MWE.

There is nothing in your question that suggests that changing page size mid-document is required, and it is such an unusual thing to do there is no real latex interface to doing it however it is not that hard if it is really needed.
This is a three page document with pages 1 and 3 letter size and page 2 being 1in taller.

\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

aaa

\clearpage
\addtolength\paperheight{1in}
\addtolength\pdfpageheight{1in}
\addtolength\textheight{1in}
\twocolumn\onecolumn

bbb 


\clearpage
\addtolength\paperheight{-1in}
\addtolength\pdfpageheight{-1in}
\addtolength\textheight{-1in}
\twocolumn\onecolumn

ccc

\end{document}



Hi @DavidCarlisle that did something But I have a new issue I am not sure what the term of this issue is or what to call it. So, I'm attaching this image in the above question so that you can see what's happening. Thanx for trying by the way.

The only part of that output is the top line that says that you have 156!!! errors. If you have any error tex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, you should ignore any pdf output that may be produced if you scroll past the error. If you want help with an error we ask again provide a complete document like the document in this answer that people can use to reproduce the error and test answers. After multiple requests you have still not provided any example. You have added my answer to your question which helps nobody and is unrelated to the shown output.

How do I get the code to sit nicely like in the question? I tried the code brackets feature available but the code still turns out like rubbish.. please help here as well. thanx in advance

you can use three backticks before and after, or highlight the code and hit the code </> button in the editor

will keep that in mind hats off.

@Simbadian Please follow links in the comments. I've already posted a link to the markdown help page, that also contains "Code and Preformatted Text" and "Syntax highlighting for code".

Ok @cabohah I am on it thanx loads

hi @DavidCarlisle and cabohah, I solved it!! the issue of the legal page was not needed. The issue of the oversized text size was caused by this \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!} and the SOLUTION  I used to handle the text was ** \small % Reduce font size to 12 points \resizebox{\textwidth}**.  THANX loads all for responding to my issue. Solved it with a fresh mind this morning!! HATs off..

@Simbadian not changing the page size, choosing a suitable font and not using \resizebox was the expected answer, and would have been given ages ago if you had ever provided any usable example.

Apologies I'd get there in terms of how things work, but I did provided the code that cabohah cleaned up!!?? Wasn't that an example of the issue and if no? then guide me in terms of presenting an example, please. As to my limited knowledge, I assumed that I presented an example that was suitable. The pages are being called by the main.tex page. The amount of code would not be a suitable approach, maybe that's where I went wrong. Nevertheless!!  Thannx loads once more

@Simbadian you are asking us to debug your code so you should provide code in a form that is possible to debug. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Apologies once more @DavidCarlisle, will have a review of the link to get up to speed on the standards and thanx loads once more for your patience. Have a great day, cheers!!
