# How to translate and rotate the heading of landscaped pages?

Tags: header-footer, rotating, landscape

## Objective

***How to change the heading of landscaped pages from***

[image]

***to***

[image]

***?***

## Minimal Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]

\section{One One}
\lipsum[2]

\newgeometry{hmargin=5cm,vmargin=3cm}

\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

## Edit 1 (my real scenario layout)

In my real scenario, the left-right margins should not be occupied by headings.

[image]

Comment: Page headings and numbers support browsing and look-up in a book, that's why I think they should remain like on portrait pages resp. the standard layout. They are not page-specific decoration. I don't like to turn a book to landscape and back while looking for a section or a page number.

Comment: @Stefan: But this heading will disturb my landscaped pages. On the landscaped pages I have a long table. The left-right margin should not be consumed by heading.

Comment: In that case I suggest to use an empty page style.

Comment: @Stefan: I already tried it. But I need page numbers. :-)

Comment: @xport: Then try `\thispagestyle{plain}` or something similar.

Comment: @Leo: I need page numbers on the landscaped pages. And the page numbers should be at the bottom as shown in the second figure above.

Comment: @xport: Do you aim at screen reading or at printing?

Comment: @Hendrik: Both.

Comment: @xport: In printing you should definitely follow Stefan's advice and leave the page numbers in their usual places. Really!! Your screenshot shows that for screen reading it would indeed be good to move (and rotate) the page numbers.

Comment: @Hendrik: OK. Will do!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `lscape` package is not designed for this. It's designed for rotating wide figures or tables, for example.  And the `geometry` package explicitly says that `\newgeometry` can't change the paper size or orientation.  So I don't think there's a way to do this automatically.

You can include landscape oriented pdf pages using the `pdfpages` package. (Include them with the `[landscape]` option.)

### A new solution

You could also use the `textpos` package to place the headers.  By combining this with the `fancyhdr` package, you can pretty much automate it.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape,lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{lscape}{% 
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields 
\fancyfoot[LE]{%
\begin{textblock}{20}(1,5){\rotatebox{90}{\leftmark}}\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{1}(13,10.5){\rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}\end{textblock}}
\fancyfoot[LO] {%
\begin{textblock}{1}(13,10.5){\rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{20}(1,13.25){\rotatebox{90}{\rightmark}}\end{textblock}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\lipsum
\section{A section}
\lipsum

\newgeometry{hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm}
\thispagestyle{lscape}
\pagestyle{lscape}
\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry
\pagestyle{headings}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Alan: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, my scenario does not match your suggestion. There is no pdf page to be imported. And I don't want to create such pdf because it is tedious job.

Comment: @xport I added a different solution.  Maybe that will work for you.

Comment: @Alan: This should work. The code seems to be pasted twice. Furthermore, `\thispagestyle{lscape}` is enough, `\pagestyle{lscape}` may be deleted. (and `\newgeometry` may be deleted?)

Comment: @Leo Thanks for catching the duplicate code.  No, I don't think the `\pagestyle` command can be removed, since we need any subsequent landscape pages to be that pagestyle too.  The `\newgeometry` command was in xport's original example; it's needed so that the landscape pages have the right size.

Comment: @Alan: heading and page number should be at top right and bottom center, respectively. Your settings does not match a bit.

Comment: @xport Examples are just that.  Proof of solution.  I'm sure you can figure out how to get the pieces in the right place.

Comment: @xport But since you asked, I've updated the code to your specs.  Since you don't say whether your document is one or two sided, I've left in the two sided version, which may be helpful to others.

Comment: @Alan: thanks for the solution. However, how do you get the values of `13`, `10.5`, `13.25`? They make exact positions or approximation you got by trial and errors?

Comment: @xport I did them by trial and error, but you could calculate them based on the various pagesize lengths.

Answer (score 16):

> I need page numbers on the landscaped
>   pages. And the page numbers should be
>   at the bottom as shown in the second
>   figure above.

I have an idea. We can use `\fancypagestyle` to define a new pagestyle with landscaped page numbers. I use `tikz` to put the page number.

```
\fancypagestyle{lscapedplain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[outer sep=1cm,above,rotate=90] at (current page.east) {\thepage};}
}
```

This would also be done by `\newpagestyle` from `titlesec`.

Comment: I accidentally undid my vote on your answer.  If you edit your answer, I can upvote it again. :-)

Comment: @Alan: I think the code here shows the key to the question. (So does yours.) @xport can do the rest herself. Never mind about voting.

Comment: Leo: I came back to this question to solve a problem that a student discovered with my thesis class, so now I've finally got around to voting for this question again. I'm actually going to include it into my thesis class; it's a very nice solution.  Thanks.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I had to add the `\usepackage{tikz}` to my document preamble. It also added a vertical line on the right side of my landscape-d page, which I had to get rid of using: `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`

Comment: Nice lightweight solution! Can the size of the number be changed somehow?

Answer (score 8):

Analternative approach using package `typearea` to switch to landscape-mode mid-document. Though it is really strange to do that.

[image: exportNewGeometry]

```
\documentclass[usegeometry,paper=a5,pagesize,headinclude]{book}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]

\section{One One}
\lipsum[2]

\storeareas\normalsetting
\KOMAoption{paper}{landscape}
\areaset{2\textwidth}{.9\textheight}
\recalctypearea
    \lipsum[3-5]
\clearpage
\normalsetting
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

This method is answered by @Leo Liu, from http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=78285.

Limited by the geometry package itself:

> Unlike \geometry in the preamble,\newgeometry is available only after \begin{document}, resets all the options ever speciﬁed except for the papersize-related options: landscape, portrait, and paper size options (such as papersize, paper=a4paper and so forth), which can’t be changed with \newgeometry.
>
> -- Geometry package manual

Make a patch so that the `\newgeometry` command uses the landscape and portrait options.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\ifGm@preamble#1{\@firstofone}
\appto\restoregeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}
\apptocmd\newgeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape,lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\ifGm@preamble#1{\@firstofone}
\appto\restoregeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}
\apptocmd\newgeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]

\section{One One}
\lipsum[2]

\newgeometry{,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm,landscape}

\lipsum[3-5]

\restoregeometry
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a suggestion using `scrlayer` to define a new pagestyle for these rotated pages.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape,lipsum}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  rightmargin,
  contents={%
    \parbox[b][\layerheight][c]{\dimexpr\footskip+\footheight\relax}{%
      \hfill\rotatebox{90}{\pagemark}}}
]{lscape.foot}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  textarea,
  addhoffset=\dimexpr-\headsep-\headheight\relax,
  width=\dimexpr\headsep+\headheight\relax,
  contents={\hfill\rotatebox{90}{\headmark}\hspace*{\headsep}}
]{lscape.head}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{lscape}{lscape.foot,lscape.head}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{One One}
\lipsum[2]

\newgeometry{hmargin=5cm,vmargin=3cm}
\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{lscape}
\lipsum[3-10]
\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]