# Rotate one whole page 90degrees in a document including header and footer created with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rotating, landscape

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to translate and rotate the heading of landscaped pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/how-to-translate-and-rotate-the-heading-of-landscaped-pages)

I have a thesis with header+footer on each page created using the `fancyhdr`    package.
On one page I have an oversized table which is rotated using the `lscape` package.

How can the header and footer for this page only also be rotated such that they are the same direction as the table? MWE below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is my heading}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{This if my footer: \thepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \centering
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
                1 & 2 \\
                3 & 4 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do the answers to the following question help you: [How to translate and rotate the heading of landscaped pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9071/1235) (possible duplicate)

Comment: Please help us helping you: Does the above link help you?

Comment: Yes, its a little complicated but does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for telling. So we might close this as a duplicate, right?