# How to adjust or remove page numbers on a landscape page within a portrait document?

Tags: header-footer, landscape

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to translate and rotate the heading of landscaped pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/how-to-translate-and-rotate-the-heading-of-landscaped-pages)

I have a document that is typset in portrait, using the article class, that contains a single landscape page (to accommodate a large table). I want to have the page numbers in the center of the footer for every page, so I'm using `\pagestyle{plain}`. However, when I use the `\usepackage{pdflscape}` package and `\begin{landscape}`, the page number is on the left side, in the center, which is directly overlapping my table. I guess `pdflscape` only rotates the contents, not the page numbers. I need this page number in the same place as the others: at the bottom of the page in the center. Using `\thispagestyle{plain}` or `\thispagestyle{headings}` doesn't change it all either.

Comment: You could just use the `sidewaystable` environment from the [`rotating` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating). It provides a portrait-style page for landscape-style tables.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example, as an alternative, that uses the [`rotating` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating) to rotate the landscape-style table on a portrait-style page, which doesn't affect the page style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}% http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  This is a sideways table.
  \caption{This is a sideways table}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}​
```