# While running this table i got errors

Tags: tables

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.3in}|p{0.9in}|p{0.2in}|p{0.3in}|p{0.2in}|p{0.2in}|p{0.2in}|p{0.2in}|p{0.2in}|p{0.3in}|p{0.3in}|p{0.2in}|p{0.3in}|p{0.2in}|p{0.3in}|} \hline 
Sl.No. &  Author \& year   & \multicolumn{7}{|p{1.5in}|}{Level-1 (Ridge)} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{0.6in}|}{Level-2 (Minutiae)} & \multicolumn{4}{|p{0.9in}|}{Methodology}  \hline 
 &  & Ridge Density & Ridge Orientation & Ridge Count  & Ridge Length  & Ridge Type & Ridge Curve Direction  & Ridge Frequency & Minutiae Points  (x, y, O)  & Minutiae  Type & Code based  & Indexing technique & Clustering  & Similarity score  \hline 
1 & J. Boer et al.\newline 2001 & Y &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  & F &  &   \hline 
2 & B. Bhanu  et al.\newline 2003 &  & Y &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y  \hline 
3 & T. Liu et al.\newline 2005 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y  \hline 
4 & J. Li et al.\newline 2006 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y  \hline 
5 & J.Feng  et al.\newline 2006 & Y &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  & H &  &   \hline 
6 & A.Ross  et al.\newline 2007 &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y  \hline 
7 & X. Liang et al.\newline 2007 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y  \hline 
8 & Gyaourova et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  & Y  \hline 
9 & M. Vatsa et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  &  & M &   \hline 
10 & S. Biswas  et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  &  &  &  & K &   \hline 
11 & Xin Shuai et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & H &  &   \hline 
12 & P Mansukhani\newline 2010 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  & T &  &   \hline 
13 & R. Cappelli\newline Dec 2011 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  & H &  &   \hline 
14 & R. Cappelli\newline May 2011 &  & Y &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  &  &  &  & Y  \hline 
15 & R.Cappelli et al.\newline 2012 &  & Y &  &  &  &  & Y & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y  \hline 
16 & M. Liu et al.\newline 2012 &  &  & Y & Y & Y & Y &  &  &  &  &  & K &  \hline 
17 & Iloanusi et al.\newline 2013 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y  & Y  &  & IS &  &   \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (S): `c' used. S

Comment: What if you replace `\hline` with \\

Comment: or \\\hline if you want the line

Comment: Yes, both suggestions work fine ... the problem is that you do not 'end' your rows with a \\.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a table row is ended, there must be a `\\`, so consider adding `\\ hline` at the very end of each row. The table is horrible anyway and needs too many modifications (here in this site, you will find more suggestions), so, consider also using a `sidewaystable` (See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37248/sidewaystable-from-rotating-package-cuts-off-table-even-after-changing-margins), e.g.).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{|p{.2in}|p{.7in}|p{.2in}|p{.3in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.3in}|p{.3in}|p{.2in}|p{.3in}|p{.2in}|p{.3in}|} 
\hline 
Sl.No. &  Author \& year   & \multicolumn{7}{|p{1.5in}|}{Level-1 (Ridge)} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{0.6in}|}{Level-2 (Minutiae)} & \multicolumn{4}{|p{0.9in}|}{Methodology}\\  \hline 
 &  & Ridge Density & Ridge Orientation & Ridge Count  & Ridge Length  & Ridge Type & Ridge Curve Direction  & Ridge Frequency & Minutiae Points  (x, y, O)  & Minutiae  Type & Code based  & Indexing technique & Clustering  & Similarity score\\  \hline 
1 & J. Boer et al.\newline 2001 & Y &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  & F &  &\\   \hline 
2 & B. Bhanu  et al.\newline 2003 &  & Y &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y\\  \hline 
3 & T. Liu et al.\newline 2005 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y \\ \hline 
4 & J. Li et al.\newline 2006 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y \\ \hline 
5 & J.Feng  et al.\newline 2006 & Y &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  & H &  & \\  \hline 
6 & A.Ross  et al.\newline 2007 &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y \\ \hline 
7 & X. Liang et al.\newline 2007 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y \\ \hline 
8 & Gyaourova et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  & Y \\ \hline 
9 & M. Vatsa et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  &  & M &  \\ \hline 
10 & S. Biswas  et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  &  &  &  & K & \\  \hline 
11 & Xin Shuai et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & H &  & \\  \hline 
12 & P Mansukhani\newline 2010 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  & T &  &  \\ \hline 
13 & R. Cappelli\newline Dec 2011 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  & H &  & \\  \hline 
14 & R. Cappelli\newline May 2011 &  & Y &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  &  &  &  & Y\\  \hline 
15 & R.Cappelli et al.\newline 2012 &  & Y &  &  &  &  & Y & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y \\ \hline 
16 & M. Liu et al.\newline 2012 &  &  & Y & Y & Y & Y &  &  &  &  &  & K & \\ \hline 
17 & Iloanusi et al.\newline 2013 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y  & Y  &  & IS &  & \\  \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here is a picture of that giant table:

[image]

Here is a relatively improved version using `booktabs` and `xcolor` package for alternating coloring:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,tabulary}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\tiny
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\rowcolors{3}{}{gray!10}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{*{15}{L}} 
\toprule 
 &     & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Level-1 (Ridge)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Level-2 (Minutiae)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Methodology}\\ \cmidrule(r-r){3-9} \cmidrule(r-r){10-11} \cmidrule(r-r){12-15}
Sl.No. &  Author \& year & Ridge Density & Ridge Orientation & Ridge Count  & Ridge Length  & Ridge Type & Ridge Curve Direction  & Ridge Frequency & Minutiae Points  (x, y, O)  & Minutiae  Type & Code based  & Indexing technique & Clustering  & Similarity score\\   
1 & J. Boer et al.\newline 2001 & Y &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  & F &  &\\    
2 & B. Bhanu  et al.\newline 2003 &  & Y &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y\\   
3 & T. Liu et al.\newline 2005 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y \\  
4 & J. Li et al.\newline 2006 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y \\  
5 & J.Feng  et al.\newline 2006 & Y &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  & H &  & \\   
6 & A.Ross  et al.\newline 2007 &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y \\  
7 & X. Liang et al.\newline 2007 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y \\  
8 & Gyaourova et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  & Y \\  
9 & M. Vatsa et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  &  & M &  \\  
10 & S. Biswas  et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  &  &  &  & K & \\   
11 & Xin Shuai et al.\newline 2008 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & H &  & \\   
12 & P Mansukhani\newline 2010 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  & T &  &  \\  
13 & R. Cappelli\newline Dec 2011 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y & Y &  & H &  & \\   
14 & R. Cappelli\newline May 2011 &  & Y &  &  &  &  & Y &  &  &  &  &  & Y\\   
15 & R.Cappelli et al.\newline 2012 &  & Y &  &  &  &  & Y & Y & Y &  &  &  & Y \\  
16 & M. Liu et al.\newline 2012 &  &  & Y & Y & Y & Y &  &  &  &  &  & K & \\  
17 & Iloanusi et al.\newline 2013 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & Y  & Y  &  & IS &  & \\ \bottomrule  
\end{tabulary}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]