# Publishing standard for landscape page number position?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, landscape

I realize there are a couple of threads on this matter, but my question is a little different.  My university thesis office returned my dissertation with formatting corrections today.  One of the things they want me to do is change the orientation of page number on landscape pages.  For now, my page numbers are all in portrait mode, even on landscape pages.

So what is the publishing standard for this?  I ask this because I am not seeing any elegant solutions to this problem.  One hack that has worked for me is first setting the pagestyle on a landscape page to `empty` and then using `\thepage` command after the table, figure or text on this page.  This also requires doing a `\centering{\thepage}`.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: I am still interested in finding an elegant solution to placing the page number in landscape mode.  However, just wanted to point out that our thesis office scrapped this requirement.  Apparently, the person who suggested this change wasn't aware of all formatting regulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a publisher, but i took a look through a series of scientific publications in my private library. Til yet i have not found an example where the orientation of headers and footers (hence especially page numbering) changed on landscape pages. I think there is a simple reason: consistency; meaning that you want to find certain information, which is transfered to headers and footers like chapter, section or page numbers, in the same spot on every page.

Regarding your hack: The `\centering` belongs into the group: `{\centering\thepage}`. And Putting `\hfill` before of the pagenumber ensures that you have a uniform style whenever you apply your hack.

You may also try out a systematic (non-hack) solution presented in this post: [How to translate and rotate the heading of landscaped pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/how-to-translate-and-rotate-the-heading-of-landscaped-pages)

Comment: Indeed.  The thesis office retracted that correction after I pointed out essentially what both the answers above say.  Thank you for your input.