# put one page completely landscape

Tags: tables, sectioning, header-footer, landscape

I have a document that is mostly in normal layout, but two sections need to be in landscape. The contents of the page turn without problem, including table and section. What doesn't turn on those pages are the header and the footer, and I'd like those to turn as well. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{newstyle}{
 \setheadrule{0pt}

  \sethead[\small{Report - \sectiontitle}]
    []
    []
    {\small{Report - \sectiontitle}}
    {}
    {}
\setfoot[\small{\copyright~{} \year myself}][][\small{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}]{\small{\copyright~{} \year myself}}{}{\small{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}
}
\titleformat{\section}
{\color{blue}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{blue}\thesection}{1em}{}[\vspace{2pt}\titlerule]
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\color{blue}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{blue}\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\color{blue}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{blue}\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}


\pagestyle{newstyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\section{A section}
Some Text

\begin{table}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
foo & bar & bar & baz & foo & bar \\
\hline
a & a & a & a & a & a\\
\hline   
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I advice you not to do that. The reader *will* get distracted by that. For example, page numbers will not be, where they just were. Confusing.

Comment: @Johannes_B, not my choice - I was asked to do this.

Comment: Is this just a one off requirement?  If so, consider moving your landscape material to a separate document, and putting two dummy blank pages in the main document.  Then you can either combine the printed pages by hand or use a PDF-stitching tool (like Preview on Mac) to assemble the pages as you need them.  Of course if you have anything in the way of cross referencing etc this becomes painful, but for simple independent tables or graphics it works well.

Comment: There must be a solution in TeX to it, that's what I'm looking for. Someone has an idea? I'm glad that at least it seems to be uncommon and it was not due to a lack of search skills that I didn't find the solution. :)

Comment: Alan Munn has answered a similar question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9072/15874).

Comment: I just provided an alternative solution, i vote to close this one as a supe of the other.

Comment: @Johannes_B where did you provide the alternate solution?

Comment: Right below the question title is a link, find my alternative solution there.