# Rotating page incl. footers

Tags: header-footer, rotating, double-sided, report, pdflscape

I am trying to rotate a page in my thesis. I have now spend time by reading other questions about the same answer. I found this in preamble:

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
```

And this in the thesis, where I want to rotate my page useful:

```
\begin{landscape}
… hello
\end{landscape}
```

The only problem, that I have is, that my footers still be at the same place. Is it possible to move the footer as well?

[image]

I am using report, two-sided.

Hope anyone can help me!

Comment: ,@A.F. Does [How to translate and rotate the heading of landscaped pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/how-to-translate-and-rotate-the-heading-of-landscaped-pages) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using package `scrlayer` to define a new layer pagestyle for the landscape pages. Note that you can still use `fancyhdr` or `scrlayer-scrpage` for the header and footer on the other pages.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,
  textarea,
  addwidth=\footskip,
  addwidth=\footheight,
  contents=\hfill%
    \rotatebox{90}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{1.25em}\quad\pagemark}
]{lscape.odd.foot}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=lscape.odd.foot,
  foreground,
  evenpage,
  contents=\vfill\hfill%
    \rotatebox{90}{\pagemark\quad\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{1.25em}}
]{lscape.even.foot}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{lscape}{lscape.odd.foot,lscape.even.foot}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{One One}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{lscape}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{landscape}

\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]