# Change page number style and position in landscape mode

Tags: page-numbering, landscape

I have a document in which I use `landscape` environment but I also have many pages in vertical orientation. I want to do two things:

-change numbering style from `1 2 3` to `S1 S2 S3` for all pages

-for pages in `landscape` mode, change the position of page number so that it is not perpendicular to the text but parallel as on a regular page

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thepage}{S\arabic{page}}` should do for the numbering scheme. The other stuff depends on the documentclass and certain packages

Comment: So I use ``article`` and I do not know what other packages may be relevant but I use a lot of them.

Comment: How about a working document?

Comment: Well, these are some data I do not want to upload here. And if I get rid of many packages for MWE then perhaps I throw out something important?

Comment: Personally, I use `fancyhdr` package, with `\pagestyle{fancy}`,  `\fancyhead{foo}` and `\fancyfoot{bar}` commands.
But there might be other solutions for your problem.

Comment: May be related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9071/43317

Comment: Here one may find the solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/how-to-translate-and-rotate-the-heading-of-landscaped-pages