# Orient headers and footers depending on portrait or landscape pages in document

Tags: header-footer, pdflscape

when I use `landscape` in my document for some pages, the headers and footers do not change with the orientation of the page.

I would like to know if it possible to get the headers and footers to appear correctly depending on the orientation of the page?

In landscape mode, the page should be modified like this:

[image]

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=120pt, top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}
\newcommand\ftheight{.5in}

\newsavebox\headimageodd
\newsavebox\headimageeven
\newcommand*{\headimages}[3][]{%
  \savebox{\headimageeven}{%
    \includegraphics[height=120pt,#1]{#2}%
  }%
  \savebox{\headimageodd}{%
    \includegraphics[height=120pt,#1]{#3}%
  }%
}
\headimages{example-image-b}{example-image-a}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[O]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries]  at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \else
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=2cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thechapter};
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.5cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (chapter) at (oddpagenum.south east) {\quad TOPIC TO BE DISCUSSED};
    \fi
    \node[anchor=north east, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\usebox\headimageodd};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[E]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south east, text width=7cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \node[anchor=north west, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\usebox\headimageeven};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CE]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south west) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south east) {\today};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CO]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south west) {\today};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south east) {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Problem 1}
\headimages{example-image-c}{example-image}
\section{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{example-image}
\caption{Big Table or Image}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9071/124842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer!

I added `\usepackage{typearea}`(from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250998/124842) and figure in minipage.

Solution:
[image]

Bad style, but maybe it will help you:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=120pt, top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{line}{RGB}{70,160,216}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand\hdheight{1in}
\newcommand\ftheight{.5in}

\newsavebox\headimageodd
\newsavebox\headimageeven
\newcommand*{\headimages}[3][]{%
  \savebox{\headimageeven}{%
    \includegraphics[height=120pt,#1]{#2}%
  }%
  \savebox{\headimageodd}{%
    \includegraphics[height=120pt,#1]{#3}%
  }%
}
\headimages{example-image-b}{example-image-a}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[O]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries]  at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \else
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=2cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{2cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (oddpagenum) at ($(current page.north west)+(.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\thechapter};
      \node[anchor=south west, text width=11.5cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.5cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (chapter) at (oddpagenum.south east) {\quad TOPIC TO BE DISCUSSED};
    \fi
    \node[anchor=north east, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north east) {\usebox\headimageodd};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[E]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\hdheight)$);
    \draw[line] ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-\hdheight]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=south east, text width=7cm, text=white, font=\fontsize{.7cm}{1.5cm}\selectfont\bfseries] (evenpagenum) at ($(current page.north east)+(-.5\hdheight,-\hdheight)$) {\raggedleft\rightmark};
    \node[anchor=north west, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.north west) {\usebox\headimageeven};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CE]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south west) {\thepage};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south east) {\today};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyfoot[CO]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
    \fill[gmitblue] (current page.south west) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(0,.5in)$);
    \node[anchor=south west, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in, inner xsep=5mm] at (current page.south west) {\today};
    \node[anchor=south, text=white, font=\large, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south) {\leftmark};
    \node[anchor=south east, text=white, font=\Large\bfseries, minimum size=.5in] at (current page.south east) {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}

\usepackage{typearea}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Problem 1}
\headimages{example-image-c}{example-image}
\section{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{example-image}
\caption{Big Table or Image}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\section{Problem 1}
\newpage
\storeareas\normalsetting

\KOMAoption{paper}{landscape}
\areaset{2\textwidth}{.8\textheight}
\recalctypearea

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{\hdheight}
    \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{example-image}
    \caption{Caption for image}
    \label{fig:sample_figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\cleardoublepage
\normalsetting

\end{document}
```

Comment: I already have the figure sideways in my original question.  I wanted to orient the header and footer according to the page layout...i.e. either portrait or landscape.  Thanks!

Comment: The orientation of header and footer should not change orientation? Can you explain or add an example picture?

Comment: I added an image for clarification.  Thanks!

Comment: I added a new solution. I hope it's getting better ...