# Landscape table on portrait page

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx, landscape

I have a portrait page with a section heading below which I would like to place a table in landscape (as in this orientation it should take up most of the rest of the page).

I can get the whole page in landscape and do it that way, however, if I do this, the section heading does not appear on the same page.

My current attempt (which sticks the table on a new, landscape, page looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
    \section{Appendix B - Risk Assessment}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering\ra{1.3}
    \caption{Table to show risks, hazards and mitigation techniques for this experiment}
    \label{tbl:RiskMatrix}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X X c X c c}
    \toprule
    Description of Hazard & Consequences & Risk Before & Mitigations Required & Risk After & ALARP? (Yes/No) \\ [0.5ex]
    \midrule
    Electrocution & Serious injury or death & 0.5 & Ensure hands are dry when plugging in. Do not tamper with any electrical components & 0.1 & Yes \\
    Burns from hot components & Non-serious burns & 0.7 & Wear thermally insulated gloves when operating equipment & 0.2 & Yes \\
    Burns from steam & Very serious burns, potential loss of sight & 0.6 & Wear safety goggles and a lab coat to protect from steam egress & 0.2 & Yes \\
    Loss of apparatus integrity & Injuries from shrapnel, serious burns, potentially fatal & 0.3 & Check equipment for signs of buckling before use. Ensure that it remains within safe operating pressures. Ensure ballistic screen is in place around equipment. & 0.2 & Yes \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

If anyone would have any suggestions on how I could achieve this or, if this is not possible, what the best alternative solution might be.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! A minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem with compilable code (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) would be nice. - Does this [question and answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9071/124842) help you?

Comment: `landscape` always starts a new page use `sidewaystable` from the rotating package (or just `\rotatebox` around the tabular if you don't want to rotate the caption)

Comment: Apologies, I've just gotten so used to just posting snippets over on SE, I've updated my answer. The QA linked appears to address the inverse problem, moving headers rather than the tables. @DavidCarlisle I'll have a look at that and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle changing `\begin{table}` to `\begin{sidewaystable}` (and the `\end`) has caused my table to vanish. Do you know what could be causing this off the top of your head? If not, I'll dig through the docs

Comment: I just tried the `\rotatebox` too and that just results in a mangled table with overlapping columns and text.

Comment: @JamesHughes you did something wrong then as `\begin{sideways}` is a very thin wrapper around `\rotatebox` (mostly for compatibility with documents from the 1980's written for the latex2.09 version of the rotating package) (sidewaystable probably doesn't support H so if you still had that try without)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the root cause of that issue turned out to be the fact that it was still utilising the `\textwidth` parameter

Comment: @Persistence: how did you make your table "reappear"? I just changed `\begin{table}` to `\begin{sidewaystable}` (and the `\end`) and this caused my table to vanish...

Comment: @MrT77 - Sorry bud, this was like 4.5 years ago, I have no idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is twofold, thanks to @David Carlilse for the idea to use the `rotating` package.

Firstly, the `tabularx` inside the table needs to be placed inside a `sideways` block.

Secondly, `tabularx` needs to be told the `\textheight` instead of the `\textwidth` so that it knows the total width of the table for its `X` column calculations. However, this results in the column overlapping with the page number so we subtract 3cm for margin.

The section now reads like this:

```
\section{Appendix B - Risk Assessment}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering\ra{1.3}
\caption{Table to show risks, hazards and mitigation techniques for this experiment}
\label{tbl:RiskMatrix}
\begin{sideways}
\begin{tabularx}{\textheight - 3cm}{X X c X c c}
\toprule
Description of Hazard & Consequences & Risk Before & Mitigations Required & Risk After & ALARP? (Yes/No) \\ [0.5ex]
\midrule
Electrocution & Serious injury or death & 0.5 & Ensure hands are dry when plugging in. Do not tamper with any electrical components & 0.1 & Yes \\
Burns from hot components & Non-serious burns & 0.7 & Wear thermally insulated gloves when operating equipment & 0.2 & Yes \\
Burns from steam & Very serious burns, potential loss of sight & 0.6 & Wear safety goggles and a lab coat to protect from steam egress & 0.2 & Yes \\
Loss of apparatus integrity & Injuries from shrapnel, serious burns, potentially fatal & 0.3 & Check equipment for signs of buckling before use. Ensure that it remains within safe operating pressures. Ensure ballistic screen is in place around equipment. & 0.2 & Yes \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sideways}
\end{table}
```

Comment: if you are using that form you don't need `rotating` you could just use graphicx and replace begin{sideways}...\end{sidways} by \rotatebox{90}{...}  (which is how it's defined)