# Section on one page with includepdf [landscape]

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, include, landscape

I want to include a PDF in landscape (its a table in PDF form)
with include PDF. I want a section on the same side, but when I use this command, the section heading is not on top (of that landscape page).

```
\includepdf[landscape=true, page=1,pagecommand=\section{Section Heading}]{table.pdf}
```

[image]

As you can see. B Section Heading is on the right. But i want it on top.

Comment: Could you provide a image of your current result or desired result? Because compiling your code I get what I'd expect... the section gets rotated with the inserted content.

Comment: i added a picture

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple reasons for this. I suspect that `\pdfpages` still uses the "portrait coordinate system" for pages included in landscape, thus "LaTeX" does not know that you are in landscape mode. You've just rotated the one PDF-page.

If you use e.g. the [`pdflscape`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape)-package to tell LaTeX that you are in landscape mode first, it seems to work fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}
    \includepdf[landscape=true, pagecommand=\section{Section Heading}]{table.pdf}
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9072/75648).
I have rotated the headings using textblock and rotated the included pdf again.

[image: turned page with rotated heading]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{textpos}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{textblock}{20}(-17,-2.5){\rotatebox{90}{\leftmark}}
\section{Section Heading}

\begin{figure}[]
\includegraphics[,angle=-90,origin=c]{document_test.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{textblock}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```