# How to translate and rotate the heading of landscaped pages? (revisited)

Tags: geometry, landscape

@Leo Liu's geometry [patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374533/112708) seemed too good to be true, and as it turns out it works only once (in this case, for chapter Bar, not Qux). It there a modidification that would make it always work? Side issue: why doesn't `pagestyle` have any effect?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape,lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374533/112708%--------------
\makeatletter
\def\ifGm@preamble#1{\@firstofone}
\appto\restoregeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}
\apptocmd\newgeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titleps}%-----------------------------------------
\usepackage{lastpage}
\newpagestyle{cust}
{
  \setfoot{%
    \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}
  }{}{}
}

\begin{document}%---------------------------------------------
%\pagestyle{empty}%Ignored
\pagestyle{cust}%Ignored
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1][1]

\newgeometry{,top=2em,landscape}
\savegeometry{landscape}
\chapter{Bar}
\lipsum[1][2]


\restoregeometry
\chapter{Baz}
\lipsum[1][3]

%\newgeometry{,top=2em,landscape}%Ignored
\loadgeometry{landscape}%Ignored
\chapter{Qux}
\lipsum[1][4]

\end{document}%-----------------------------------------------
```

[image: Shot 1]
[image: Shot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to patch `\loadgeometry` too. And the first page of a chapter uses plain style, so you need to change this page style.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape,lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374533/112708%--------------
\makeatletter
\def\ifGm@preamble#1{\@firstofone}
\appto\restoregeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}
\apptocmd\newgeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}{}{}
\apptocmd\loadgeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}{}{}  
\makeatother

\usepackage{titleps}%-----------------------------------------
\usepackage{lastpage}
\newpagestyle{cust}
{
  \setfoot{%
    \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}
  }{}{}
}
\renewpagestyle{plain}
{
  \setfoot{%
    \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}
  }{}{}
}
\begin{document}%---------------------------------------------
%\pagestyle{empty}%Ignored
\pagestyle{cust}%Ignored
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1][1]

\newgeometry{,top=2em,landscape}
\savegeometry{landscape}
\chapter{Bar}
\lipsum[1][2]


\restoregeometry
\chapter{Baz}
\lipsum[1][3]

%\newgeometry{,top=2em,landscape}%Ignored
\loadgeometry{landscape}%Ignored
\chapter{Qux}
\lipsum[1][4]

\end{document}
```