# Page number doesn't go down when changing paper size in mid-document

Tags: pdftex

I'm trying to change the size of a single page in my document. Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6838/178369) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817170/3337089) answer, I used `\eject \pdfpagewidth=8.27in \pdfpageheight=15in`, but the page number is not at the bottom, but at it's usual distance from top in a normal page as shown in the below figure. How can I make the page number go to the bottom?

**Code snippet**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Summary of various Image and Video Quality Metrics on various Databases}
\author{Nagabhushan S N}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage[paperheight=11.69in,paperwidth=8.27in,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup {
    colorlinks = true
}
\begin{document}

\eject \pdfpagewidth=8.27in \pdfpageheight=15in
\section{Blah blah blah}\label{sec:vqa}
More blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

**Sample Image**:

[image: Sample image]

PS: I'm using pdflatex.

Comment: \pdfpagewidth only adapts the "background paper". If you want to change the layout (textwidth/textheight etc), you should use the other answer which uses typearea.

Comment: But with typearea, I see that I can specify only standard page sizes. Can I specify arbitrary size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of packages `typearea` and `geometry`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[usegeometry,paper=11.69in:8.27in]{typearea}% load before geometry
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\newcommand\changepapersize[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=#1,DIV=last}%
  \newgeometry{margin=1in,footskip=0.5in}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\storeareas\defaultareasettings}
\BeforeRestoreareas{\clearpage}

\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup {colorlinks = true}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\lipsum

\changepapersize{15in:8.27in}
\section{Blah blah blah}\label{sec:vqa}
\lipsum[1-15]

\defaultareasettings
\section{Foo}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This solution have a little problem with page number in rotated pages. But I follow this solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250998/14423

Comment: @juanuni Which problem do you mean?

Comment: well, the problem ocurrs when the page is rotated, for example, with `pdflscape`. In that case the page number also is rotated.

Comment: Do you want to switch to `landscape` for some pages inside the document? And the page number should be below the rotated text?

Comment: You are rigth. With `pdflscape` I couldn't do it.

Comment: You could change the code above to: `\usepackage[usegeometry,paper=a4]{geometry}` or `paper=letter` or another paper format. Then use `\changepapersize{landscape}` in the document.

Comment: Yeah, but if is needed a custom paper size and switch to `landscape` ?

Comment: You could use `\changepapersize` twice: `\changepapersize{landscape}\changepapersize{15in:8.27in}`. Or redefine `\changepapersize` to `...\KOMAoption{paper}{#1}\KOMAoption{DIV}{last}`. Then `#1` can be a list and you can use `\changepapersize{landscape,15in:8.27in}`.

Comment: How could I do it but with XeLaTeX