# A3 Page within A4 document - broken layout (koma&geometry)

Tags: floats, koma-script, geometry

I'm currently writing my master thesis. I have a large class diagramm which I want to add as A3 page within the A4 documents. Unfortanetly the layout of my documents seems to break using the commands:

```
\afterpage{% Insert after the current page
    \clearpage
    \KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape,pagesize}
    \recalctypearea
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{Bilder/Class_Diagramm.png}
        \caption{Klassendiagramm der Gesamtsoftware}
        \label{fig3_1:}
    \end{figure}  
    \clearpage
    \KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
    \recalctypearea
}
```

The output looks like this but I only want one A3 page with the graphic on full A3 size [image: A3 Image]

Within my header file I also use

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper,            % Papierformat
oneside,            % einseitiger Druck
%twoside,           % zweiseitiger Druck
12pt,               % Schriftgröße
onecolumn,          % einspaltiger Text
%twocolumn,         % zweispaltiger Text
openright,          % Kapitel dürfen nur auf einer rechten Seite beginnen
openany,            % Kapitel dürfen rechts oder links beginnen
parskip=half,       % eine halbe Zeile Abstand zw. Absätzen
headsepline,        % Kopfzeilenlinie
footsepline,        % Fußzeilenlinie
bibliography=totoc, % Bibliographie im Inhaltsverzeichnis
hidelinks,          % Verstecke Boxen um die Hyperlinks
%idxtotoc           % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
left=25mm,
right=25mm,
top=30mm,
bottom=40mm,
%includeheadfoot,
]{geometry}
```

Does someone know why there is this strange interaction within the layout? Could this be due to interaction between geometry and koma?

Comment: With geometry you have a text area 645.87756pt by 455.24411pt, but using `\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}` changes the text area to 548.5pt by
448.13095pt, which is what you would get without geometry.  Using `\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,pagesize}` changes the text area to 389.0pt by 338.01878pt, which is just plain wrong!

Comment: It is, however, what you would get if you started with a3paper.  Weird!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528238/page-number-doesnt-go-down-when-changing-paper-size-in-mid-document  The accepted solution uses \KOMAoptions and \newgeometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which worked for me

```
\newpage
\storeareas\normaleinstellung
\KOMAoptions{paper=a3,paper=landscape}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{.5\paperwidth}
\activateareas
\storeareas\spezialeinstellung
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{Bilder/Class_Diagramm.png}
    \caption{Klassendiagramm der Gesamtsoftware}
    \label{fig3_2:klassendiagramm}
\end{figure} 
\clearpage
\normaleinstellung
```

I used \newpage instead of clearpage so that I don't add a blank page before the figure. Using \storeareas helped to switch between the layouts.

Comment: I would use [p] instead of [H], since it is intended to use the entire page.  Note that the caption will extend below the bottom of the text area, depending of how keepaspectratio restricts the sizes.