# Adding unnumbered sections to TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, minitoc, unnumbered-sections

I have many unnumbered sections in my report (more than 100), all created with:

`\section*{section name}`

I want to find a way to easily add them all to the `TOC` (specifically to a `minitoc`). Since I use the `*` to remove the numbering, they won't appear in `TOC`. I found out in `minitoc` documentation that I should use:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{repeat here section title}
```

However, I don't want to have a duplicated title in every section, or even to change all the involved files to add those already written sections to the `TOC`. How to add those sections' names to the `minitoc` without using the `addcontentsline` command? Is it possible?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use `\section` but to change `secnumdepth` so that they don't get numbered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{ADSF}
\section{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm! It's easier to remove the * from each section than duplicate all their names! And I could even use the \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} after some chapters, keeping the numbering on the previous ones!

Comment: A convenient solution, but unsuitable for documents with a mix of numbered and non-numbered parts. For these scenarios, look at @Vser 's answer below

Comment: For a scoped version, enclose the relevant part in `{}` and use `\makeatletter\c@secnumdepth=0\makeatother` at the beginning.Also, to apply either to chapters, use -1.

Comment: This messes up either toc page numbers and/or bookmark page numbers and/or clickable links (wrong pages), unfortunately. You have to randomly spread `\phantomsection` additions and hope that nothing breaks.

Comment: agreed ruins \hyperref on the toc

Answer (score 99):

Another solution using `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{repeat here section title}` relies on nameref. In fact I'm numbering every section (chapters and so on) with a label. So you could use:

```
% Package 'hyperref' needed for command '\nameref'
\section*{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:intro}}
```

It's only a local change and is persistent to names' change of your section.

Comment: [Non numbered chapter\* header issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199086)

Comment: Do you need to include `\usepackage{nameref}` in the header to do this ?

Comment: Rather `\usepackage{hyperref}` I think.

Comment: This is a better solution for those seeking a document with both numbered and non-numbered parts/sections.

Comment: This also works for other composition units like chapters with `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{<label_of_chapter>}}`.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using [KOMA-Script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script?lang=de) the easiest way is to use these built in commands:

`\addpart \addchap \addsec`

Which work just like  `\part* \chapter* \section*` 
while also being added to the toc.

Comment: Simple and Elegant! God bless Markus Kohm, who created the Koma Scripts. They always surprise me with very elegant solutions to awkward LaTeX problems. (See, for example [solution for landscape pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode/430619#430619))

Answer (score 4):

Easy to use:

```
\section*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Preface}
```

got this answer here : https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=335

Comment: Nicely simplified, but there is not a great difference with @Vser answer. ;)

Comment: Down vote.  This is exactly the code that's included in the question.  Your answer adds nothing new.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to redefine your chapters (or sections). Here I copy what I did for my report. I redefined `\chapter*` and defined a `\chapter**`

The latter is the old `\chapter*`, while the former is an unnembered chapter, but added to the toc.

```
 \let\@originalchapter\chapter
     \def\chapter{
                 \@ifstar\chapterstar\@originalchapter
                 }
     \def\chapterstar{
                 \@ifstar\chapter@nonum@notoc\chapter@nonum
                 }
 \newcommand\chapter@nonum[2][]{
         \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{
          \cleardoublepage
          \phantomsection
          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}#2}
          \@originalchapter*{#2}
          \chaptermark{#2}
          }{
          \cleardoublepage
          \phantomsection
          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}#1}
          \@originalchapter*[#1]{#2}
          \chaptermark{#1}
       }
  }
 \newcommand\chapter@nonum@notoc[2][]{
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{
        \@originalchapter*{#2}
        \chaptermark{#2}
     }{
     \@originalchapter*[#1]{#2}
     \chaptermark{#1}
   }
}

\let\@originaltableofcontents\tableofcontents
  \def\tableofcontents{
   \let\@toclocaloriginalchapter\chapter
   \def\chapter{\@toclocaloriginalchapter*}
   \@originaltableofcontents
   \def\chapter{\@toclocaloriginalchapter}
}
```

Comment: Of course, you can do the same with `\section` and `\section*`