# how to exclude a chapter from numbering?

Tags: chapters, thesis

How can I remove the number of a chapter (preface) both in the table of contents and the first page of this chapter?

Comment: Use `\chapter*{Preface} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}`.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11668/adding-unnumbered-sections-to-toc