# Adding unnumbered subsections to toc

Tags: sectioning

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11669/174620 This answer worked very well for setting the counter to zero for sections. I want similar command for subsection. I tried `\setcounter{subsecnumdepth}{0}` which gave `No counter 'subsecnumdepth' defined.}\\\setcounter{subsecnumdepth}{0}` this error. Is there any way for setting subsection counter 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`, all subsections already are unnumbered. (If you want numbered sections but unnumbered subsections, you can use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}`.)

To include the subsections in the table of contents, use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`.