# Some of the contents are not showing with `toc` command

Tags: table-of-contents, texshop

I am almost done with my document, now, I notice that `toc` not able to show `abstract`, àcknowledgement` and other chapters in table of contents. Whereas all chapters are able to appear in my contents.

Any help please?

`main.tex`

````
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\NoWarnNat{
\xpatchcmd{\NAT@citexnum}{\PackageWarning}{\let\PackageWarning\@gobbletwo\PackageWarning}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\NAT@citex}{\PackageWarning}{\let\PackageWarning\@gobbletwo\PackageWarning}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\nocite}{\PackageWarning}{\let\PackageWarning\@gobbletwo\PackageWarning}{}{}
}
\makeatother


\NoWarnNat

%\author{Python Buddha}
\date{02 March 2020}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\chapter*{Hingabe}


\chapter*{Erklärung}
Declaration was originally a self-published electronic pamphlet by Michael Hardt and Antonio Negri on the Occupy movement that was released as a "Kindle single" in May 2012. The book explores the new democratic politics of organization, representation, and resistance that have been inaugurated by the movement. It has since been published in paper form by Argo-Navis.

\chapter*{Bestätigung}

n data networking, telecommunications, and computer buses, an acknowledgement is a signal that is passed between communicating processes, computers, or devices to signify acknowledgement, or receipt of message, as part of a communications protocol


\chapter*{Zusammenfassung}
\input{chapters/abstract_v2}

\chapter*{Weisheiten}
\input{chapters/introduction_v2}

\chapter{nehmen}
\input{chapters/chapter1_v1}

\chapter{Suchen}
\input{chapters/chapter2_v1}

\chapter{die Stille}
\input{chapters/chapter3_v1}

\chapter{Einzelstimmen}
\input{chapters/chapter4_v1}

\chapter{Abkündigungen}
\input{chapters/chapter5_v1}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Title}
\input{mainchapters/appendix}

\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{/Users/pythonbuddha/Documents/Thesis/References.bib}
\end{document}

```
````

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Adding unnumbered sections to TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11668/5764)

Comment: Another potential duplicate: [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35433)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because unnumbered chapters, sections, etc. are not directly included in table of contents. However, you can include them manually with the `\addcontentsline` command. This command takes three arguments:

1. The table in which the contents has to be included; use `toc` for table of contents.
2. The type of content; for example `chapter`, `section`, `subsection`,
   etc.
3. The name of the content that should appear in the table.

For example,

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter*{First unnumbered chapter}
\chapter*{Other unnumbered chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Other unnumbered chapter}
\chapter{Other chapter}

\end{document}
```

results in the following table of contents.
[image]