# Render a table of contents like an itemize list

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, itemize

I write some short reports with the `article` class, and I would like to have a minimalist table of contents, which would be rendered like an `itemized` list. To be more specific, I would like to have a rendering similar as this one (but with clickable titles) for the table of contents of an article with three sections.

```
\subsection*{Agenda}

\begin{itemize}
    \item First section
    \item Second section
    \item etc
\end{itemize}
```

Is it possible to easily get such a result?
Thank you in advance!

**Edit: Thank you for your answers! Here is the code I used.**

```tex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{}  % Removes the section numbers in the ToC
\renewcommand{\l@section}[2]{#1}  % #1 = section number + title; #2 = page number
\pretocmd{\contentsline}{\item\gdef\contentslineused{}}{}{}
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{
    \subsection*{Agenda}
    \begin{itemize}
        \@starttoc{toc}
        \ifcsname contentslineused\endcsname\else
            \item Agenda
        \fi
    \end{itemize}
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code prints the `\tableofcontents` as an `itemize`d list. I've removed the numbering of the `\section`s by making `\numberline` do nothing with it's argument (the section number). Note that you'll have to manually insert sections' titles into the ToC if you're using `\section*` (see [Adding unnumbered sections to ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11668/5764)). Of course, you can update the way `\section` functions to do that automatically, based on your setup.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1\quad}% Keeps the section numbers in the ToC
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{}% Removes the section numbers in the ToC
\renewcommand{\l@section}[2]{% #1 = section number + title; #2 = page number
  #1\dotfill #2
}
\pretocmd{\contentsline}{\item\gdef\contentslineused{}}{}{}
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \begin{itemize}
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \ifcsname contentslineused\endcsname\else
      \item Table of Contents
    \fi
  \end{itemize}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Agenda}

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Final section}

\end{document}
```

The conditional syntax within the newly-defined `\tableofcontents` is to avoid a first-time compile when there is no ToC yet. It'll print a list with a single item `Table of Contents` when there is no ToC, and the actual ToC after another compilation.

Comment: I tried this code, but it throws an error: `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`. However, it works if I add a `\item test` just after the `\begin{itemize}` for example.

Comment: @MichaelMarx: Right... I already had a ToC file while I was working on the code, so forgot to check for the existence of a `.toc`. I've updated the code to accommodate for that.

Comment: Thank you! I just updated my post with the final code I used. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that employs the machinery of the [tocloft](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft) package.

[image]

I interpreted your write-up as not wanting to show the page numbers; if this interpretation is incorrect, simply omit (or comment out) the instruction `\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\@gobble}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % optional
\renewcommand\contentsname{Agenda}
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\normalsize\bfseries} % default: \Large\bfseries
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\mdseries} % default is \bfseries
\setlength\cftsecnumwidth{1em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cftsecpresnum{\textbullet\@gobble} % don't show section numbers
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\@gobble}           % don't show page numbers
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % choose a suitable color

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\section{Second}
\section{Third}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I like your code, however I preferred the other one cause the bullet is not included in the link (I personally find it more aesthetic).

Comment: @MichaelMarx - If you had asked about how one might change the color of the text bullet, I could have let you know that all you'd have to do was to replace `\textbullet` with `{\color{black}\textullet}`.

Comment: In fact, I was thinking about the box that defines the link to the section. The bullet is included in the clickable frame, as if it is part of the link, and I find it a bit confusing. I chose the other answer because I find it more straighforward (as it defines epxlicitly an `itemize`), so I could more easily figure how to customize it. :)