# Rotate single PDF page when viewing

Tags: pdf, rotating

I got a Latex document which renders fine, some content is rotated using the `turn` environment from the `rotate` package. Everything works like it should.

Except: It know that it is possible to display a single page in a pdf in another orientation. The document viewer then rotates this page when viewing. This would help the readers of my document to read the turned text.

How is this possible? Perhaps somehow using the `pdfpageattr` command?

Again: I do not to want to rotate the content, I just want to tell the PDF-Reader that it should rotate the page when displaying.

Comment: You could have a look at how [pdflscape](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) does it.

Comment: I already tried that, but I can not read Latex Module Code so I do not understand what happens there.

Comment: So you want a series of regular (portrait) pages, and then a rotated (landscape) page, and then some more regular (portrait) pages, right? Is it possible to completely separate the content on the landscape page? That is, is it (say) a page-sized `table` or `figure`, or does the landscape page form part of the regular text flow, but you just want it rotated?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can indeed use the `pdfpageattr` command. You can do it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  text

  \pagebreak[4]
  \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}
  text
\end{document}
```

This will rotate the second page by 90 degrees. It should be obvious how to get different rotations.

Comment: If I change the important line with the folowing: `\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{/Rotate 90}`, it also work. Why?

Comment: then the current attributes won't be saved. Which is usually not a problem, unless you have some other attributes set already.

Comment: Thanks, exacttly what I was searching for. Now I'm running into other problems, but that will be another question here.

Comment: Could you please show how to do this for a *single* page, i.e. how to change it back to the default after one page. This would improve the answer very much. I would recommend to use `afterpage`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer It's been a while and your suggestion hasn't been included in this answer. I landed on this question wanting to know how to do exactly what you describe! Would you be able to expand on your suggestion with an edit, or a separate answer?

Comment: +1, and to rotate back I just added the same thing afterward but with `Rotate 0` instead of `Rotate 90`.

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer did not work for me, since it rotated all pages in the PDF instead of a single one. I managed to get it to work using the `pdflscape` package instead, as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode):

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
...
\begin{landscape}
...
\end{landscape}
```

I needed this to display figures. Note that, when inside the `landscape` environment, you must use `\linewidth` for a figure's width, `\textwidth` will not work.

Comment: The `pdfpageattr` didn't work for me either. `pdflscape` works fine.

Comment: upvote for the `\linewidth` clarification!

Answer (score 13):

A slightly more complete version to the accepted answer would be to create an environment that turns the page back to portrait:

```
\newenvironment{rotatepage}%
    {\clearpage\pagebreak[4]\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}}%
    {\clearpage\pagebreak[4]\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}}%
```

And then `\begin{rotatepage} <the content on this page is turned 90°> \end{rotatepage}`.

---

But we can extend this further. We might want to use the features provided by the `rotating` package. And we might use documents that use different margins for odd and even pages. Then an automated solution that turns the page by 90° or 270° respectively would be nice. An example using KOMA script:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrextend,rotating}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{rotatepage}
        {%
            \if@twoside%
                \ifthispageodd{\pagebreak[4]\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}}{%
                \pagebreak[4]\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 270}}%
            \else%
                \pagebreak[4]\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}%
            \fi%
        }%
        {\pagebreak[4]\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}}%

\makeatother
```

And then `\begin{rotatepage}\begin{sidewaystable} <the content on this page is turned 90°> \end{sidewaystable}\end{rotatepage}`

---

Finally, we can combine `rotatepage` and the environments provided by the `rotating` package. If we want to turn pages automatically that use `sidewaytable`, we can hook the `rotatepage` environment into `sidewaytable` with `etoolbox`. In addition to the code above we would need:

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{sidewaystable}{\begin{rotatepage}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{sidewaystable}{\end{rotatepage}}
```

Of course, similar adjustments could be made for `sidewaysfigure` etc.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the `afterpage` solution ended up being simpler for me - linking for visibility because this question comes up more often in search: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433414/77706

Comment: I suggest to add `\clearpage` so that the environment does not affect multiple pages. `\newenvironment{rotatepage}%
    {\clearpage\pagebreak[4]\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}}%
    {\clearpage\pagebreak[4]\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}}%`

Answer (score 2):

In a comment to [Roelof Spijker's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40692/6865) Martin Scharrer requested the use of the [afterpage package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) to rotate the following pages back again:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
text
\makeatletter%
\if@twoside%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}%
  \afterpage{\afterpage{\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}}}%
\else%
  \clearpage%
  \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}%
  \afterpage{\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}}%
\fi%
\makeatother%
text
\newpage
text
\newpage
text
\end{document}
```

Creating an environment ([answer of Jörg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212843/6865)) seems to be the better solution imho, thus this answer is just for demonstrative purpose (but might be helpful in another context).