Landscape page with section title in portrait
I am trying to include a big table in the first page of my appendix, so right under the section title. However, the result using \begin{landscape} also rotates the section title. The document will be printed, so I want the section title to stay at the top, but the table be rotated, while at the same time having the whole page rotated in landscape as a pdf to make it easier to view.
Right now, the result is shown in the image, and I want the section title "Anexo" to be placed where I drew it in red, or at least I think that is the best way to format this (I'm open to suggestions).
This is the code I used:
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\section*{Anexo}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anexos}
\markboth{ANEXO}{ANEXO}


\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}[bh]
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tblr}{

...

\end{tblr}
}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

I tried other methods (rotating, sidewaystable...) but none work. I think the best would be to rotate the table, and then rotate the page but without changing the formatting, so without rotating the text box or text direction, but I haven't found how to do that.


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Can you edit your code to provide an example we can compile to reproduce the problem? As far as I know whether the page gets rotated or not depends on your PDF viewer anyway, so there is nothing you can do to guarantee this. That is, even if you get this to work, you can't know whether your reader will get rotation or not. I'm sure there was a question about this ... or similar to this ....

Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699428/displaying-some-pdf-pages-in-landscape-without-affecting-printing?rq=1 help? (This isn't the question I was thinking of, but seems to pose essentially the same kind of problem.)

@cfr apologies for not answering. So I found about \pdfpageattr in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40683/rotate-single-pdf-page-when-viewing and I managed to rotate the page, but now using sidewaystable takes the whole page and it can't be in the same page as the section title...

You need to just rotate the tabular environment e.g. put it in a box and rotate the box. sidewaystable will put it on its own page. But the table won't get automatically rotated in the viewer in that case, of course. As I say, if you want people to play with approaches, you need to provide code.
