\afterpage positions landscape page later than expected
I have a wide table that had to be rotated to landscape.
For this I used pdflandscape, but I found out that without \afterpage, text wouldn't flow.
After enclosing the landscape environment in \afterpage, the table get positioned later in the document than it should.
In the code, there is a figure right after the table, but in the PDF, the table shows the figure right before the table.
Is this expected? Have I done something wrong? It makes no sense to cite a Table in the text and have it shown after you have already cited a different figure...
Thanks a lot!
MWE:
\documentclass[11pt, b5paper, openright]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
    \section{Results}
        \subsection{LC-HRMS metabolomic and chemometric analyses}
            \lipsum[1]
            \begin{figure}[h!]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{example-image-10x16}
                \caption{
                    Representative LC-HRMS total ion chromatograms (TICs) and PCA metabolomic analysis.  \textbf{(a)} Overlaid Total Ion Chromatograms (TIC) for three quality control 
                    (QC) samples at different injection sequence points, represented in orange color. These chromatograms demonstrate the excellent reproducibility observed in 
                    retention times. The TIC is also shown for a malignant melanoma patient (MMP) in red color and a healthy control (HC) in black color. Furthermore, the figure 
                    includes Extracted Ion Chromatograms (XIC) of three marker metabolites: PE(18:2) in blue line, PC(18:2) in purple line, and Hexoyl-PE(18:2) in pink line. PCA \textbf{(b)} 
                    and PLS-DA \textbf{(c)} scores plot based on LC-HRMS data of serum samples from total MMPs (red), and HCs (green). QC samples are indicated in blue. PCA \textbf{(d)} and PLS-DA \textbf{(e)} 
                    scores plot based on LC-HRMS data of serum samples from stage I MMP (red) and HCs (green).
                }
                \label{chromatogram}
            \end{figure}
            \lipsum[1-4]
            \begin{figure}[h!]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=0.65\textheight]{example-image-10x16}
                \caption{
                    \textbf{(a)}  Heatmap where each row represents the intensity of each metabolite selected as potential biomarker with its characteristic mass to charge ratio and retention time, while each column represents each of the serum samples. \textbf{(b)} Heatmap where each row represents the average intensity of each metabolite selected as potential biomarker and each column represents each group of samples.
                    The colour code represents the normalized intensity with which each metabolite is detected. Blue represents a decreasing trend, while red represents a rising trend.
                }
            \end{figure}
            \lipsum[1-4]
        \subsection{Identification of potential biomarkers}
            \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
            \afterpage{
            \begin{landscape}
                \vspace*{\fill}
                \begin{table}[htb!]
                    \centering
                    \caption{Potential biomarkers differentially expressed in MMP (Stage I) compared to HC serum samples based on MS/MS fragmentation spectra and data-base search.}
                    \label{metabolites}
                        \small
                        \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
                            \toprule
                            \textbf{ID}   & \textbf{m/z\textsuperscript{1}}  & \textbf{RT\textsuperscript{2}} & \textbf{Tentative ID\textsuperscript{3}}     & \textbf{Molecular Formula\textsuperscript{4}} & \textbf{Mass error\textsuperscript{5}} & \textbf{P-value\textsuperscript{6}} & \textbf{FC\textsuperscript{7}}   & \textbf{AUC\textsuperscript{8}} & \textbf{VIP\textsuperscript{9}} & \textbf{IL\textsuperscript{10}} \\
                            \midrule
                            M8   & 319.1932 & 15.75  & ---                  & ---                       & ---            & $3.64x10^{-3}$   & 0.63 (↓) & 0.77    & 1.59    & -       \\
                            M31  & 478.2926 & 10.50  & PE(18:2)             & \ce{C23H44NO7P}           & 0              & $6.42x10^{-7}$   & 1.78 (↑) & 0.89    & 2.14    & 2       \\
                            M43  & 500.2737 & 10.72  & PE(20:5)             & \ce{C25H42NO7P}           & 7              & $8.77x10^{-5}$   & 1.55 (↑) & 0.79    & 1.68    & 2       \\
                            M56  & 520.3398 & 10.74  & PC(18:2)             & \ce{C26H50NO7P}           & 1              & $1.73x10^{-7}$   & 1.80 (↑) & 0.90    & 2.20    & 2       \\
                            M61  & 531.3236 & 10.83  & ---                  & ---                       & ---            & $7.90x10^{-7}$   & 1.75 (↑) & 0.88    & 2.17    & -       \\
                            M64  & 539.3174 & 10.81  & CDP-DG(18:0/22:3)    & \ce{C52H91N3O15P2}        & 1              & $5.85x10^{-8}$   & 1.95 (↑) & 0.90    & 2.45    & 1       \\
                            M65  & 542.3222 & 10.83  & PC(20:5/0:0)         & \ce{C28H48NO7P}           & 3              & $1.16x10^{-6}$   & 1.54 (↑) & 0.87    & 1.89    & 2       \\
                            M95  & 604.2886 & 10.58  & POB-PS               & \ce{C26H48NO11P}          & 5              & $5.09x10^{-8}$   & 1.62 (↑) & 0.91    & 2.07    & 2       \\
                            M97  & 610.3136 & 10.62  & ---                  & ---                       & ---            & $1.20x10^{-7}$   & 1.69 (↑) & 0.9     & 2.12    & -       \\
                            M102 & 640.3431 & 10.26  & Hexosyl-PE(18:2)     & \ce{C29H54NO12P}          & 4              & $1.17x10^{-3}$   & 2.03 (↑) & 0.73    & 2.09    & 2       \\
                            \bottomrule
                        \end{tabular}
                        \vspace{0.5mm}
                        \footnotesize
                        \begin{flushleft}
                            \textsuperscript{\textbf{1}} Mass-to-charge ratio; \textsuperscript{\textbf{2}} Retention time (min); \textsuperscript{\textbf{3}} Common name of the tentatively identified metabolite according to MS/MS fragmentation spectra and data-base search; \textsuperscript{\textbf{4}} Molecular formula of the tentatively identified metabolite; \textsuperscript{\textbf{5}} Mass error (ppm); \textsuperscript{\textbf{6}} p-value corresponding to univariate statistical analyses (T-test). Only peaks with a p-value \textless 0.05 were selected;
                            \textsuperscript{\textbf{7}} Fold change expressed as the ratio of the two averages (HC/MMP). Only peaks with a fold-change \textgreater 1.5 or \textless 0.66 were selected. The arrows indicate if the metabolite is increased (↑) or decreased (↓) in HC relative to MMP; \textsuperscript{\textbf{8}} Area Under the Curve corresponding to ROC curve analyses; \textsuperscript{\textbf{9}} VIP value corresponding to Variable Importance in the Projection selection technique;
                            \textsuperscript{\textbf{10}} Identification level: (1) Molecular formula matched in compound databases and (2) Experimental fragmentation spectrum matched in spectral databases and in silico fragmentation tools.
                        \end{flushleft}
                \end{table}
                \vspace*{\fill}
            \end{landscape}
            }
            \lipsum[1]
        \subsection{Clinical characterization of candidate biomarkers}
            \lipsum[1-3]
            \begin{figure}[p]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=0.7\textheight]{example-image-10x16}
                \caption{
                    \textbf{(a)} Graphical illustration of the relationship between candidate biomarkers and both stage I MM subtype (SSM: Superficial spreading melanoma; ALM: Acral lentigous melanoma; LMM: Lentigo maligna melanoma) and stage I MM location.
                    \textbf{(b-e)} Box plots representing MM type and location features for metabolites M43 and M102. Boxplots for the resting metabolites are included in the Supporting Information (Figure S2).}
                \label{clinical}
            \end{figure}
        \subsection{Model performance}
            \subsubsection{Metabolite selection}
                \lipsum[1-2]
            \subsubsection{Model training}
                \lipsum[1-2]
                \begin{figure}[ht]
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
                    \caption{
                        Model development results. \textbf{(a)} ROC curves representing the average performance of each of the algorithms employed after repeated 10-fold cross-validation and hyperparameter tuning on the training set.
                        \textbf{(b)} Confusion matrix and performance metrics yielded by the SLNN model on the validation dataset.
                    }
                \end{figure}
            \subsubsection{Model validation}
                \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SE. Do I understand correctly that by the time you wish to get the table environment typeset in landscape mode, there's also a figure environment that is waiting to get typeset? Please advise.

use sidewaystable (from the rotating package) instead of this afterpage/landscape/table combination. But beside this: figure and table belong to different float classes, so their order is not forced: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388

As far as I know, that is not the case, since the figure is defined AFTER the table, so in my understanding it should be after the table in the queue.

Regarding sidewaystable, I discarded that option since it only rotates the table, but not the page. I find that really annoying, since I don't want my readers to tilt their heads in fron of the screen...I'll stick to it if there is no solution

the only reason to put anything in a figure or table environmment os to allow it to move, so the figure moving is not unexpected. als note size commands do not take an argument so just \footnotesize ... not \footnotesize{...}

a MWE is supposed to be working that is we are supposed to be able to use it to see the issue. But the code is incomplete. That said, you have specified the tabular should appear at the next page break so if you want the tabular before the figure put \clearpage before the figure to ensure the page break is before the figure

you can rotate pages with sidewaystables: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699430/2388

You are adding a space after \afterpage and before \begin{landscape} (which automatically performs a \clearpage).

@DavidCarlisle Yeah, I understand that about floats, but I don't want the order to be messed up. Also, sorry for the not working MWE. I thought including the whole thing would be too much code. I'll try to include everything next time. Regarding the use of \clearpage, that would send me back to the problem of origin: having the text not flowing and resulting in a half-empty page before the figure...I guess I'll move to sidewaystable.
PD: Thanks for the clarification on \footnotesize :)

Thanks @UlrikeFischer, I'll give it a go.

@JohnKormylo I've checked the code I posted and also my original code and I haven't found such spaces :/

the order isn't messed up, by design figure and table can float past each other, latex will keep all floating figures in order and all floating tables in order but allows different types to pass. If you need them in the same order they should be the same float type. On examples you can use example-image which is in tex distributions for such tests and then make a small but complete example that shows the problem, it would not need to be much larger than the code posted but would allow answers to be tetsted.

with no test file hard to be sure, but essentially you are forcing the figure on to the current page with [h] but forcing the table on to the next page with \afterpage so the table coming after the figure is essentially the direct result of the markup, Probably you should change the figure to use [p] so it is delayed to a float page so will come after a page break.

Thanks a lot for your replies @DavidCarlisle. I'll edit the MWE so that it's testeable.
I think I already tried before changing the position of the figure with the argument and nothing changed :/

\afterpage{  adds a space.  \afterpage{% does not.

@JohnKormylo true, but it's in vmode so the space is ignored, it saves a byte of token memory that mattered when I wrote afterpage, less so now

It seemed a likely candidate for the extra page, but with no complete MWE I couldn't test.

Hello @DavidCarlisle, the MWE has been updated. It actually took me a while to reproduce the behaviour...it seems it's the exact combination of text lengths that triggers it. I had to play with lipsum length a lot. As you can see, Figure 3 renders before Table although the Table is declared earlier than the figure in the text.

Thanks I'll look although your comment although the Table is declared earlier than the figure in the text shows you are not thinking about this the way latex is. The latex implementation basically says one float is figure the other is table so they are different classes and explicitly allowed to float past each other. LaTeX has absolutely no built in mechanism to stop a table floating past a figure.

@DavidCarlisle sorry for the word choice, I understand now how floats work. I meant "I'd like the floats to be rendered in the same order they are declared in the code" (even though that's not how LaTeX understand them)

@jpm92 then to do that you need to (a) use the same float class and (b) not use afterpage to delay one float until later (the argument of afterpage is not executed at all it is just saved as text and then treated as if \inputon a later page, so in your current version the table _is_ seen after the figure because the argument of\afterpage` is not executed until after the figure had been set.

@DavidCarlisle But then I'll have the problem of the text not flowing and leaving a blank gap in a page. I'll try Mico's option and see If I'm lucky

Since you're using \afterpage, why not include both the landscape/table combo and the figure environment in its scope? This setup, plus a couple of judiciously-placed \clearpage instructions, suffices to guarantee that the figure environment will get placed after the table environment.





\documentclass[draft]{report} % or some other suitable document class
% Be sure to remove 'draft' option in real document
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' env.
\usepackage{afterpage} % for '\afterpage' macro
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mhchem}    % for '\ce' macro
\usepackage{graphicx}  % for '\includegraphics' macro
\usepackage[flushleft,para]{threeparttable} 
          % for '\tnote' macro and 'tablenotes' and 'threeparttable' environments
\usepackage[tight-spacing]{siunitx} % for '\num' macro
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % for '\autoref' macro

\begin{document} 
\setcounter{chapter}{3} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{4} 

\subsection{Identification of potential biomarkers}

Identification of the metabolites corresponding to the candidate biomarkers was performed based on the assessment of the molecular formula from accurate mass, isotopic clustering, and experimental fragmentation spectra interpretation and comparison in spectral databases (see Materials and Methods section for more details). Additionally, we established 2 identification levels: (1)~Molecular formula matched with isotopic profile and compound databases and (2)~experimental fragmentation spectrum matched in spectral databases and in silico fragmentation tools. As a result, tentative identifications were achieved for 7 of the selected potential biomarkers (\autoref{metabolites}), which included metabolites from various glycerophospholipid (GPL) classes, such as glycerophosphoethanolamines, glycerophosphocholines, CDP-Diacylglycerols, and oxidized glycerophospholipids.

\afterpage{%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercolumn spacing

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Potential biomarkers differentially expressed in MMP (Stage~I) compared to HC serum samples based on MS/MS fragmentation spectra and data-base search.}
\label{metabolites}

\smallskip
\small
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} % target width: '\linewidth'
   l *{10}{c}}
\toprule
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{m/z}\tnote{1} & \textbf{RT}\tnote{2} & \textbf{Tentative ID}\tnote{3} & \textbf{Molecular Formula}\tnote{4} & \textbf{Mass error}\tnote{5} & \textbf{P-value}\tnote{6} & \textbf{FC}\tnote{7} & \textbf{AUC}\tnote{8} & \textbf{VIP}\tnote{9} & \textbf{IL}\tnote{10} \\
\midrule
M8  & 319.1932 & 15.75 & -- & -- & -- & \num{3.64e-3} & 0.63 (↓) & 0.77& 1.59& --   \\
M31 & 478.2926 & 10.50 & PE(18:2) & \ce{C23H44NO7P} & 0 & \num{6.42e-7} & 1.78 (↑) & 0.89& 2.14& 2   \\
M43 & 500.2737 & 10.72 & PE(20:5) & \ce{C25H42NO7P} & 7 & \num{8.77e-5} & 1.55 (↑) & 0.79& 1.68& 2   \\
M56 & 520.3398 & 10.74 & PC(18:2) & \ce{C26H50NO7P} & 1 & \num{1.73e-7} & 1.80 (↑) & 0.90& 2.20& 2   \\
M61 & 531.3236 & 10.83 & -- & -- & --& \num{7.90e-7} & 1.75 (↑) & 0.88& 2.17& --   \\
M64 & 539.3174 & 10.81 & CDP-DG(18:0/22:3)& \ce{C52H91N3O15P2}& 1 & \num{5.85e-8} & 1.95 (↑) & 0.90& 2.45& 1   \\
M65 & 542.3222 & 10.83 & PC(20:5/0:0) & \ce{C28H48NO7P} & 3 & \num{1.16e-6} & 1.54 (↑) & 0.87& 1.89& 2   \\
M95 & 604.2886 & 10.58 & POB-PS & \ce{C26H48NO11P} & 5 & \num{5.09e-8} & 1.62 (↑) & 0.91& 2.07& 2   \\
M97 & 610.3136 & 10.62 & -- & -- & --& \num{1.20e-7} & 1.69 (↑) & 0.9 & 2.12& --   \\
M102& 640.3431 & 10.26 & Hexosyl-PE(18:2) & \ce{C29H54NO12P} & 4 & \num{1.17e-3} & 2.03 (↑) & 0.73& 2.09& 2   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip 
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] Mass-to-charge ratio; 
\item[2] Retention time (min); 
\item[3] Common name of the tentatively identified metabolite according to MS/MS fragmentation spectra and data-base search; 
\item[4] Molecular formula of the tentatively identified metabolite; 
\item[5] Mass error (ppm); 
\item[6] $p$-value corresponding to univariate statistical analyses (T\nobreakdash-test). Only peaks with a $p$-value \textless~0.05 were selected;
\item[7] Fold change expressed as the ratio of the two averages (HC/MMP). Only peaks with a fold-change \textgreater~1.5 or \textless~0.66 were selected. The arrows indicate if the metabolite is increased (↑) or decreased (↓) in HC relative to MMP; 
\item[8] Area Under the Curve corresponding to ROC curve analyses; 
\item[9] VIP value corresponding to Variable Importance in the Projection selection technique;
\item[10] Identification level: (1)~Molecular formula matched in compound databases and (2)~Experimental fragmentation spectrum matched in spectral databases and in silico fragmentation tools.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage % flush the first float 

\begin{figure}[p!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.92\textwidth]{render/mel_Fig3.png}
\caption{%
\textbf{(a)} Graphical illustration of the relationship between candidate biomarkers and both stage~I MM subtype (SSM: Superficial spreading melanoma; ALM: Acral lentigous melanoma; LMM: Lentigo maligna melanoma) and stage~I MM location.
\textbf{(b)}--\textbf{(e)} Box plots representing MM type and location features for metabolites M43 and M102. Boxplots for the resting metabolites are included in the Supporting Information (Figure S2).}
\label{clinical}
\end{figure}
\clearpage % flush the second float
} % end of scope of \afterpage directive


Based on the identical criteria applied and the identification rules described by Kind and Fiehn [51], we were not able to assign biologically coherent molecular formulas for the following 3 metabolites: M8, M61 and M97.

\subsection{Clinical characterization of candidate biomarkers}

Further analysis of differentially expressed metabolites between healthy controls (HC) and individuals with MM was conducted using the Wilcoxon pairwise test. This analysis revealed significant correlations between these metabolites and certain features, such as melanoma type and location. \autoref{clinical} provides a summary of the statistically significant relationships identified, with particular emphasis on the M102 metabolite, which stood out prominently.

Specifically, M102 demonstrated a strong association with superficial spreading melanoma (SSM) ($p=0.002$) located in the torso region ($p=0.0000327$).

On the other hand, the remaining metabolites either displayed broad associations with melanoma location and subtype or showed no significant relationships at all, as observed in the cases of M56 and M8. The supporting information contains the corresponding $p$-values and boxplots for each of the significant associations discovered (Table S1 and S2, and \autoref{clinical}).

\end{document}


thanks >^.^< ;)

Is there a way to achieve such ordering without having to modify the table? To be honest, LaTeX is a bit of a mess already for me to be overcomplicating things if it is not necessary. I'm happy with how the table looks without using other packages :) Thanks a lot for your response :)

@jpm92 - You are entirely free to ignore the suggested edits to the contents of the tabular environment. All you really need is the following setup: \afterpage{\begin{landscape} \begin{table} ... \end{table} \end{landscape} \clearpage \begin{figure} ... \end{figure}\clearpage}. That said, you may want to re-evaluate at some point whether it's LaTeX or your code that's "a bit of a mess". :-)

Thanks a lot @Mico, I'll give it a go when I'm in front of the computer. Nonetheless I liked some of the suggestions (like the use of \num) :)

I'll mark this answer as accepted since you replied long ago. Nonetheless I noticed \clearpage is not needed. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Conceptually If you have a global requirement to have figures and tables stay in order and not float past each other they should have the same float type so, for the standard classes
\makeatletter
\def\ftype@table{1}% to match figure (was 2)
\makeatother

However that is not needed for this specific case, it is enough to delay the figure and enter it after the delayed rotated table.
\documentclass[11pt, b5paper, openright]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
    \section{Results}
        \subsection{LC-HRMS metabolomic and chemometric analyses}
            \lipsum[1]
            \begin{figure}[!ht]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{example-image-10x16}
                \caption{
                    Representative LC-HRMS total ion chromatograms (TICs) and PCA metabolomic analysis.  \textbf{(a)} Overlaid Total Ion Chromatograms (TIC) for three quality control 
                    (QC) samples at different injection sequence points, represented in orange color. These chromatograms demonstrate the excellent reproducibility observed in 
                    retention times. The TIC is also shown for a malignant melanoma patient (MMP) in red color and a healthy control (HC) in black color. Furthermore, the figure 
                    includes Extracted Ion Chromatograms (XIC) of three marker metabolites: PE(18:2) in blue line, PC(18:2) in purple line, and Hexoyl-PE(18:2) in pink line. PCA \textbf{(b)} 
                    and PLS-DA \textbf{(c)} scores plot based on LC-HRMS data of serum samples from total MMPs (red), and HCs (green). QC samples are indicated in blue. PCA \textbf{(d)} and PLS-DA \textbf{(e)} 
                    scores plot based on LC-HRMS data of serum samples from stage I MMP (red) and HCs (green).
                }
                \label{chromatogram}
            \end{figure}
            \lipsum[1-4]
            \begin{figure}[!ht]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=0.65\textheight]{example-image-10x16}
                \caption{
                    \textbf{(a)}  Heatmap where each row represents the intensity of each metabolite selected as potential biomarker with its characteristic mass to charge ratio and retention time, while each column represents each of the serum samples. \textbf{(b)} Heatmap where each row represents the average intensity of each metabolite selected as potential biomarker and each column represents each group of samples.
                    The colour code represents the normalized intensity with which each metabolite is detected. Blue represents a decreasing trend, while red represents a rising trend.
                }
            \end{figure}
            \lipsum[1-4]
        \subsection{Identification of potential biomarkers}
            \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
            \afterpage{
            \begin{landscape}
                \vspace*{\fill}
                \begin{table}[htbp!]
                    \centering
                    \caption{Potential biomarkers differentially expressed in MMP (Stage I) compared to HC serum samples based on MS/MS fragmentation spectra and data-base search.}
                    \label{metabolites}
                        \small
                        \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
                            \toprule
                            \textbf{ID}   & \textbf{m/z\textsuperscript{1}}  & \textbf{RT\textsuperscript{2}} & \textbf{Tentative ID\textsuperscript{3}}     & \textbf{Molecular Formula\textsuperscript{4}} & \textbf{Mass error\textsuperscript{5}} & \textbf{P-value\textsuperscript{6}} & \textbf{FC\textsuperscript{7}}   & \textbf{AUC\textsuperscript{8}} & \textbf{VIP\textsuperscript{9}} & \textbf{IL\textsuperscript{10}} \\
                            \midrule
                            M8   & 319.1932 & 15.75  & ---                  & ---                       & ---            & $3.64x10^{-3}$   & 0.63 (↓) & 0.77    & 1.59    & -       \\
                            M31  & 478.2926 & 10.50  & PE(18:2)             & \ce{C23H44NO7P}           & 0              & $6.42x10^{-7}$   & 1.78 (↑) & 0.89    & 2.14    & 2       \\
                            M43  & 500.2737 & 10.72  & PE(20:5)             & \ce{C25H42NO7P}           & 7              & $8.77x10^{-5}$   & 1.55 (↑) & 0.79    & 1.68    & 2       \\
                            M56  & 520.3398 & 10.74  & PC(18:2)             & \ce{C26H50NO7P}           & 1              & $1.73x10^{-7}$   & 1.80 (↑) & 0.90    & 2.20    & 2       \\
                            M61  & 531.3236 & 10.83  & ---                  & ---                       & ---            & $7.90x10^{-7}$   & 1.75 (↑) & 0.88    & 2.17    & -       \\
                            M64  & 539.3174 & 10.81  & CDP-DG(18:0/22:3)    & \ce{C52H91N3O15P2}        & 1              & $5.85x10^{-8}$   & 1.95 (↑) & 0.90    & 2.45    & 1       \\
                            M65  & 542.3222 & 10.83  & PC(20:5/0:0)         & \ce{C28H48NO7P}           & 3              & $1.16x10^{-6}$   & 1.54 (↑) & 0.87    & 1.89    & 2       \\
                            M95  & 604.2886 & 10.58  & POB-PS               & \ce{C26H48NO11P}          & 5              & $5.09x10^{-8}$   & 1.62 (↑) & 0.91    & 2.07    & 2       \\
                            M97  & 610.3136 & 10.62  & ---                  & ---                       & ---            & $1.20x10^{-7}$   & 1.69 (↑) & 0.9     & 2.12    & -       \\
                            M102 & 640.3431 & 10.26  & Hexosyl-PE(18:2)     & \ce{C29H54NO12P}          & 4              & $1.17x10^{-3}$   & 2.03 (↑) & 0.73    & 2.09    & 2       \\
                            \bottomrule
                        \end{tabular}
                        \vspace{0.5mm}
                        \footnotesize
                        \begin{flushleft}
                            \textsuperscript{\textbf{1}} Mass-to-charge ratio; \textsuperscript{\textbf{2}} Retention time (min); \textsuperscript{\textbf{3}} Common name of the tentatively identified metabolite according to MS/MS fragmentation spectra and data-base search; \textsuperscript{\textbf{4}} Molecular formula of the tentatively identified metabolite; \textsuperscript{\textbf{5}} Mass error (ppm); \textsuperscript{\textbf{6}} p-value corresponding to univariate statistical analyses (T-test). Only peaks with a p-value \textless 0.05 were selected;
                            \textsuperscript{\textbf{7}} Fold change expressed as the ratio of the two averages (HC/MMP). Only peaks with a fold-change \textgreater 1.5 or \textless 0.66 were selected. The arrows indicate if the metabolite is increased (↑) or decreased (↓) in HC relative to MMP; \textsuperscript{\textbf{8}} Area Under the Curve corresponding to ROC curve analyses; \textsuperscript{\textbf{9}} VIP value corresponding to Variable Importance in the Projection selection technique;
                            \textsuperscript{\textbf{10}} Identification level: (1) Molecular formula matched in compound databases and (2) Experimental fragmentation spectrum matched in spectral databases and in silico fragmentation tools.
                        \end{flushleft}
                \end{table}
                \vspace*{\fill}
            \end{landscape}
            \begin{figure}[!htp]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=0.7\textheight]{example-image-10x16}
                \caption{
                    \textbf{(a)} Graphical illustration of the relationship between candidate biomarkers and both stage I MM subtype (SSM: Superficial spreading melanoma; ALM: Acral lentigous melanoma; LMM: Lentigo maligna melanoma) and stage I MM location.
                    \textbf{(b-e)} Box plots representing MM type and location features for metabolites M43 and M102. Boxplots for the resting metabolites are included in the Supporting Information (Figure S2).}
                \label{clinical}
              \end{figure}
            }
            \lipsum[1]
        \subsection{Clinical characterization of candidate biomarkers}
        \lipsum[1-3]
         
        \subsection{Model performance}
            \subsubsection{Metabolite selection}
                \lipsum[1-2]
            \subsubsection{Model training}
                \lipsum[1-2]
                \begin{figure}[ht]
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
                    \caption{
                        Model development results. \textbf{(a)} ROC curves representing the average performance of each of the algorithms employed after repeated 10-fold cross-validation and hyperparameter tuning on the training set.
                        \textbf{(b)} Confusion matrix and performance metrics yielded by the SLNN model on the validation dataset.
                    }
                \end{figure}
            \subsubsection{Model validation}
                \lipsum[1-2]
              \end{document}
              


I had this half written yesterday but just noticed Mico posted the same so you should accept his although I post anyway in case you were expecting an answer following the comments


Problem solved, thanks a lot for the effort @DavidCarlisle. I'm really impressed with the TeX community. I marked Mico's answer as accepted but you both were really helpful.
