# multiple rotated figures on one page

Tags: floats, subfloats, rotating

I googled for hours and tried all examples I found (`rotatebox`, `subfigures`, `minipages`), but nothing provided the output I am looking for.

Is it really that difficult to place 3 figures rotated so they are in `landscape` mode side-by-side? It took me like 30 seconds in Word (see link to screenshot for better understanding below). It would be the non-plus-ultra if each `figure` would have a rotated caption as well... Does somebody know how to achieve this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's an option using the [`rotating`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/rotating) package; note that I have loaded the [`mwe`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mwe) just for demonstration

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{First caption}
  \label{fig:first}
    \includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Second caption}
  \label{fig:second}
    \includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=3cm]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Third caption}
  \label{fig:third}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

If you'd prefer `subfigure`s with `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)`, then you can use the `subcaption` package as follows (for example)

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\textheight}
    \includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{First caption}
  \label{fig:first}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{\textheight}
    \includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Second caption}
  \label{fig:second}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{\textheight}
    \includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=3cm]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Third caption}
  \label{fig:third}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Global caption}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

In both cases, you can apply some manual spacing if you wish using `\vspace`.

Comment: I'm too slow, was just about to post this. Perhaps some `\vspace` between the captions and the next image? Edit: By the way, I don't think you have to load `mwe` explicitly to use its images.

Comment: thank you! I managed it finally and used the same approach as you demonstrated with sidewaysfigure.

Comment: @Airlike you're very welcome :)

Comment: @cmhughes Perhaps you should highlight that it is the `rotating` package *and* `sidewaysfigure`, which makes the figure be rotated.

Answer (score 6):

Without captions it is trvial just `graphicx` package and then

```
\noindent
\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics{fig1}}\hfill
\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics{fig2}}\hfill
\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics{fig3}}
```

will put the three figures side by side.

With captions probably the easiest way is `lscape` (or `pdflscape`) package then

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\includegraphics{fig1}
\caption{cap 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\includegraphics{fig2}
\caption{cap 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\includegraphics{fig3}
\caption{cap 13}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: I managed it also finally.. but the comment function here does not allow to post my code... I used "sidewaysfigure".