# How to insert submatches from regular expression in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

I am trying to use the regular expression feature from TexStudio but somehow I can't get it to work and i couldn't find an example or an explanation in the manual.

I am trying to replace variables `y1,y2,y3` (y1) with `x_1,x_2,x_3` (x_1). In the tip from 'Reg' it is mentioned that 'You can use \1 to \9 in the replace text to insert a submatch.'

[image]

I tried to Replace it like this but now everything is replaced with (x_\1) and not the corresponding number. What am I doing wrong?

In adddition: is there a regular expression for all numbers? (1 as well as 1999) For letters there is [A-Z], but [0-9999] only gets the first digit marked.

Thank You!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use capture groups in order for the `\1` to work.

```
Find: y(\d+)
Replace: x_\1
```

should work. You can check what is being replaced with the little preview text after the `\1` button.

Also, `\d` characters are digits, then `+` just means 1 or more.

[image]