# How do you find and replace but ignoring things inside the brackets?

Tags: texstudio, find

I am looking to use find and replace to change my graphic file locations without the need to do each one individually.

So I currently have several

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig1}
\includegraphics[scale=0.85]{fig2}
```

etc.

Is there a way at which I can find and replace to something like this

*find(\includegraphics[*]{/Chapter/Images/* *

where * is this thing I am trying to ignore and not change. This would result in

```
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{/Chapter/Images/fig1}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.85]{/Chapter/Images/fig2}
```

If anyone knows of a way I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Assuming you use texstudio (as you tagged your question), you could do this with regex matches and capture groups. See for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432218/how-to-insert-submatches-from-regular-expression-in-texstudio

Comment: why do you need to do that at all? it is almost always better just to have  `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig1}`  you can use `\graphicspath{{Chapter/Images/}}` so tex looks in the subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer is the comment from @David Carlisle, but, just to make a regex exercise, in TeXStudio you should search for:

`\\includegraphics\[(.*)\]\{(.*)\}`

And subtitute with

`\includegraphics[\1]{/Chapter/Images/\2}`